# What is the easiest way to draw a 3D cube with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, pgf-core

I'm trying to find the easiest way to draw a 3D cube (it's for my UML diagram) with TikZ. Could you please give an example?

Like this:
[image]

Comment: Depends a bit on what you want the cube to look like.  There's a really nice one at TeXample: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/sudoku-3d-cube/ but that might not be what you want.  Can you sketch a picture?

Comment: @Andrew see the picture above :)

Comment: Another example, already published here on TeX.sx: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35289/7417](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35289/7417)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'm sure that there are better ways, but here's one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{1}
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `minimal`? If not, I'd suggest replacing it by a standard document class, as we generally want to discourage usage of `minimal`‽

Comment: @doncherry Because the question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/86 hadn't been asked when I wrote that!  I was young, I was naive, I didn't know what I was doing.  Now I'm old and grumpy and can say, "You want it changed?  You know where the 'edit' button is!".  (Seriously, you should feel free to make changes like that.)

Comment: Good response `:)`. Well, I guess concerning people like you I could just edit it, but then again I think "He knows a lot more about that stuff than I do, perhaps there's a reason he used `minimal`". When coming across newer users using it, I usually point them to the question you mentioned.

Comment: A quick grep shows that I've used it 45 times in answers (subject to rounding errors).  If you come across any others, feel free to edit.

Comment: I shall `:)`. Perhaps they'll introduce a gold version of the Archaeologist badge some time ...

Comment: Note that this needs something like `line join=round` to make sure the corners of the faces don't protrude outside the shape.

Comment: @rubenvb See my CW answer below for a link to a question about how to fix that issue.

Comment: @Loop your method thickens some of the edge lines, whereas the small option I suggest doesn't...

Comment: @rubenvb Technically, the thickening is *correct* since each line appears on its face so where you see two faces then you see two lines.

Comment: @loop but we're drawing a cube, not four rectangles in their own plane. A real cube doesn't even have black lines on its edges, these ones are only to give the shape, well, its shape. So in light of answering the question of how to draw a 3D cube, I'd argue they are wrong.

Comment: @rubenvb Fortunately, it doesn't matter who is "right".  TikZ can draw it either way.

Answer (score 67):

Drawing a cube seems to be a fairly common task!  There are a few other questions here that involve drawing cubes.  It's not always right to merge them, but I thought it worth doing a little more than just linking.  So this answer is a Community Wiki (so almost anyone can update it) list of the other cubical questions here.  The intent is to include at least one representative picture from the answers.

1. [Need help creating a 3D cube from a 2D set of nodes in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29877/86)

   [Tom Bombadil's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7279/tom-bombadil) answer here is well on the way to being a package, showing that he has mastery over cubes as well as rings.

   [image: cubes]
2. [How to draw a cube with TikZ where all faces have a distinct color?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28284/86)

   The accepted answer yields the first image, and the second is a another from the same question:

   [image] 
   [image: transparent cube]
3. [Is there a way to draw TikZ lines on the "inside" or "outside" of a path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29991/86)

   Although not obviously about cubes, the motivation was to draw a cube and get the corners right.

   [image: cube with corners]
4. [How to draw parallelepiped and cube with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285578/)

One [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288101/) provides a `pic` for drawing annotated cuboids like these:

[image: annotated cuboids]

Comment: Also, Tom's answer has made significant progress since the version posted here and now includes some shaded cubes which really look as if they belong among the rings and mists of Middle Earth... ;).

Answer (score 45):

Since you want to use this for UML diagrams, I think a custom node shape is the right way to go here.  It's a lot more overhead and requires getting under PGF's hood/bonnet, but the payoff is that it the drawing code looks just like any other TikZ code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd,
  parallelepiped offset x/.initial=2mm,
  parallelepiped offset y/.initial=2mm
}
\pgfdeclareshape{parallelepiped}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \backgroundpath{
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped offset x}}
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped offset y}}
    \def\ppd@offset{\pgfpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[parallelepiped,draw=red,fill=yellow,
  minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=1.5cm] (1) {Node One};
\node[parallelepiped,draw=blue,fill=green,
  minimum height=2.5cm,minimum width=1.5cm,parallelepiped offset x=4mm] (2)
 at (6,0) {Node Two};
 \draw[ultra thick, ->] (1) -- (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

Take a look at the files `pgflibraryshapes.*.code.tex` in the PGF distribution to learn how to do this kind of thing.  I started with a copy of the `cross out` node which, like this one, inherits from the `rectangle` node.  A further enhancement would be to add anchors to the right/top faces/edges, but as you can guess I have spent enough time on this already. `:-D`

Comment: Very nice!  Plus the text should be in the actual middle of the cube and be a bit faded so that it looked as though it were inside ...

Comment: @Andrew: yes, if what is desired is a cube with text in the center.  But I looked up UML diagrams like the OP is trying to create and they put it on the front of the cube/parallelipiped.  See [“UML Deployment Diagrams”](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/deployment-diagrams.html)

Comment: Since when has doing what the spec says stopped you from doing what is _right_??  You are a mathematician after all.

Comment: Sometimes doing what is asked and nothing more is wise... (especially for a mathematician who should be writing his book).

Comment: @Matthew: It's spelled parallelepiped. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped

Comment: @Faheem: fixed.

Comment: In the spirit of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/4012, I guess so ... thanks `:)`

Comment: This is great. Is there a way of swapping this around so that the left face shows? If I rotate the shape, it also puts the bottom of the cub on show, changing the perspective from the top.

Comment: @Allentro for sure, but since you're showing a different corner it would require rewriting the lines which draw the node.

Answer (score 37):

I know that this is not what the question was about, but it is an attempt of a 3D cube, with perspective.  I don't know how to do it with grids like Stefan's example, but with coordinate calculations and intersections, one can do something like this.  It is not mathematically correct, but I think it looks pretty good.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \clip (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
   \coordinate (tf) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (bf) at (0,-3);
   \coordinate (tr) at (15:2.5cm);
   \coordinate (tl) at (165:2.5cm);

   % You can change the perspective by playing with the 5, 5, 15:
   \coordinate (fr) at ($ (tf)!5!(tr) $);
   \coordinate (fl) at ($ (tf)!5!(tl) $);
   \coordinate (fb) at ($ (tf)!15!(bf) $);

   \path[name path=brpath] (bf) -- (fr);
   \path[name path=rbpath] (tr) -- (fb);
   \path[name path=blpath] (bf) -- (fl);
   \path[name path=lbpath] (tl) -- (fb);
   \path[name path=trpath] (tl) -- (fr);
   \path[name path=tlpath] (tr) -- (fl);

   \draw[name intersections={of=brpath and rbpath}] (intersection-1)coordinate (br){}; 
   \draw[name intersections={of=blpath and lbpath}] (intersection-1)coordinate (bl){}; 
   \draw[name intersections={of=trpath and tlpath}] (intersection-1)coordinate (tb){}; 

   \shade[right color=gray!10, left color=black!50, shading angle=105] (tf) -- (bf) -- (bl) -- (tl) -- cycle;
   \shade[left color=gray!10, right color=black!50, shading angle=75] (tf) -- (bf) -- (br) -- (tr) -- cycle;

   \begin{scope}
      \clip (tf) -- (tr) -- (tb) -- (tl) -- cycle;
      \shade[inner color = gray!5, outer color=black!50, shading=radial] (tf) ellipse (3cm and 1.5cm);
   \end{scope}

   \draw (tf) -- (bf);
   \draw (tf) -- (tr);
   \draw (tf) -- (tl);
   \draw (tr) -- (br);
   \draw (bf) -- (br);
   \draw (tl) -- (bl);
   \draw (bf) -- (bl);
   \draw (tb) -- (tr);
   \draw (tb) -- (tl);

   %set the sizes of the little cubes:
   \def\tone{.4}\def\ttwo{.75}\def\fone{.36}\def\ftwo{.70}
   \draw ($ (bf)!\tone!(br) $) -- ($ (tf)!\tone!(tr) $) -- ($ (tl)!\tone!(tb) $);
   \draw ($ (bf)!\ttwo!(br) $) -- ($ (tf)!\ttwo!(tr) $) -- ($ (tl)!\ttwo!(tb) $);
   \draw ($ (bf)!\tone!(bl) $) -- ($ (tf)!\tone!(tl) $) -- ($ (tr)!\tone!(tb) $);
   \draw ($ (bf)!\ttwo!(bl) $) -- ($ (tf)!\ttwo!(tl) $) -- ($ (tr)!\ttwo!(tb) $);
   \draw ($ (tl)!\fone!(bl) $) -- ($ (tf)!\fone!(bf) $) -- ($ (tr)!\fone!(br) $);
   \draw ($ (tl)!\ftwo!(bl) $) -- ($ (tf)!\ftwo!(bf) $) -- ($ (tr)!\ftwo!(br) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I learned something new: `name path`.  Thanks Jan!

Comment: Nice!  And anyone else coming here looking for how to draw a cube will now have a feast of answers to choose from.

Comment: What do you change in order to extend one dimension (making an orthotope instead of a cuboid)? Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

There is already a lot of nice answers to this question, but I would like to promote the `3d` TikZ library which makes it easier to manipulate simple objects with three-dimensional coordinates. Here is a solution in the spirit of Stefan's:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x  = {(0.5cm,0.5cm)},
                    y  = {(0.95cm,-0.25cm)},
                    z  = {(0cm,0.9cm)}]
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=-1]
  \shade[left color=blue!50,right color=blue!20] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=1]
  \shade[right color=blue!70,left color=blue!20] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=1]
  \shade[top color=blue!80,bottom color=blue!20] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Again, the tricky part is to fine tune the perspective and shading, but in my opinion the `canvas` option provides an easy way to draw in 3D.

[image]

Answer (score 22):

Here's an example for a shaded 3D cube with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[on grid]
  \shade[yslant=-0.5,right color=gray!10, left color=black!50]
    (0,0) rectangle +(3,3);
  \draw[yslant=-0.5] (0,0) grid (3,3);
  \shade[yslant=0.5,right color=gray!70,left color=gray!10]
    (3,-3) rectangle +(3,3);
  \draw[yslant=0.5] (3,-3) grid (6,0);
  \shade[yslant=0.5,xslant=-1,bottom color=gray!10,
    top color=black!80] (6,3) rectangle +(-3,-3);
  \draw[yslant=0.5,xslant=-1] (3,0) grid (6,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Shaded 3D cube]

I used on on my [blog](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/graphics/pgf-tikz/tikz-cube-3d/).

Comment: The cube is nice, but the shading doesn't give a good 3D-effect IMHO.

Comment: @Hendrik: quick and easy simulating kind of light which should lead a bit to an optical 3D appearance though it's of course 2D. For an oblique view one could modify it. My answer points to an easy way, as desired.

Comment: As now there's a picture in the question, showing a different requested style, I consider to remove the answer.

Comment: (Voting for it not to be removed as it's a really nice example.)  What destroys the 3D effect for me is not the shading but the perspective - or lack of it.

Comment: @Andrew: I've been too lazy :-) if you know how to easily add perspective, you're welcome to modify. We could bring that enhancement to TeXample.net afterwards.

Comment: Perspective is tricky since TikZ doesn't have true 3d capabilities.  One would need to apply a transformation which depends on the (x,y,z) coordinates.

Answer (score 17):

A bit late to join the party, but I found that a bit of corner rounding is sufficient to make the corners look decent:

[image: cube]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{tikz,color}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Settings
    \definecolor{CUBE}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,0.9};
    \coordinate (CenterPoint) at (0,0);
    \def\width{1.5cm};
    \def\height{1.0cm};
    \def\textborder{0.1cm};
    \def\xslant{0.2cm};
    \def\yslant{0.15cm};
    \def\rounding{0.2pt};
    % Drawing
    \node[thick, draw,
          minimum height  = \height,
          minimum width   = \width,
          text width      = {\width-2*\textborder},
          align           = center,
          fill            = CUBE!50,
          rounded corners = \rounding]
          at (CenterPoint) {``Cube''}; % TEXT HERE?
    % "3D" top
    \draw [rounded corners = \rounding, thick, fill=CUBE!70] %
        ($(CenterPoint) + (-\width/2. - 2*\rounding, \height/2.)$) -- %
        ($(CenterPoint) + (-\width/2. + \xslant - 2*\rounding, \height/2. + \yslant)$) -- %
        ($(CenterPoint) + (\width/2. + \xslant + 2*\rounding, \height/2. + \yslant)$) -- %
        ($(CenterPoint) + (\width/2. + 2*\rounding, \height/2.)$) -- %
        cycle;
    % "3D" side
    \draw [rounded corners = \rounding, thick, fill=CUBE!90] %
        ($(CenterPoint) + (\width/2. + \xslant + 2*\rounding, \height/2. + \yslant)$) -- %
        ($(CenterPoint) + (\width/2. + 2*\rounding, \height/2.)$) -- %
        ($(CenterPoint) + (\width/2. + 2*\rounding, -\height/2.)$) -- %
        ($(CenterPoint) + (\width/2. + \xslant + 2*\rounding, -\height/2. + \yslant)$) -- %
        cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am sure if this is useful someone with more experience and knowledge can compensate, if required, the extra width (`+ 2*\rounding`) added to make the corners fit together, add anchors around the drawing, encapsulate it in some routine you can call and even allow for the "3D" part to appear on other sides (change perspective).

But since this article helped me, I thought I would give back what I learned even if little or rudimentary.

Also, details on the corners (*please remove them if they are occupying too much space and are not useful*):

[image: corner1] [image: corner2] [image: corner3]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. This is really quite late, but a nice answer! :)

Comment: Instead of `rounded corners`, you may try `line cap=round,line join=round` (and `0pt` as value for `\rounding` in your MWE).

Comment: `line cap=round` and `line join=round` leave the corners between the three distinct faces pointy, with bits sticking out. `0pt` also leaves the same artifacts. I didn't try different values but I guess there should be a best value for each line thickness.

Answer (score 4):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\psset{
  dimen = m,
  linejoin = 1,
  fillstyle = solid,
  fillcolor = yellow!30
}
\begin{pspicture}(4,2.5)
  \psframe(0,0)(3.5,2)
  \pspolygon(3.5,0)(3.5,2)(4,2.5)(4,0.5)
  \pspolygon(0,2)(0.5,2.5)(4,2.5)(3.5,2)
  \rput(1.75,1){Node}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: This your code does not run on my Windows: `undefined control sequence \psframe(0,0)(3.5,2)`