# \shortstack when writing text in nodes in TikZ

Tags: stacking-symbols

I have seen the command `\shortstack` in some nodes in TikZ (for example, the accepted answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13030/node-shapes-tikz)).

What is used for? I couldn't find its definition in the TikZ manual.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`\shortstack` is not part of `tikz`. It is used to stack items over each other.  Note that the MWE does not use any packages.

[image]

### Syntax:

```
\shortstack[alignment]{line 1 \\ line 2 \\ line 3 etc. }
```

where the valid alignement are:

```
r - right aligned
l - left aligned
c - centered (default)
```

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\shortstack{Predefined\\Process}
\hspace{1cm}
\shortstack[r]{Predefined\\Process}
\hspace{1cm}
\shortstack[l]{Predefined\\Process}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

`\shortstack` is not a [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)-specific command. It is part of the standard LaTeX distribution and is defined in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) with the following format:

```
\shortstack[<alignment>]{<stuff>}
```

Here is the original definition(s):

```
\gdef\shortstack{\@ifnextchar[\@shortstack{\@shortstack[c]}}
\gdef\@shortstack[#1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox\bgroup
    \baselineskip-\p@\lineskip 3\p@
    \let\mb@l\hss\let\mb@r\hss
    \expandafter\let\csname mb@#1\endcsname\relax
    \let\\\@stackcr
    \@ishortstack}
\gdef\@ishortstack#1{\ialign{\mb@l {##}\unskip\mb@r\cr #1\crcr}\egroup}
```

It is meant to stack things on top of one another like in a `tabular`. However, it has a shorter `\baselineskip`, causing a shorter vertical stacking of elements.

Here is a minimal example showing some of the difference between `tabular` and `\shortstack`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \verb|\shortstack|: & \shortstack{Predefined\\Process} \hspace{1cm}
    \shortstack[r]{Predefined\\Process} \hspace{1cm}
    \shortstack[l]{Predefined\\Process} \\ \hline
  \verb|tabular|: & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Predefined\\Process\end{tabular} \hspace{1cm}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}Predefined\\Process\end{tabular} \hspace{1cm}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}Predefined\\Process\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}​
```

Note the reduced baseline skip in `\shortstack`. Also, `\shortstack` necessarily has a zero-width horizontal padding. Finally, the default alignment for `\shortstack` is along the `b`aseline, while `tabular` allows for `t`op, `c`enter (default), or `b`aseline.

Answer (score 4):

`\shortstack` is defined in the basic `latex.ltx` file.  its purpose is to set text in multiple lines within a confined area.