# Break after arrow

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, formatting, ieeetran

The length of formula in attached code is getting too long, I would wish to break it short.
I try to insert a break after the \rightsquigarrow by failed.

How should I insert a break?

```
   \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, url, proof}
    \newcommand{\srule}[3]{
    \infer[ (#1) ]
         {#3}
         {#2}
         \bigskip
    }
    \begin{document}

    {\centering
        \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
            \srule{if2}
            { \bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n t_1 \leq t_i}
            {(t_1\Rightarrow P_1,\ldots,t_n\Rightarrow P_n),C,D)
            \stackrel{\tau}\rightsquigarrow
            (P_1, C \land \bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n t_1 \leq t_i,D+t_1))}
        \end{minipage}

        } 

    \end{document}
```

[image: The expected formula should be like this]

Comment: The equation is a little unusual, so it's difficult to make a suggestion. Could you add a picture illustrating the result that you want?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question to put the picture of expected result.

Comment: I guess you don't want the "if" from `if2` in math mode, do you? At the moment it looks like the variables `i` and `f`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just add another `\stackrel{}` to achieve:

[image]

Alternatively, you could use `\shortstack{}{}` as discussed at [\shortstack when writing text in nodes in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42858/shortstack-when-writing-text-in-nodes-in-tikz) and shown in the example below. This also produces an image as above.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, url, proof}
\newcommand{\srule}[3]{
\infer[ (#1) ]
     {#3}
     {#2}
     \bigskip
}
\begin{document}

{\centering
    \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}% ---------- \stackrel version
        \srule{if2}
        { \bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n t_1 \leq t_i}
        {\stackrel{\displaystyle(t_1\Rightarrow P_1,\ldots,t_n\Rightarrow P_n),C,D)
        \stackrel{\tau}\rightsquigarrow}
        {(P_1, C \land \bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n t_1 \leq t_i,D+t_1))}}
    \end{minipage}
    %
    \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}% ---------- \shortstack version
        \srule{if2}
        { \bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n t_1 \leq t_i}
        {\shortstack{$(t_1\Rightarrow P_1,\ldots,t_n\Rightarrow P_n),C,D)
        \stackrel{\tau}\rightsquigarrow$ \\
        $(P_1, C \land \bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n t_1 \leq t_i,D+t_1))$}}
    \end{minipage}
    } 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vertical stacking is easily obtained using `array`. The following MWE uses a `\frac` to stack elements as well as `array` for "sub-stacking" the lower part:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, url, proof}
\newcommand{\srule}[3]{
  \infer[ (#1) ]
    {#3}
    {#2}
    \bigskip
  }

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
  \srule{if2}
    { \bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n t_1 \leq t_i}
    {(t_1\Rightarrow P_1,\ldots,t_n\Rightarrow P_n),C,D)
    \stackrel{\tau}\rightsquigarrow
    (P_1, C \land \bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n t_1 \leq t_i,D+t_1))}
\end{minipage}

\[
  \frac
    {\bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n t_1 \leq t_i}
    {\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
       ((t_1\Rightarrow P_1,\ldots,t_n\Rightarrow P_n),C,D)
         \stackrel{\tau}\rightsquigarrow \\
       (P_1, C \land \bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n t_1 \leq t_i,D+t_1)
     \end{array}}\ (if2)
\]

\end{document}
```