# Left aligning multiple rows of text in a single cell in a table

Tags: tables

I have the following table:

```
\documentclass[Journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\arrayrulecolor{mycolor}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % for header footer

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \caption{Some caption}
    \label{table:tab1}
    \begin{tabular}{rcccccc}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Column 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 3}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 4}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ Column 5}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ Column 6}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ Column 7}} \\
        \midrule
        ABC et al [21] &  &  &\checkmark&& \checkmark& \shortstack{Some text goes here\\and some here}\\ 
        \midrule
        XYZ et al [23] &  &  \checkmark&    \checkmark& & & \shortstack{Similarly some text here\\and some here}\\

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:dvar}%
\end{table*}%

\end{document}
```

This code results in the following table:
[image]

I want the second line of column 7's first cell "and some here" to start just below "Some text goes here". And the same for all cells of column 7. In simple words I want both the rows in each cell of column 7 to be left aligned. If you notice in the current scenario the first line is left aligned but the second isn't. 
How do I do it. 
Appreciated.

Comment: what about using `l` in last column like: \begin{tabular}{rcccccl}?

Comment: works just for the first line

Comment: What about \shortstack[l]{...}? (There is a lowercase L as an optional argument... And possibly previous comment has to used too)..

Comment: post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42860/120578
that `\shortstack` has an optional argument about the alignment of the contained text.

A left alignment in the column type of the last row is a must too, because if not used, only the current text of every `\shortstack` will be aligned and no alignment will be generated between different cells.

So, just use something like this:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{rcccccl}\hline
        \textbf{Column 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 3}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 4}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ Column 5}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ Column 6}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ Column 7}} \\\hline
        ABC et al [21] &  &  &\checkmark&& \checkmark& \shortstack[l]{Some text goes here\\and some here}\\ \hline
        XYZ et al [23] &  &  \checkmark&    \checkmark& & & \shortstack[l]{Similarly some text here\\and some here}\\\hline
    \end{tabular}%
\end{document}
```

(`\checkmark` is from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132790/120578)

[image]

PS: Thanks for introducing `\shortstack` command to me`

Comment: That helped. And I am glad I helped too.

Answer (score 3):

You also can use the `makecell` package, which lets you have line breaks in standard columns, and define a common formatting  of the arguments of `\makecell` and `\thead`.

Another, unrelated remark: I don't think a hammersledge like `TikZ` should be used for checkmarks, as there are some symbols font packages which already define them. I use two of them in the following code:

```
\documentclass[Journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption, makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % for header footer
\usepackage{bbding, pifont}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
    \centering\renewcommand{\cellalign}{bl}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
    \caption{Some caption}
    \label{table:tab1}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}rcccccl@{}}
        \toprule
        \thead{Column 1} & \thead{Column 2} & \thead{Column 3} & \thead{Column 4} & \thead{ Column 5} & \thead{ Column 6} & \thead{Column 7} \\
        \midrule
        ABC et al [21] & & &\checkmark&& \checkmark& \makecell{Some text goes here\\and some here}\\
        \midrule
        XYZ et al [23] & & \ding{51}& \Checkmark& & & \makecell{Similarly some text here\\and some here}\\

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:dvar}%
    \end{table*}%

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another option is to use `\makecell[l]{Some text goes here\\and some here}` instead of redefining `\cellalign`