# How can I create this kind of flow chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, formatting, nodes, node-connections

I am creating a beamer presentation. I try to create a  tikz flow chart. Here is my production. T_T
[image]

Actually, what I want to do is
[image]

Be grateful with any help! So frustrated now.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20,
text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,
text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
% Place nodes
\node [block] (begin) {begin};
\node [block, below of=begin] (input) {input};
\node [block, below of=input] (data) {initdata };
\node [decision, below of=data] (judge) {judge the data};
\node [block, right of=judge, node distance=4cm] (output) {update model};
\node [block, below of=judge] (sum) {s=s+(i-1)};
\node [block, below of=sum, node distance=3cm] (increase) {i=i+1};
% Draw edges
\path [line] (begin) -- (input);
\path [line] (input) -- (data);
\path [line] (data) -- (judge);
\path [line] (sum) -- (increase);
\path [line] (judge) -| node [near start] {no} (output);
\path [line] (judge) |- node [near start]{yes}(sum);
\path [line] (increase)--(judge);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show us the code of what you've done so far as well, not just a screenshot.

Comment: In [tikz-picture-shapes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87945/tikz-picture-shapes) you will find some missing shapes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a solution via TikZ matrix node

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, arrows, positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\tikzset{%
decision/.style = {diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text badly centered, inner sep=0pt},
block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
io/.style ={trapezium, draw, minimum width=2.5cm,trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120},
line/.style = {draw, -stealth},
cloud/.style = {draw, rectangle, fill=red!20, minimum height=2em, minimum width=1.5cm, rounded corners=10pt}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
% Place nodes with matrix nodes
 \matrix[matrix of nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm]{%
    \node [cloud] (init) {\color{red}begin}; & \\
    \node [io] (identify) {\color{red}input};&\\
    \node [block] (evaluate) {$i=1,s=1$};    & \\
    \node [decision] (decide) {$i \le n$?};  & 
    \node [io] (print) {{\color{red}output}};               \\
    \node [block] (stop) {$s=s+(i-1)$};      & \node [cloud] (end) {\color{red}stop};   \\
    \node [block] (loop) {$i=i+1$};          & \\
};
% Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);  
    \path [line] (identify) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -- node[right]{\color{red}Yes} (stop);
    \path [line] (decide) --node[above]{\color{red}No} (print);
    \path [line] (print.south) -- (end);
    \path [line] (stop) --  (loop);
    \path [line] (loop) -- ++(-2,0) |-(decide);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm sorry to tell you that it fails to compile in my computer. The error shows that "not in outer par mode". The error focus on \begin{center}. Shall we have to use \begin center? Thanks!

Comment: `\centering` instead of `center` environment

Comment: @percusse still shows the same error......

Comment: @Hinn It should go away with `article` class. Standalone is not meant for floats.

Comment: @Jesse It works at the other PC. My PC is bad.

Comment: @Hinn -- Sorry I was unavaible when you had questions. Glad to know that it works now. My appreciation also goes to percusse for the helping hand.

Comment: @Jesse   after deleting the \begin{center} and \begin{figure}, it's OK now. Thank you! Now I'm trying to zoom out the \tikzstyle{io} the diamond. How could I make it smaller? Thanks!

Comment: Play with the minimum width/height to tune its size. left/right angle can be changed too, but these angles are fine to me.