# Tikz node with data storage flowchart symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, flow-charts, tikz-shape

I am trying to create a Tikz node with some text that has the ‘data storage’ flowchart shape:

[image: Data Storage or Stored Data Symbol]

This is what I'm building on:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzstyle{storage} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text width=3cm, text centered, draw=black]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \node (sto1) [storage] {Some text}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have been trying to get the data storage node shape, mainly referring to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246960/tikz-internal-storage-symbol) as well as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87945/tikz-picture-shapes), however I haven't succeeded in creating it.

Comment: Are you looking for `\tikz\node[cylinder, aspect=.5, minimum height=5mm, cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder body fill=blue!30, draw] {};` ?

Comment: @Kpym This seems to create a cylinder which has the fill that I want but still the borders of a cylinder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241737/121799
\tikzset{pics/named scope code/.style={code={\tikz@fig@mustbenamed%
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box/.expanded=\tikz@fig@name]#1\end{scope}%
}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
  pic memory/.style={named scope code={
  \filldraw[fill=blue!30!gray!50](0,0) arc(90:270:0.5 and 1) --++(4,0) arc(-90:-270:0.5 and 1) --cycle
 node[pos=.6,below={1cm},anchor=center] {#1};
  }}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (memory1) at (0,0) {pic memory=Test text};
\draw[thick,blue,-latex] (memory1.west) -- ++(-2,0);
\draw[thick,red,-latex] (memory1.north) -- ++(-1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this can be done with a `rounded rectangle` node:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    datastore/.style={draw, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle east arc=concave, rounded rectangle arc length=150}
]

\node[datastore, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1.5cm, fill=cyan!30, draw=cyan!70!black]{Example};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To draw a flowchart symbol for "Storage", similar to the one mentioned in ["display" shape for flowchart with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428163/display-shape-for-flowchart-with-tikz) , you can use the following code.

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
  
  \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text 
   width=3cm, draw=orange, fill=orange!20]
  \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
  
  \makeatletter
  
  \pgfdeclareshape{display}
  {
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
    \inheritbackgroundpath[from=rectangle]
    \backgroundpath{
      % points
      \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
      \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
      % dimensions
      \pgfmathsetlength{\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgf@xb-\pgf@xa}
      \pgfmathsetlength{\pgfutil@tempdimb}{\pgf@yb-\pgf@ya}
      % path
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}{\pgfqpoint{-0.2\pgfutil@tempdima} 
       {0pt}}}
          \pgfpatharc{-90}{90}{0.2\pgfutil@tempdima and 0.5\pgfutil@tempdimb}
  
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}{\pgfqpoint{0.8\pgfutil@tempdima} 
      {0pt}}}    
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\pgfqpoint{-0.2\pgfutil@tempdima} 
       {0pt}}}
      \pgfpatharc{90}{-90}{0.2\pgfutil@tempdima and 0.5\pgfutil@tempdimb}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}{\pgfqpoint{-0.2\pgfutil@tempdima} 
      {0pt}}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}{\pgfqpoint{0.8\pgfutil@tempdima} 
      {0pt}}}
      \pgfpathclose    
    }
  }
  \makeatother
  
  \tikzstyle{disp} = [display, draw, fill = cyan!20, 
  text width = 5em, align=center, minimum height = 3.5em]
  
  
  \pgfplotsset{width=10cm, compat=1.9}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
  \node (disp) [disp] {Storage};
  \node (pro2b) [process, right of = disp, xshift=2cm] {Process 2b};
  \draw [arrow] (disp) -- (pro2b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]