# TikZ: how to draw a diamond child

Tags: tikz-pgf, workflow

I need to draw an "easy" flowchart. I would do that, using the child statement. I've used (as example) an example found here. I've modified it and this is the code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}% just for showing image
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%-------definisce stile dei nodi---------------
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!50]

\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]

\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
%--------------------------------------

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
thick,
every node/.style = {
      text width = 5em,
      top color = blue!60,
      bottom color = blue!60,
      rectangle,
      font = \sffamily,
      text=white
                    },
sibling distance = 7em,
edge from parent fork down                  
  ]
\node[text width=10em] (T0) {test0}
    child {node (T1) {test1}
    %child {node[ellipse,draw] (right node) {right}};
        child {node[diamond, red] (T4) {test4}
            child {node (T5) {test5}}
        }}
    child {node (T2) {test2}}
       ;
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

But the "diamond" icon doesn't work. I've also tried to insert the "decision" style that I've created

```
 \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum
 height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
```

and neither this nor "diamond" works.

How can I draw a "diamond" (because I need to draw a decision Icon)?

Comment: I would try including the library `shapes.geometric`. You may also want to have a look to [TikZ picture shapes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87945/13304).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Claudio Fiandrino said, you need to load the `shapes` (or `shapes.geometric`) `tikzlibrary`, too, in order to make `diamond` work.

When I tried your code, the setting `every node./style={...}` gave some problems, because it was overriding the `decision`style (and all the other styles):
[image]

Since you have defined a style for each node, I'd suggest you to use them:

[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes.geometric}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}% just for showing image
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%-------definisce stile dei nodi---------------
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!50]

\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]

\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
%--------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
thick,
every node/.style = {
      font = \sffamily,
      text=white
                    },
sibling distance = 7em,
edge from parent fork down                  
  ]
\node[startstop,text width=10em] (T0) {test0}
    child {node[process] (T1) {test1}
    %child {node[ellipse,draw] (right node) {right}};
        child {node[decision,text=red] (T4) {test4}
            child {node[process] (T5) {test5}}
        }}
    child {node[process] (T2) {test2}}
       ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** some more suggestions, thanks to Claudio Fiandrino's comment:

- In order to show only the image the `standalone` class is better, and you won't need this code:

  ```
  \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}% just for showing image
  \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
  \setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
  ```

  but only `\documentclass{standalone}`.
- Usually it's better to use `\tikset{...}` than `\tikzstyle{...}` to define the style of a node. For more information, you can read the answer linked by Claudio Fiandrino ([Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)).

The new improved code, that produces the same output, is the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes.geometric}

%-------definisce stile dei nodi---------------
\tikzset{%
        startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!50},
        io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30},
        process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30},
        decision/.style={diamond, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30},
        arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth},
        every node/.style={font = \sffamily,text=white}
}

%--------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick,
    sibling distance = 7em,
    edge from parent fork down                  
  ]
\node[startstop,text width=10em] (T0) {test0}
    child {node[process] (T1) {test1}
    %child {node[ellipse,draw] (right node) {right}};
        child {node[decision,text=red] (T4) {test4}
            child {node[process] (T5) {test5}}
        }}
    child {node[process] (T2) {test2}}
       ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2:** After some trial and error, I obtained this result:

[image]

I defined three diffent styles for the `edge` between the `diamond` and its `child`s:

```
\tikzset{%
        MyEdgeA/.style={edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.west) -| (\tikzchildnode.north)}},
        MyEdgeB/.style={edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -| (\tikzchildnode.north)}},
        MyEdgeC/.style={edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east) -| (\tikzchildnode.north)}}
}
```

You can set the type of edge you want giving it as a `child` option:

```
child[MyEdgeA]{...}
```

Moreover, I changed the distance between the diamond and the subsequent nodes with:

```
level 3/.style={level distance=5em}
```

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes.geometric}

%-------definisce stile dei nodi---------------
\tikzset{%
        startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!50},
        io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30},
        process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30},
        decision/.style={diamond, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30},
        arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth},
        every node/.style={font=\sffamily,text=white}
}

\tikzset{%
        MyEdgeA/.style={edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.west) -| (\tikzchildnode.north)}},
        MyEdgeB/.style={edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -| (\tikzchildnode.north)}},
        MyEdgeC/.style={edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east) -| (\tikzchildnode.north)}}
}
%--------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick,
    sibling distance = 7em,
    edge from parent fork down,
    level 3/.style={level distance=5em}
  ]
\node[startstop,text width=10em] (T0) {test0}
    child {node[process] (T1) {test1}
    %child {node[ellipse,draw] (right node) {right}};
        child {node[decision,text=red] (T4) {test4}
            child[MyEdgeA] {node[process] (T5) {test5}
                edge from parent
                node[pos=0.5,above,text=black] {No}}
            child[MyEdgeB] {node[process] (T6) {test6}
                edge from parent
                node[pos=0.7,right,text=black] {bla bla..}}
            child[MyEdgeC] {node[process] (T7) {test7}
                edge from parent
                node[pos=0.5,above,text=black] {Yes}}
        }}
    child {node[process] (T2) {test2}}
       ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the diamond have the same line width?

Comment: @Sigur Actually, I changed only the width of the process blocks to make them fit in the block diagram; probably it is better to change the diamond, too. Thanks, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Small tips: I believe today using `standalone` gives more flexibility and `\tikzset` should be preferred to `\tikzstyle` (see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/13304).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I knew that, but since I'm not an expert in defining node styles, I didn't try it :-)! However, this time I was able to do it! Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: As last thing... I need three arrow from diamond (one west, second east, last below) with the label: "yes", "no", "bla bla bla...". Is it possible?

Renato

Comment: @RenatoP Please see my edit 2.

Answer (score 5):

To draw diamonds, you have to include the `shapes` tikz library (and for arrows the `arrows` tikz library) in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}% just for showing image
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%-------definisce stile dei nodi---------------

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw=brown, fill=green!30!yellow, inner sep=0em]

%--------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
thick,
every node/.style = {
      text width = 5em,
      fill=blue!60,
      rectangle,
      font = \sffamily,
      text=white,
      text centered,
                    },
sibling distance = 7em]%,
%edge from parent fork down                  
%  ]
%\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width=10em] (T0) {test0}
    child {node (T1) {test1}
    %child {node[ellipse,draw] (right node) {right}};
        child {node[decision] (T4) {test4}
            child {node (T5) {test5}}
        }}
    child {node (T2) {test2}}
       ;
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

I've furthermore applied some other minor changes to improve your code and result. The default background color for all nodes is set to `fill=blue!60`, rather than the bottom and top colors (because this is used for gradient fills, and it overwrites the standard fill). I've removed defined styles that were not used; I've kept and adjusted the `decision` style to which I refer (rather than `diamond`) from the tikzpicture. The `inner sep=0em` in the definition of the style `decision` is used to shrink the (imho) oversized diamond.

EDIT: If you want to use the `edge from parent fork down` you would have to shrink the diamond even more, or redefine other dimensions to prevent connecting elements and blocks from crossing each other.