# How can I draw a *manual input* and *Multi-document* nodes in a flowchart using TiKz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes

I am drawing flowcharts using TiKz.  I have found a number of suggestions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87945/tikz-picture-shapes?lq=1) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13030/node-shapes-tikz?lq=1).  However, I have not found code to draw a manual input node[image: node images] (image [source](http://www.breezetree.com/article-excel-flowchart-shapes.htm))

I could eventually figure this out, but I am new to TiKz, and would help to know if someone already has the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at the [PGFmanual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfmanual), especially the `tape` shape from the `shapes.symbols` library and the `trapezium` shape from the `shapes.geometric` library.

For the multi-document node the `double copy shadow` shadow is used with the `fill=white` option. The `double copy shadow` key is also explained in the manual and accepts any additional shadow options.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={5pt}]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,shapes.geometric,shadows}
\tikzset{
  multidocument/.style={
    shape=tape,
    draw,
    fill=white,
    tape bend top=none,
    double copy shadow},
  manual input/.style={
    shape=trapezium,
    draw,
    shape border rotate=90,
    trapezium left angle=90,
    trapezium right angle=80}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [multidocument]            {Multi-document};
\node [manual input] at (0,-1.5) {Manual Input};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

> [image]

Comment: shape border rotate=90. Clever idea! I was just searching for something like this.