# How to draw an overlaid pages image for a Tikz flowchart node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

In Natural Language Processing and related disciplines, it's common to see an "overlaid pages" image included as a node in a flowchart of a system:

```
  _____
 |  ___|__
 | |   ___|___
 | |  |       |
 | |  |       |
 |_|  |       |
   |__|       |
      |       |
      |_______|
```

The image is meant to represent a corpus or some other large collection of text data. How can I draw something like this for a Tikz flowchart?

Comment: For other and similar flowchart nodes, see “[How can I draw a *manual input* and *Multi-document* nodes in a flowchart using TiKz?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141048)”, “[TikZ picture shapes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87945)” and “[Node shapes TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13030)”.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbell: Thanks for the links. Actually, the reason I didn't use the suggestion in the first link for "multi-documents" is that 1) the resulting image looks too much like MS Word's version of the image and 2) the overlaid image in the OP is the standard in the NLP literature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `shadows` library from `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [double copy shadow={shadow xshift=-1ex,shadow yshift=1.5ex},fill=white,draw=black,thick,minimum height = 2cm,minimum width=1cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are using it in a flow chart, you may define a style via `tikzset`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\tikzset{    
    overlaid/.style={double copy shadow={shadow xshift=-1ex,shadow yshift=1.5ex},fill=white,draw=black,thick,minimum height = 2cm,minimum width=1cm,text width = 2cm, align=center},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [overlaid] {Some text goes here};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, Harish. Thanks for taking the time to share it.