# Htlatex and Tikz creates sometimes incorrect svgs

Tags: tikz-pgf, mactex, tex4ht, svg, latex2html

I have a document with a large number of Tikz pictures and I need to generate a html page from it. I have declared a driver to have TikZ pictures as SVGs (after [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35145/maintaining-layout-of-tikz-diagrams-with-tex4ht-converting-as-single-pictures)) and run `htlatex main.tex`:

```
\ifx\HCode\UnDef\else\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}\fi
```

However, for some pictures SVGs are correctly generated for some they are not (e.g., TikZ pictures from answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20324/looking-for-an-example-of-an-olap-cube-with-dimensions-drawn-in-tikz)). For most of them, I got *XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag* error with `</text>` mentioned, e.g.:

```
alt="ExAAel "  class="pic-halign" ></text>
```

Is there any website that would help me to understand which kind of TikZ pictures are supported by htlatex?

UPDATE:

Because of problems with SVG generation, I decided to try to generate pngs. I use tikzexternalize as [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey) suggested. I am on MacOs so I also needed to install (with macports) poppler to have pdftoppm and pnmtopng. Here is my example document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures_external/]

\begin{document}

\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" && pdftoppm "\image.pdf" | pnmtopng > "\image.png"}} 

 \tikzset{external/figure name={tikz-figure}}

 \begin{tikzpicture}  
  % Picture code
\end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

Unfortunately I got the following error:

> ```
> > Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error
> > -interact ion=batchmode -jobname "figures_external/braids-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalreal
> > job{example_tikz_external}\input{example_tikz_external}" && pdftoppm
> > "figures_e xternal/braids-figure0.pdf" | pnmtopng >
> > "figures_external/braids-figure0.png"' did NOT result in a usable
> > output file 'figures_external/braids-figure0' (expe cted one of
> > .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system
> > calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is
> > also nam ed 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command
> > simply failed? Error messages can be found in
> > 'figures_external/braids-figure0.log'. If you continu e now, I'll try
> > to typeset the picture. See the tikz package documentation for
> > explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help.
> ```

I wonder what could be a reason that the externalize call fails.

Comment: My general principle when using TikZ to generate SVGs is that it works fine on pictures without text but is unreliable for pictures with text.

Comment: Is it possible to generate pngs from tikz pictures?

Comment: Take a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11866/86  It is also possible to modify the system command used in the externalisation library to generate PNGs directly.

Comment: Do you mean that I should move TikZ pictures to separated tex files and apply this method?

Comment: I think I'd go for the externalisation method.  Here's what I use: `\usetikzlibrary{external}
  \tikzexternalize
  \tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex       \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" && pdftoppm "\image.pdf" | pnmtopng > "\image.png"}}
  \tikzset{external/figure name={braids-figure}}
`

Comment: Could you put a short latex example as an answer with this command? I will mark it as correct, because this command solves my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A modified version of the michal.h21 example, which works for me is (MacOS, MacTex 2011):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
\tikzexternalize[mode=only graphics]
\tikzset{png export/.style={/pgf/images/external info,/pgf/images/include external/.code={%
\includegraphics[width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight]{##1.png}%
}
}
}
\tikzset{png export}% 
}{%
\tikzexternalize%
\tikzset{pdf export/.style={/pgf/images/external info,/pgf/images/include external/.code={%
\includegraphics[width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight]{##1.pdf}%
}
}
}
\tikzset{pdf export}% 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \path (0,0) node[draw] (A) {A};
      \path (2,0) node[draw] (B) {B};
      \draw (A) -- (B) node[midway,above = 0 em] {via};
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The command sequence is the same as michal.h21 suggested. It is still not perfect solution, because for some pictures I got *! Undefined control sequence \Gin@ewidth ->\pgfexternalwidth*  error.

Regarding the error, I got it for picture that uses *remember picture*, such as an example from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/.

Comment: Since PDF export is the default for `tikz`, there should not be a need to define `pdf export` style.

Answer (score 7):

In order to use the `tikz externalize` library, you need to call latex with `--shell-escape` option, so it can run the external commands. in `tex4ht` running of the external commands is not allowed.

My solution is to run first `pdflatex file -shell-escape` to get the pdf figures, then comvert pdf files to png using `imagemagick` and finally run `htlatex` to insert the generated png.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
\tikzexternalize[mode=only graphics]
}{
\tikzexternalize
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
png export/.style={
  /pgf/images/external info,
  /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
    \includegraphics
       [width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight]
       {##1.png}%
   }
  }
}

 \tikzset{png export}

\begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \path (0,0) node[draw] (A) {A};
      \path (2,0) node[draw] (B) {B};
      \draw (A) -- (B) node[midway,above = 0 em] {via};
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

command sequence:

```
pdflatex myfile -shell-escape
for i in example-figure*.pdf; do convert -density 300 $i `echo $i | sed -e 's/\.pdf/\.png/g'`; done
htlatex myfile
```

Comment: After running pdflatex example.tex  -shell-escape, I get the following error on the line with \tikzset{png export}: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/pgf/images/external info'

Comment: When I remove /pgf/images/external info from style, I keep getting only the Package tikz Error.

Comment: I have changed {##1.png}% to {##1.pdf}% and it works fine. Thank you for your help. I need to find a better condition than @ifpackageloaded[tex4h], because it does not work as expected.

Comment: there was error in the shell command, it generated wrong filenames for the png files

Comment: The error is in tex file. Both the \tikzset should be executed only if tex4th is loaded. Moving both just after \tikzexternalize[mode=only graphics] solves my problem.

Comment: See my answer for an example that works for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Under Windows 7, automatic conversion from PDF to PNG can be done calling the batch file (you may call it `pdf2png.bat`) containing the single line `for %%x in (%~n1-figure*.pdf) do (convert -density 300 %%x %%~nx.png)`, with the `tex` file as argument (e.g. `pdf2png example.tex`).

Answer (score 2):

With the following solution (slightly modified from Skarab's one) you don't need the intermediate step of pdf->png conversion "by hand": it is performed automatically (you still need `imagemagick` installed in your system though). It works for me with TeXLive under Ubuntu:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzset{
    png copy/.style={
        external/system call={
            pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource";
            convert -density 300 -transparent white "\image.pdf" "\image.png"
        }
    }
}
\tikzset{png copy}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
\tikzexternalize[mode=only graphics]
\tikzset{png export/.style={/pgf/images/external info,/pgf/images/include external/.code={\includegraphics[width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight]{##1.png}}}}
\tikzset{png export}
}{
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{pdf export/.style={/pgf/images/external info,/pgf/images/include external/.code={\includegraphics[width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight]{##1.pdf}}}}
\tikzset{pdf export}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \path (0,0) node[draw] (A) {A};
      \path (2,0) node[draw] (B) {B};
      \draw (A) -- (B) node[midway,above = 0 em] {via};
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Therefore with this solution you need just 2 steps to obtain the final `tex4ht` output:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape mytexfile
htlatex mytexfile
```

Faster, cleaner and you don't have to worry about OS batch conversion command. I got the clue from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55635/28685).