# In which order execute htlatex and bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, tex4ht

I would like to learn the correct order of calling *htlatex* and *bibtex*. So far I tried the following order:

```
htlatex main
bibtex main
htlatex main
htlatex main
```

and ([I use pdflatex to generate pdfs from TikZ pictures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40135/htlatex-and-tikz-creates-sometimes-incorrect-svgs)):

```
pdflatex
pdflatex
bibtex main
pdflatex
htlatex main
```

But neither of them works. Could anybody write me what is the correct order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I need to use latex not pdflatex. Second, the correct order is:

```
latex main 
makeglossaries main
bibtex main
latex main
latex main
htlatex main
```

In my case --- I need to generate external pictures from TikZ figures -- I call latex in the following way:

```
latex -src -interaction=nonstopmode -max-print-line=120 -enable-write18 main
```