# Tex4ebook and bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, tex4ebook

What is the preferred way of using bibliographies with Tex4ebook? I have tried using bibtex and biblatex but cannot get the bibliography to show on the epub.

I tried the method in [In which order execute htlatex and bibtex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42608/in-which-order-execute-htlatex-and-bibtex), but it doesn't produce any references?

I'm using the latest Miktex if that's relevant.

Thank you.

@Michal.21

The log file is at https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuihY7Zd3CrNdgot943134AzNDc

Thank you.

Update 2:

Miktex has an old file: biblatex.4ht (2015-02-04-14:23).

I replaced it with your version and now the sequence make4ht - biber - make4ht gives a proper html file with hyperlinks for the reference. A single make4ht gives the reference without the links. Tex4ebook still doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't get such warnings in the log. Could you try to use the [current `biblatex.4ht` file](https://gist.github.com/michal-h21/8ec83c30cc1b303db57f54d6bc4616b4)? It is possible that Miktex uses a wrong version.

Comment: so it seems that miktex has really old `biblatex.4ht` version. could you also try to [install tex4ebook manually](https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook/blob/master/INSTALL.md)?

Comment: @michal.h21It didn't work either. I suspect my Miktex is corrupted. I will try a new install or switch to Texlive. Many thanks.

Comment: I should update tex4ebook as well, there was a lot of changes recently, I wanted to wait until I finish some features, but it is possible that the version in TeX distributions has some issues which I can't see, as I use the development version.

Comment: @michal.h21 An update for the distributions would be very useful. Also why not include the helper functions like addfont4ht.sty as well in the archive so users have everything they need to run tex4ebook. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `make4ht` build file to call `biber` or `bibtex` directly in the `tex4ebook` run. Save the following file as `mybuild.mk4`:

```
Make:add("biber","biber ${input}")
Make:htlatex {}
Make:biber {}
Make:htlatex {}
```

You can select the build file using `-e` option (alternatively, you can name it as your TeX file, but with `.mk4` extension)

```
tex4ebook -e mybuild.mk4 filename.tex
```

The following sample file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{xampl.bib}
\title{Základní dokument v češtině}
\author{Michal Hoftich}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Úvod}
Příliš žluťoučký kůň \textit{úpěl} \textbf{ďábelské ódy} \parencite{article-full}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Is displayed in this way:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response but I still don't get the references. I tried the MWE from https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/310 and it doesn't give the reference either. Normal LaTex works fine and gives the reference.

Comment: @user41974 that example works fine for me. Do you get any compilation errors? Could you try to compile it using `make4ht` instead of `tex4ebook`?

Comment: @Michael.h21 make4ht doesn't work either. Looking at the log file it gives "LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber". I did this and ran make4ht again but it doesn't help. Are you using Miktex?

Comment: @Michael.h21 It also gives an error "l.20 --- TeX4ht warning --- Problem with 'list' environment. Expected syntax: \begin{list}{label}{spacing} \item.... \end{list} ---" near the end of the log file.

Comment: @user41974 no, I am using TL on Linux. could you update your question with full log of `tex4ebook` run? It should be possible to get it using `tex4ebook -e mybuild.mk4 filename > full.log`

Comment: Hello, I wonder how to make the references correct for tex4ebook? I encountered the reference issues (including for TOC, for in-text references and bibliographies). I run tex4ebook twice, which seemingly fixes the problem. I wonder how I can take advantage of build files to avoid this situation? Sorry for a silly question. I am a newbie. Thanks!

Comment: @FrankScience do you have a sample document? It may depend on used packages and other things.  You can definitely use build files to specify the number of compilations and invocations of Bibtex or Biber.

Comment: Thanks. Sample documents are https://arxiv.org/e-print/1401.1044 and https://github.com/stacks/stacks-project/blob/master/more-algebra.tex. [A document](https://github.com/stacks/stacks-project/blob/master/more-algebra.tex) for the compilation of the later one: seemingly it's a normal latex; bibtex; latex; latex. Well, in order to compile these codes, seemingly a bunch of code hacking is necessary.

Comment: @FrankScience I get lot of errors with that project, it doesn't even compile for me.

Comment: For stacks project, I edited preamble: document class is modified to be amsart (ignoring the preferred stacks-project), and I moved most of the content from preamble to document. Applying a bunch of regular expressions to replace non-standard _\mathfrak, etc, I succeeded to compile more-algebra.tex. What a hardship.

Comment: @FrankScience the macro definitions should be moved to a `sty` file, they can be then redefined and configured in a corresponding `4ht` file. Custom classes generally need `4ht` file that loads basic configurations, at least like [this](https://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn5.html#QQ1-5-30).

Answer (score 3):

Save the following as `mybuild.mk4` and run with `tex4ebook -e mybuild.mk4 filename.tex`, notice the extra `htlatex` to complete the cycle. It worked for me.

```
Make:add("biber","biber ${input}")
Make:htlatex {}
Make:biber {}
Make:htlatex {}
Make:htlatex {}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Please, can you add an explanation, with a complete code or observation?

Comment: I suggest to use `latexmk`, i.e. `Make:latexmk {}` (this is a new feature), which computes automatically what bib engine you need and the times of `latex` to run.