# Double bibliography entries in table of contents with latest tex4ebook and texlive 2020

Tags: biblatex, texlive, tex4ebook

This is a followup of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344859/tex4ebook-and-bibliographies).

sample.tex:

```
\documentclass[ebook,12pt,oneside,openany]{memoir}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{Hiemenz,
author={Hiemenz},
title={Polymer Chemistry}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{test}

\title{Book}
\author{Author}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents \newpage

\chapter{C1}

Here comes a quotation \cite{Hiemenz}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

mybuild.mk4:

```
Make:add("biber","biber ${input}")
Make:htlatex {}
Make:biber {}
Make:htlatex {}
Make:htlatex {}
Make:htlatex {}
```

command:

```
tex4ebook -e mybuild.mk4 sample.tex
```

This gives two entries for the bibliography in the table of contents (see picture).

[image: toc for ebook]

It used to work in previous versions like Texlive 2019.

How can this be fixed thanks.

Update:

Using the config file suggested by @michal.h21 still has a problem with the contents since the bibliography doesn't show on the contents :

[image: texlive 2020]

Running on texlive 2019 (without the config file) is fine:

[image: texlive 2019]

Update 2:

Here is what I get with the new build file.

[image: result for new version of build file]

The bibliography is gone. Also a minor error - 1 C1 is shown as 1C1 in TOC.

Also for my information, does the fix have to be in the build file and not the tex4ebook source. I think it would be easier for the user if he doesn't have to add things to the build file.

Thanks again.

Comment: Instead of `\bibliography` use `\addbibresource`

Comment: Doesn't help, problem is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: it seems that my original solution also removes bibliography from TOC, which is not desired

Here is alternative using `make4ht` build file:

```lua
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"

-- process the NCX file, it contains bookmarks
local ncxprocess = domfilter {
  function(dom)
    for _, navpoint in ipairs(dom:query_selector("navPoint")) do
       -- get section text, trim spaces and make it lowercase
       local text = navpoint:query_selector("text")[1]:get_text():gsub("^%s*", ""):gsub("%s*$", ""):lower()
       -- match bibliography
       if text == "bibliography" then
         -- remove first bibliography node
         navpoint:remove_node()
         -- and break processing. the second bibliography booksmark will be preserved
         break
       end
    end
    for _, el in ipairs(dom:query_selector("text")) do
      local text = el:get_text()
      -- replace element text with a new text node containing original text
      el._children = {el:create_text_node(text)}
    end

    return dom
  end
}

local ncxclean = filter {
  function(s)
    -- remove unvanted spaces at the start of the NCX file
    local s=s:gsub("^%s*", ""):gsub("%s*$", "")
    return s
  end
}

Make:add("biber","biber ${input}")

-- use tex4ebook -m draft to speed up compilation, it is not necessary to execute biber and multiple LaTeX calls
-- every time you compile the document
if mode=="draft" then
  Make:htlatex {}
else
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:biber {}
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
end

-- the NCX file at this point is not valid XML, we need to clean it using Tidy first
-- Make:match("ncx$", "tidy -m -xml -utf8 -q -i ${filename}")
Make:match("ncx$", ncxclean)
-- remove bibliography
Make:match("ncx$", ncxprocess)
```

It uses LuaXML DOM processing methods to find the first bibliography section and removes it from the bookmarks.

---

TeX4ebook adds all sectioning commands, including starred versions to the bookmarks. Memoir uses the starred command, but in addition to that, it also adds a bibliography to TOC. You can disable the additional TOC entry using this config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\nobibintoctrue
\EndPreamble
```

The resulting bookmarks:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works now. For my reference, what changed - was it memoir or tex4ebook. As I said it worked on texlive 2019.

Comment: Actually it doesn't quite work - see update.

Comment: @user41974 ah, I see. Maybe it will be easiest to remove the duplicate entry using Lua scripting. I will try it later.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, though I still don't understand why it doesn't work now and it was ok with texlive 2019.

Comment: @user41974 I've updated my answer. I think we didn't add starred sections to bookmarks in the past, but this resulted in missing bibliography or index sections in bookmarks with default classes.

Comment: It still doesn't work - please see update 2.

Comment: @michael.h21 Sorry, it works if I don't use the config file. Space issue is still there.

Comment: @michael.h21 Is there a way to fix the missing space in the TOC, thanks.

Comment: @user41974 This is actually a bug in `tex4ebook`. I've updated the `tex4ebook` sources. In the meantime, you can try the updated `.mk4` file that should fix the spacing issue.

Comment: @michael.h21 Using the new build file and running command `tex4ebook -a info -c ebook.cfg -e mybuild.mk4 sample.tex` works. Will `\nobibintoctrue` in ebook.cfg and the ncx commands in mybuild.mk4 still be needed with the new version of tex4ebook, thanks.

Comment: @user41974 you shouldn't beed the `.cfg` file with this build file. The TeX4ebook update should fix the space issue, I don't have any good solution for the duplicate TOC entry unfortunatelly.

Comment: @michael.h21 I still need `\nobibintoctrue` in ebook.cfg even with the new tex4book (texlive now has new version) otherwise get duplicate bibliography entries in TOC.

Comment: @michael.h21 With the latest version of tex4ebook on texlive and using epub3 output the `\nobibintoctrue` is not needed, thanks.

Comment: @user41974 that's great!