# From inside a LaTeX article, I want to render several parts of the code into a separate png (a "render pass")

Tags: tikz-external, png

I have a long article with many, say, TikZ images. Let's say it looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    ...much more stuff...
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
    ...much more stuff...
\end{document}
```

Now from this file, I want to render the whole article into a pdf and also the tikzpicture into a PNG. This has to happen automatically with latex since I want to write a package that uses this.

(So answering "Oh, just copy and paste the image code to a separate file." is not helpful.)

Comment: Also, if someone knows a good tag for this question, I will be happy to include it!

Comment: Not to png, but to pdf.... Yes you can use tikz external library.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8641/export-eps-figures-from-tikz

Comment: @HarishKumar: You can also generate PNGs using the `external` library, if you have ImageMagick (or presumably some other converter) installed.

Comment: @Jake: I knew from outside we can. But from inside... well now I know. Thanks and upvoted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the TikZ `external` library to automatically generate PNGs of your `tikzpicture`s.

The style

```
\tikzset{
    png export/.style={
        external/system call={
            pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource";
            convert -density 300 -transparent white "\image.pdf" "\image.png"
        }
    }
}
```

specifies that after the `tikzpicture` is compiled using `pdflatex`, ImageMagick (`convert`) is used for generating a PNG from the PDF. This requires `pdflatex` to be called with `-shell-escape`.

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{
    png export/.style={
        external/system call={
            pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource";
            convert -density 300 -transparent white "\image.pdf" "\image.png"
        }
    }
}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{png export}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{external/force remake}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [orange,scale=10] {1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [cyan,scale=10] {2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Of course, for this to work we have to call `pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex` instead of `pdflatex file.tex`.

Comment: @Turion: Yes, you're right, I forgot to mention that.