# Producing odt from tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex4ht, open-office

How can I produce an `.odt` file from a `.tex` source which includes `\tikzpicture`?

I tried `mk4ht oolatex test.tex` but I only be able to produce an empty `.odt` file from the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) node[draw] (A) {A};
    \path (2,0) node[draw] (B) {B};
    \draw (A) -- (B) node[midway,above = 0 em] {via};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am open to other way to get my `.odt` file.

Comment: I think openoffice doesn't support svg embedding. You can include diagrams as png figures. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40135/2891 for examples where tikz externalization is used to compile diagrams to png and then including. This works for me with oolatex.

Comment: @michal.h21 svg are well supported by OpenOffice (3.2 at least), so the problem comes from elsewhere. In an other hand, I tried your solution but I was unable to produce any png files. I get the following error `! Undefined control sequence.
\Gin@ewidth ->\pgfexternalwidth`

Comment: did you include the graphicx package in your document?

Comment: @michal.h21 yes I add `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\usetikzlibrary{external}` as you did in your example.