# Pass several comma separated TikZ options to a single keyval key

Tags: tikz-pgf, delimiters, key-value

I'm still improving my answer to [Need help creating a 3D cube from a 2D set of nodes in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29877/need-help-creating-a-3d-cube-from-a-2d-set-of-nodes-in-tikz/29882#29882). One of the options should be to emphasize the edges of the cuboid. This would mean e.g.

```
\draw[red, very thick, dashed] <some coordinates>
```

I'm using `keyval` to define parameters for the cuboid. Now my quesrion is, how can I pass all these commands to a single key? I would do this:

```
\tikzcuboid{%
        emphedge=Y,%
        emphstyle=very thick,
    }
```

I can only pass one option (here `very thick`), as further commas (e.g. `very thick, red, dashed`) are interpreted as delimiters for keys by `keyval`. I tried several things, like

```
emphstyle={very thick, red, dashed}
emphstyle=style={very thick, red, dashed}
emphstyle=(very thick, red, dashed)
```

So my question basically is: are there some kind of special delimiters for `keyval` that I can put a list of comma separated arguments in? These special delimiters should however not be passed on, since this would probably cause problems with `TikZ`.

Comment: Why are you using `keyval` and not `pgfkeys`? Having two different key/value packages used together just causes troubles. You don't provide a MWE so I can't test anything, but when wrapping the comma separated list in `{ }` doesn't protect the commas try two sets of braces, e.g. `emphstyle={{very thick, red, dashed}}`. One might be already removed by `keyval`.

Comment: Have a look at the linked question, you find an (almost) MWE there (under **Edit 3**), after the definitions there are 6 examples. Thanks for the hint about double  braces, I'll try that.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. And I used `keyval` as I had an old `.tex` file where I used it and thus had a starting point. To be honest, I didn't know `pgfkeys` existed.

Comment: Imho one layer of braces should be enough to protect the commas in the value. So if `emphstyle={very thick, red, dashed}` doesn't work the problem is somewhere in the definition/processing/code of the emphstyle-key.

Comment: Like Martin, I prefer `pgfkeys` but `xkeyval`is a solution because  during a period, in the sources of `Tikz`, `xkeyval` and `pgfkeys` worked together. Now I'm not sure If `xkeyval` is not faster than `pgfkeys`.

Comment: @Altermundus: `xkeyval` might be faster as `pgfkeys` but IMHO it would be weird to not use `pgfkeys` for something TikZ related.

Comment: @Martin I agree with you and I prefer `pgfkeys` but do not forget two arguments: the first is that many packages use xkeyval and the second is that early versions of Tikz too. Some users have become accustomed to use `xkeyval` to create their own packages. It's not easy to learn `pgfkeys`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To protect the commas in your code you can do this

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzcuboid@emphedge}{Y}}%
    {\protected@edef\cube@temp{%
\noexpand\draw[\tikzcuboid@emphstyle](0,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,\dimy,\dimz) -- (0,\dimy,\dimz) -- cycle;     
\noexpand\draw[\tikzcuboid@emphstyle] (0,\dimy,\dimz) -- (0,0,\dimz) -- (\dimx,0,\dimz) -- (\dimx,\dimy,\dimz);
\noexpand\draw[\tikzcuboid@emphstyle](\dimx,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,0,0) -- (\dimx,0,\dimz);
      }\cube@temp   
    }%
    {}
```

the result with

```
\tikzcuboid{%
    shiftx=16cm,%
    shifty=8cm,%
    scale=1.00,%
    rotation=0,%
    densityx=2,%
    densityy=2,%
    densityz=2,%
    dimx=4,%
    dimy=4,%
    dimy=4,%
    linefront=green!75!black,%
    linetop=green!50!black,%
    lineright=green!25!black,%
    fillfront=green!25!white,%
    filltop=green!50!white,%
    fillright=green!75!white,%
    emphedge=Y,%
    emphstyle={very thick, red, dashed}
}
```

and the picture

[image]

Comment: Nice, it works! However, you wrote the dirst `\draw` twice. Furthermore I noticed that drawing three cycles is not good, as e.g. dashed lines are overwritten, my bad. So I'll take the liberty to edit your post.

Comment: @Tom: no problem for the code !

Answer (score 7):

If you'd be willing to switch to using `\pgfkeys` then this is quite simple.  It's possible to declare a key to be an alias to a list of keys.  This is done via:

```
\tikzset{my key/.style={list,of,other,keys}}
```

Then the key `my key` expands to `list,of,other,keys` in the proper way.

Here's an example of how to do it, based on your code at the linked question.  I've added some spaces into the key names to make them easier (which meant that I saw some errors: you had `dimy` in place of `dimz` a couple of times).  I've replaced the `\ifthenelse` by a boolean key.  I've also condensed the `line` and `fill` keys to one single style which gives greater flexibility.  You could replace the `\filldraw` by a simple `\path` for maximum flexibility here, then the grids could be filled or not filled at leisure.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
%====================================
%emphasize vertices --> switch and emph style (e.g. thick,black)
%====================================

\newif\ifcuboidshaded
\newif\ifcuboidemphedge

\tikzset{
  cuboid/.is family,
  cuboid,
  shift x/.initial=0,
  shift y/.initial=0,
  dim x/.initial=3,
  dim y/.initial=3,
  dim z/.initial=3,
  scale/.initial=1,
  density x/.initial=1,
  density y/.initial=1,
  density z/.initial=1,
  rotation/.initial=0,
  angle x/.initial=0,
  angle y/.initial=90,
  angle z/.initial=225,
  scale x/.initial=1,
  scale y/.initial=1,
  scale z/.initial=sqrt(0.5),
  front/.style={draw=black,fill=white},
  top/.style={draw=black,fill=white},
  right/.style={draw=black,fill=white},
  shaded/.is if=cuboidshaded,
  shade color/.initial=black,
  shade perc/.initial=25,
  emph edge/.is if=cuboidemphedge,
  emph style/.style={thick},
}

\newcommand{\tikzcuboidkey}[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cuboid/#1}}

% Commands
\newcommand{\tikzcuboid}[1]{
    \tikzset{cuboid,#1} % Process Keys passed to command
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\vectorxx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scale x}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{angle x})}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\vectorxy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scale x}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{angle x})}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\vectoryx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scale y}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{angle y})}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\vectoryy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scale y}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{angle y})}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\vectorzx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scale z}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{angle z})}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\vectorzy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scale z}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{angle z})}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=\tikzcuboidkey{shift x}, yshift=\tikzcuboidkey{shift y}, scale=\tikzcuboidkey{scale}, rotate=\tikzcuboidkey{rotation}, x={(\vectorxx,\vectorxy)}, y={(\vectoryx,\vectoryy)}, z={(\vectorzx,\vectorzy)}]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingx}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{density x}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingy}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{density y}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingz}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{density z}}
    \newcommand{\dimx}{\tikzcuboidkey{dim x}}
    \newcommand{\dimy}{\tikzcuboidkey{dim y}}
    \newcommand{\dimz}{\tikzcuboidkey{dim z}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondx}{2*\steppingx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondy}{2*\steppingy}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondz}{2*\steppingz}
    \foreach \x in {\steppingx,\secondx,...,\dimx}
    {   \foreach \y in {\steppingy,\secondy,...,\dimy}
        {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowx}{(\x-\steppingx)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowy}{(\y-\steppingy)}
            \filldraw[cuboid/front] (\lowx,\lowy,\dimz) -- (\lowx,\y,\dimz) -- (\x,\y,\dimz) -- (\x,\lowy,\dimz) -- cycle;

        }
    }
    \foreach \x in {\steppingx,\secondx,...,\dimx}
    {   \foreach \z in {\steppingz,\secondz,...,\dimz}
        {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowx}{(\x-\steppingx)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowz}{(\z-\steppingz)}
            \filldraw[cuboid/top] (\lowx,\dimy,\lowz) -- (\lowx,\dimy,\z) -- (\x,\dimy,\z) -- (\x,\dimy,\lowz) -- cycle;
        }
    }
    \foreach \y in {\steppingy,\secondy,...,\dimy}
    {   \foreach \z in {\steppingz,\secondz,...,\dimz}
        {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowy}{(\y-\steppingy)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowz}{(\z-\steppingz)}
            \filldraw[cuboid/right] (\dimx,\lowy,\lowz) -- (\dimx,\lowy,\z) -- (\dimx,\y,\z) -- (\dimx,\y,\lowz) -- cycle;
        }
    }
    \ifcuboidemphedge
        \draw[cuboid/emph style] (0,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,\dimy,\dimz) -- (0,\dimy,\dimz) -- cycle;%
        \draw[cuboid/emph style] (0,\dimy,\dimz) -- (0,0,\dimz) -- (\dimx,0,\dimz) -- (\dimx,\dimy,\dimz);%
        \draw[cuboid/emph style] (\dimx,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,0,0) -- (\dimx,0,\dimz);%
    \fi
    \end{scope}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzcuboid{shift x=0cm,%
        shift y=0cm,%
        scale=1.00,%
        rotation=30,%
        density x=1,%
        density y=2,%
        density z=3,%
        dim x=4,%
        dim y=5,%
        dim z=2,%
        front/.style={draw=yellow!30!black,fill=yellow!30!white},%
        top/.style={draw=red!30!black,fill=red!30!white},%
        right/.style={draw=blue!30!black,fill=blue!30!white}%
    }
    \tikzcuboid{%
        shift x=0cm,%
        shift y=8cm,%
        scale=1.00,%
        rotation=60,%
        density x=3,%
        density y=2,%
        density z=5,%
        dim x=4,%
        dim y=4,%
        dim z=4,%
        front/.style={draw=orange!75!black,fill=orange!75!white},%
        top/.style={draw=green!75!black,fill=green!75!white},%
        right/.style={draw=violet!75!black,fill=violet!75!white}%
    }
    \tikzcuboid{%
        shift x=8cm,%
        shift y=8cm,%
        scale=1.00,%
        rotation=45,%
        density x=1,%
        density y=(2/3),%
        density z=2,%
        dim x=3,%
        dim y=3,%
        dim y=3,%
        front/.style={draw=white!15!black,fill=black!15!white},%
        top/.style={draw=white!30!black,fill=black!30!white},%
        right/.style={draw=white!45!black,fill=black!45!white}%
    }
    \tikzcuboid{%
        shift x=8cm,%
        shift y=0cm,%
        scale=1.00,%
        rotation=75,%
        density x=2,%
        density y=3,%
        density z=2,%
        dim x=6,%
        dim y=8,%
        dim z=1,%
        front/.style={draw=red!75!black,fill=red!25!white},%
        top/.style={draw=red!50!black,fill=red!50!white},%
        right/.style={draw=red!25!black,fill=red!75!white}%
    }
    \tikzcuboid{%
        shift x=16cm,%
        shift y=8cm,%
        scale=1.00,%
        rotation=0,%
        density x=2,%
        density y=2,%
        density z=2,%
        dim x=4,%
        dim y=4,%
        dim y=4,%
        front/.style={draw=green!75!black,fill=green!25!white},%
        top/.style={draw=green!50!black,fill=green!50!white},%
        right/.style={draw=green!25!black,fill=green!75!white},%
        emph edge,%
        emph style/.style={very thick},
    }
    \tikzcuboid{%
        shift x=16cm,%
        shift y=0cm,%
        scale=1.00,%
        rotation=0,%
        density x=1,%
        density y=1,%
        density z=1,%
        dim x=4,%
        dim y=4,%
        dim z=4,%
        front/.style={draw=blue!75!black,fill=blue!25!white},%
        right/.style={draw=blue!25!black,fill=blue!75!white},%
        top/.style={draw=blue!50!black,fill=blue!50!white},%
        angle x=15,%
        angle y=135,%
        angle z=225,%
        scale x=1,%
        scale y=1,%
        scale z=1,%
        emph edge=false,%
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the effort, it works fine. I think I'll switch to `pgfkeys`, however I will still write keys as `dimx` (things like `verythick` instead of `very thick` constantly break my neck, I really don't like spaces in keys or variables). I also spotted the errors in the other post, I will correct them with my next edit. I'm sorry I can award only one "accepted answer", yours would deserve it as well

Comment: Oh, and as I pointed out below Altermundus' post, drawing three cycles for emphasizing is only fine for slid lines, but not for e.g. dashed ones, so I changed it there.

Comment: As an alternative to the spaces, you could define them hierarchically.  Then you have a *directory* called `dim` with three subkeys `dim/x`, `dim/y`, and `dim/z`.  (I'm not saying you *should* do this, just saying that it's possible.)

Comment: And as penance for not accepting my answer, you should make a proper package out of your code and upload it to CTAN.

Comment: Okay, will do :D