# Enable rectangle to have a 3-D vision

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw a rectangle with 3-D vision, or 3-D rectangle. I also need to fill it with text.
[image]

Comment: Are you bound to [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)? [`pstricks`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) can do this...

Comment: Take a look at [Need help creating a 3D Cube from a Set of Nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29877/need-help-creating-a-3d-cube-from-a-2d-set-of-nodes-in-tikz)

Comment: @Werner: No, it should not be restricted to tikz. As long as it can output this 3-D rectangle in latex, any way is ok. Can you give a simple example?

Comment: ... and another (related) shameless [advertisement](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35289/7417) `:)`

Comment: @Christian thanks for your provided link. It is exactly what I want.