# tensor math graphic

Tags: matrices, 3d, tikz-matrix, tensor

Is there any good packages for creating a graphic similar to this:

[image]

in order to display how tensor math is working to a less mathematically skilled audience?

It would be nice to have the tensor math laid out in standard math notation, but then show arrows or coloring connecting the numbers for the operation of interest and expand the tensor to matrices that are stacked on top of each other as the image above shows.

Something similar to this but only with higher dimensionality:

[image: here]
<sub>(source: [texample.net](http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/PNG/matrix-multiplication.png))</sub>

Comment: Possibly partially related : [Placing text on face of 3d cube](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254010/placing-text-on-face-of-3d-cube) and [Rotated numbers on planes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310688/rotated-numbers-on-planes)

Comment: Also see [Is it possible to produce data cubes in Latex with reasonable effort?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244357/is-it-possible-to-produce-data-cubes-in-latex-with-reasonable-effort)