# How to draw a sliced cube shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a box, sliced into rectangles. I followed the code from here [Need help creating a 3D cube from a 2D set of nodes in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29877/need-help-creating-a-3d-cube-from-a-2d-set-of-nodes-in-tikz) but latex is too difficult so i dont know how to edit the code from there

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in{0,...,4}
{   \draw (0,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,4);
    \draw (\x ,0,4) -- (\x ,4,4);
    \draw (4,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,0);
    \draw (\x ,4,4) -- (\x ,4,0);
    \draw (4,0,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
    \draw (0,4,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Below is what Id like (edited from paint)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a version which is very close to your MWE. There are arguably more elegant ways of doing this with the 3d library and/or tikz-3dplot.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in{0,...,4}
{   \draw (0,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,4);
    \ifnum\x=0
    \draw (\x ,0,4) -- (\x ,4,4);
    \else
    \draw (\x ,0,4) -- (\x ,0.1,4)  (\x ,0.9,4) -- (\x ,1.1,4)
    (\x ,1.9,4) -- (\x ,2.1,4) (\x ,2.9,4) -- (\x ,3.1,4)
    (\x ,3.9,4) -- (\x ,4,4);
    \fi
    \draw (4,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,0);
    \ifnum\x=0
    \draw (\x ,4,4) -- (\x ,4,0);
    \else
    \draw (\x,4,0) -- (\x,4,0.1)  (\x,4,0.9) -- (\x,4,1.1)
    (\x,4,1.9) -- (\x,4,2.1) (\x,4,2.9) -- (\x,4,3.1)
    (\x,4,3.9) -- (\x,4,4);
    \fi
    \draw (4,0,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
    \draw (0,4,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]