# How to make cuboids with different dimensions xyz with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I want to plot blocks (transportation pallets). Each block has 0.8m width, 1.2m depth, and 2.15m high, and they are placed horizontally (only one block height) grouped 2x2, 3x3, 4x4, 5x5, 6x6, 7x7 blocks.

I have been testing the two solutions of ["Need help creating a 3D cube from a 2D set of nodes in TikZ
"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29877/need-help-creating-a-3d-cube-from-a-2d-set-of-nodes-in-tikz) but I do not know how to adapt the code to my problem.

For example, I would like to change the cuboids dimensions of this example:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newif\ifcuboidshade
\newif\ifcuboidemphedge

\tikzset{
  cuboid/.is family,
  cuboid,
  shiftx/.initial=0,
  shifty/.initial=0,
  dimx/.initial=3,
  dimy/.initial=3,
  dimz/.initial=3,
  scale/.initial=1,
  densityx/.initial=1,
  densityy/.initial=1,
  densityz/.initial=1,
  rotation/.initial=0,
  anglex/.initial=0,
  angley/.initial=90,
  anglez/.initial=225,
  scalex/.initial=1,
  scaley/.initial=1,
  scalez/.initial=0.5,
  front/.style={draw=black,fill=white},
  top/.style={draw=black,fill=white},
  right/.style={draw=black,fill=white},
  shade/.is if=cuboidshade,
  shadecolordark/.initial=black,
  shadecolorlight/.initial=white,
  shadeopacity/.initial=0.15,
  shadesamples/.initial=16,
  emphedge/.is if=cuboidemphedge,
  emphstyle/.style={thick},
}

\newcommand{\tikzcuboidkey}[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cuboid/#1}}

% Commands
\newcommand{\tikzcuboid}[1]{
    \tikzset{cuboid,#1} % Process Keys passed to command
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorxx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalex}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{anglex})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorxy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalex}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{anglex})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectoryx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scaley}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{angley})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectoryy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scaley}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{angley})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorzx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalez}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{anglez})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorzy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalez}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{anglez})*28.452756}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=\tikzcuboidkey{shiftx}, yshift=\tikzcuboidkey{shifty}, scale=\tikzcuboidkey{scale}, rotate=\tikzcuboidkey{rotation}, x={(\vectorxx,\vectorxy)}, y={(\vectoryx,\vectoryy)}, z={(\vectorzx,\vectorzy)}]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingx}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{densityx}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingy}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{densityy}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingz}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{densityz}}
  \newcommand{\dimx}{\tikzcuboidkey{dimx}}
  \newcommand{\dimy}{\tikzcuboidkey{dimy}}
  \newcommand{\dimz}{\tikzcuboidkey{dimz}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondx}{2*\steppingx}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondy}{2*\steppingy}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondz}{2*\steppingz}
  \foreach \x in {\steppingx,\secondx,...,\dimx}
  { \foreach \y in {\steppingy,\secondy,...,\dimy}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowx}{(\x-\steppingx)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowy}{(\y-\steppingy)}
      \filldraw[cuboid/front] (\lowx,\lowy,\dimz) -- (\lowx,\y,\dimz) -- (\x,\y,\dimz) -- (\x,\lowy,\dimz) -- cycle;
    }
    }
  \foreach \x in {\steppingx,\secondx,...,\dimx}
  { \foreach \z in {\steppingz,\secondz,...,\dimz}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowx}{(\x-\steppingx)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowz}{(\z-\steppingz)}
      \filldraw[cuboid/top] (\lowx,\dimy,\lowz) -- (\lowx,\dimy,\z) -- (\x,\dimy,\z) -- (\x,\dimy,\lowz) -- cycle;
        }
    }
    \foreach \y in {\steppingy,\secondy,...,\dimy}
  { \foreach \z in {\steppingz,\secondz,...,\dimz}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowy}{(\y-\steppingy)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowz}{(\z-\steppingz)}
      \filldraw[cuboid/right] (\dimx,\lowy,\lowz) -- (\dimx,\lowy,\z) -- (\dimx,\y,\z) -- (\dimx,\y,\lowz) -- cycle;
    }
  }
  \ifcuboidemphedge
    \draw[cuboid/emphstyle] (0,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,\dimy,\dimz) -- (0,\dimy,\dimz) -- cycle;%
    \draw[cuboid/emphstyle] (0,\dimy,\dimz) -- (0,0,\dimz) -- (\dimx,0,\dimz) -- (\dimx,\dimy,\dimz);%
    \draw[cuboid/emphstyle] (\dimx,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,0,0) -- (\dimx,0,\dimz);%
    \fi

    \ifcuboidshade
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cstepx}{\dimx/\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cstepy}{\dimy/\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cstepz}{\dimz/\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lows}{\s-1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cpercent}{(\lows)/(\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}-1)*100}
        \fill[opacity=\tikzcuboidkey{shadeopacity},color=\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolorlight}!\cpercent!\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolordark}] (0,\s*\cstepy,\dimz) -- (\s*\cstepx,\s*\cstepy,\dimz) -- (\s*\cstepx,0,\dimz) -- (\lows*\cstepx,0,\dimz) -- (\lows*\cstepx,\lows*\cstepy,\dimz) -- (0,\lows*\cstepy,\dimz) -- cycle;
        \fill[opacity=\tikzcuboidkey{shadeopacity},color=\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolorlight}!\cpercent!\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolordark}] (0,\dimy,\s*\cstepz) -- (\s*\cstepx,\dimy,\s*\cstepz) -- (\s*\cstepx,\dimy,0) -- (\lows*\cstepx,\dimy,0) -- (\lows*\cstepx,\dimy,\lows*\cstepz) -- (0,\dimy,\lows*\cstepz) -- cycle;
        \fill[opacity=\tikzcuboidkey{shadeopacity},color=\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolorlight}!\cpercent!\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolordark}] (\dimx,0,\s*\cstepz) -- (\dimx,\s*\cstepy,\s*\cstepz) -- (\dimx,\s*\cstepy,0) -- (\dimx,\lows*\cstepy,0) -- (\dimx,\lows*\cstepy,\lows*\cstepz) -- (\dimx,0,\lows*\cstepz) -- cycle;
    }
    \fi 

  \end{scope}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \tikzcuboid{%
    shiftx=0cm,%
    shifty=0cm,%
    scale=1.00,%
    rotation=0,%
    densityx=1,%
    densityy=1,%
    densityz=1,%
    dimx=4,%
    dimy=2,%
    dimz=4,%
    front/.style={draw=blue!75!black,fill=blue!25!white},%
    right/.style={draw=blue!25!black,fill=blue!75!white},%
    top/.style={draw=blue!50!black,fill=blue!50!white},%
    anglex=-7,%
    angley=90,%
    anglez=221.5,%
    scalex=1,%
    scaley=1,%
    scalez=0.5,%
    emphedge=false,%
    shade,%
    shadeopacity=0.15,%
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

That has 2 layers of blocks when I want to plot only 1 layer, and the xyz dimensions of the cubes are the same, and I would like to change the x, y and the z dimension of the cuboids.

I have also tested the second solution, and also I was not able to get the result I am looking.

If possible, I would like also to place a label with the total dimension of each group of blocks at the x, y, and z dimensions. I do not know if it is possible that the text of the labels can be aligned with the same side angles of the figure. For example, in the case of a 2x2 group of blocks will be in the x dimension 1.6m, the y dimension 2.15 m (only one level of blocks) and the z dimension 2.4m.

**EDIT**

Using marmot's solution below, and

```
scalex=0.8,%
scaley=2.0,%
scalez=0.5,%
```

I would like to place text with the dimensions of each side of the group. For example:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess in the code you are using it was not foreseen to have only one cube in a given direction. To remedy this, I replaced

```
\foreach \x in {\steppingx,\secondx,...,\dimx}
```

by

```
 \ifnum\dimx=1
 \def\lstx{\dimx}
 \else
 \def\lstx{\steppingx,\secondx,...,\dimx}
 \fi
 \foreach \x in \lstx
```

and similar for other directions. Other than that, the dimensions in the various directions are set by keys like `scalex`, which I set to `2` in the MWE

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newif\ifcuboidshade
\newif\ifcuboidemphedge

\tikzset{
  cuboid/.is family,
  cuboid,
  shiftx/.initial=0,
  shifty/.initial=0,
  dimx/.initial=3,
  dimy/.initial=3,
  dimz/.initial=3,
  scale/.initial=1,
  densityx/.initial=1,
  densityy/.initial=1,
  densityz/.initial=1,
  rotation/.initial=0,
  anglex/.initial=0,
  angley/.initial=90,
  anglez/.initial=225,
  scalex/.initial=1,
  scaley/.initial=1,
  scalez/.initial=0.5,
  front/.style={draw=black,fill=white},
  top/.style={draw=black,fill=white},
  right/.style={draw=black,fill=white},
  shade/.is if=cuboidshade,
  shadecolordark/.initial=black,
  shadecolorlight/.initial=white,
  shadeopacity/.initial=0.15,
  shadesamples/.initial=16,
  emphedge/.is if=cuboidemphedge,
  emphstyle/.style={thick},
}

\newcommand{\tikzcuboidkey}[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cuboid/#1}}

% Commands
\newcommand{\tikzcuboid}[1]{
    \tikzset{cuboid,#1} % Process Keys passed to command
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorxx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalex}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{anglex})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorxy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalex}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{anglex})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectoryx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scaley}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{angley})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectoryy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scaley}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{angley})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorzx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalez}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{anglez})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorzy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalez}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{anglez})*28.452756}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=\tikzcuboidkey{shiftx}, yshift=\tikzcuboidkey{shifty}, scale=\tikzcuboidkey{scale}, rotate=\tikzcuboidkey{rotation}, x={(\vectorxx,\vectorxy)}, y={(\vectoryx,\vectoryy)}, z={(\vectorzx,\vectorzy)}]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingx}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{densityx}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingy}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{densityy}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingz}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{densityz}}
  \newcommand{\dimx}{\tikzcuboidkey{dimx}}
  \newcommand{\dimy}{\tikzcuboidkey{dimy}}
  \newcommand{\dimz}{\tikzcuboidkey{dimz}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondx}{2*\steppingx}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondy}{2*\steppingy}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondz}{2*\steppingz}
  \foreach \x in {\steppingx,\secondx,...,\dimx}
  {\ifnum\dimy=1
   \def\lsty{\dimy}
   \else
   \def\lsty{\steppingy,\secondy,...,\dimy}
   \fi
    \foreach \y in \lsty
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowx}{(\x-\steppingx)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowy}{(\y-\steppingy)}
      \filldraw[cuboid/front] (\lowx,\lowy,\dimz) -- (\lowx,\y,\dimz) -- (\x,\y,\dimz) -- (\x,\lowy,\dimz) -- cycle;
    }
    }
  \ifnum\dimx=1
  \def\lstx{\dimx}
  \else
  \def\lstx{\steppingx,\secondx,...,\dimx}
  \fi
  \foreach \x in \lstx
  { \ifnum\dimz=1
   \def\lstz{\dimz}
   \else
   \def\lstz{\steppingz,\secondz,...,\dimz}
   \fi
    \foreach \z in \lstz
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowx}{(\x-\steppingx)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowz}{(\z-\steppingz)}
      \filldraw[cuboid/top] (\lowx,\dimy,\lowz) -- (\lowx,\dimy,\z) -- (\x,\dimy,\z) -- (\x,\dimy,\lowz) -- cycle;
        }
    }
    \ifnum\dimy=1
    \def\lsty{\dimy}
    \else
    \def\lsty{\steppingy,\secondy,...,\dimy}
    \fi
    \foreach \y in \lsty
  { \foreach \z in {\steppingz,\secondz,...,\dimz}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowy}{(\y-\steppingy)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowz}{(\z-\steppingz)}
      \filldraw[cuboid/right] (\dimx,\lowy,\lowz) -- (\dimx,\lowy,\z) -- (\dimx,\y,\z) -- (\dimx,\y,\lowz) -- cycle;
    }
  }
  \ifcuboidemphedge
    \draw[cuboid/emphstyle] (0,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,\dimy,\dimz) -- (0,\dimy,\dimz) -- cycle;%
    \draw[cuboid/emphstyle] (0,\dimy,\dimz) -- (0,0,\dimz) -- (\dimx,0,\dimz) -- (\dimx,\dimy,\dimz);%
    \draw[cuboid/emphstyle] (\dimx,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,0,0) -- (\dimx,0,\dimz);%
    \fi

    \ifcuboidshade
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cstepx}{\dimx/\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cstepy}{\dimy/\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cstepz}{\dimz/\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lows}{\s-1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cpercent}{(\lows)/(\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}-1)*100}
        \fill[opacity=\tikzcuboidkey{shadeopacity},color=\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolorlight}!\cpercent!\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolordark}] (0,\s*\cstepy,\dimz) -- (\s*\cstepx,\s*\cstepy,\dimz) -- (\s*\cstepx,0,\dimz) -- (\lows*\cstepx,0,\dimz) -- (\lows*\cstepx,\lows*\cstepy,\dimz) -- (0,\lows*\cstepy,\dimz) -- cycle;
        \fill[opacity=\tikzcuboidkey{shadeopacity},color=\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolorlight}!\cpercent!\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolordark}] (0,\dimy,\s*\cstepz) -- (\s*\cstepx,\dimy,\s*\cstepz) -- (\s*\cstepx,\dimy,0) -- (\lows*\cstepx,\dimy,0) -- (\lows*\cstepx,\dimy,\lows*\cstepz) -- (0,\dimy,\lows*\cstepz) -- cycle;
        \fill[opacity=\tikzcuboidkey{shadeopacity},color=\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolorlight}!\cpercent!\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolordark}] (\dimx,0,\s*\cstepz) -- (\dimx,\s*\cstepy,\s*\cstepz) -- (\dimx,\s*\cstepy,0) -- (\dimx,\lows*\cstepy,0) -- (\dimx,\lows*\cstepy,\lows*\cstepz) -- (\dimx,0,\lows*\cstepz) -- cycle;
    }
    \fi 

  \end{scope}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \tikzcuboid{%
    shiftx=0cm,%
    shifty=0cm,%
    scale=1.00,%
    rotation=0,%
    densityx=1,%
    densityy=1,%
    densityz=1,%
    dimx=4,%
    dimy=1,%
    dimz=4,%
    front/.style={draw=blue!75!black,fill=blue!25!white},%
    right/.style={draw=blue!25!black,fill=blue!75!white},%
    top/.style={draw=blue!50!black,fill=blue!50!white},%
    anglex=-7,%
    angley=90,%
    anglez=221.5,%
    scalex=2,%
    scaley=1,%
    scalez=0.5,%
    emphedge=false,%
    shade,%
    shadeopacity=0.15,%
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: I added some keys for the egde labels. Note, however, that they may not look good if you use (very) different angles. Nor did I use `siunitx` to typeset the distances (because I do not want to flood this answer with not directly related packages). If you want a solution in which the labels look good for all possible angles, please ask a separate question.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newif\ifcuboidshade
\newif\ifcuboidemphedge

\tikzset{
  cuboid/.is family,
  cuboid,
  shiftx/.initial=0,
  shifty/.initial=0,
  dimx/.initial=3,
  dimy/.initial=3,
  dimz/.initial=3,
  scale/.initial=1,
  densityx/.initial=1,
  densityy/.initial=1,
  densityz/.initial=1,
  rotation/.initial=0,
  anglex/.initial=0,
  angley/.initial=90,
  anglez/.initial=225,
  scalex/.initial=1,
  scaley/.initial=1,
  scalez/.initial=0.5,
  xedgelabel/.store in=\xedgelabel,
  yedgelabel/.store in=\yedgelabel,
  zedgelabel/.store in=\zedgelabel,
  xedgelabel={},
  yedgelabel={},
  zedgelabel={},
  edgelabel/.style={},
  front/.style={draw=black,fill=white},
  top/.style={draw=black,fill=white},
  right/.style={draw=black,fill=white},
  shade/.is if=cuboidshade,
  shadecolordark/.initial=black,
  shadecolorlight/.initial=white,
  shadeopacity/.initial=0.15,
  shadesamples/.initial=16,
  emphedge/.is if=cuboidemphedge,
  emphstyle/.style={thick},
}

\newcommand{\tikzcuboidkey}[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cuboid/#1}}

% Commands
\newcommand{\tikzcuboid}[1]{
    \tikzset{cuboid,#1} % Process Keys passed to command
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorxx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalex}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{anglex})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorxy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalex}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{anglex})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectoryx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scaley}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{angley})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectoryy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scaley}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{angley})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorzx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalez}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{anglez})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorzy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalez}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{anglez})*28.452756}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=\tikzcuboidkey{shiftx}, yshift=\tikzcuboidkey{shifty}, scale=\tikzcuboidkey{scale}, rotate=\tikzcuboidkey{rotation}, x={(\vectorxx,\vectorxy)}, y={(\vectoryx,\vectoryy)}, z={(\vectorzx,\vectorzy)}]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingx}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{densityx}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingy}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{densityy}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingz}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{densityz}}
  \newcommand{\dimx}{\tikzcuboidkey{dimx}}
  \newcommand{\dimy}{\tikzcuboidkey{dimy}}
  \newcommand{\dimz}{\tikzcuboidkey{dimz}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondx}{2*\steppingx}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondy}{2*\steppingy}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondz}{2*\steppingz}
  \foreach \x in {\steppingx,\secondx,...,\dimx}
  {\ifnum\dimy=1
   \def\lsty{\dimy}
   \else
   \def\lsty{\steppingy,\secondy,...,\dimy}
   \fi
    \foreach \y in \lsty
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowx}{(\x-\steppingx)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowy}{(\y-\steppingy)}
      \filldraw[cuboid/front] (\lowx,\lowy,\dimz) -- (\lowx,\y,\dimz) -- (\x,\y,\dimz) -- (\x,\lowy,\dimz) -- cycle;
    }
    }
  \ifnum\dimx=1
  \def\lstx{\dimx}
  \else
  \def\lstx{\steppingx,\secondx,...,\dimx}
  \fi
  \foreach \x in \lstx
  { \ifnum\dimz=1
   \def\lstz{\dimz}
   \else
   \def\lstz{\steppingz,\secondz,...,\dimz}
   \fi
    \foreach \z in \lstz
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowx}{(\x-\steppingx)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowz}{(\z-\steppingz)}
      \filldraw[cuboid/top] (\lowx,\dimy,\lowz) -- (\lowx,\dimy,\z) -- (\x,\dimy,\z) -- (\x,\dimy,\lowz) -- cycle;
        }
    }
    \ifnum\dimy=1
    \def\lsty{\dimy}
    \else
    \def\lsty{\steppingy,\secondy,...,\dimy}
    \fi
    \foreach \y in \lsty
  { \foreach \z in {\steppingz,\secondz,...,\dimz}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowy}{(\y-\steppingy)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowz}{(\z-\steppingz)}
      \filldraw[cuboid/right] (\dimx,\lowy,\lowz) -- (\dimx,\lowy,\z) -- (\dimx,\y,\z) -- (\dimx,\y,\lowz) -- cycle;
    }
  }
    \path (0,0,\dimz) -- (0,\dimy,\dimz) node[midway,above,edgelabel]{\yedgelabel};
    \path (0,0,\dimz) -- (\dimx,0,\dimz) node[midway,below,edgelabel]{\xedgelabel};
    \path (\dimx,0,\dimz) -- (\dimx,0,0) node[midway,below,edgelabel]{\zedgelabel};
  \ifcuboidemphedge
    \draw[cuboid/emphstyle] (0,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,\dimy,\dimz) -- (0,\dimy,\dimz) -- cycle;%
    \draw[cuboid/emphstyle] (0,\dimy,\dimz) -- (0,0,\dimz) -- (\dimx,0,\dimz) -- (\dimx,\dimy,\dimz);%
    \draw[cuboid/emphstyle] (\dimx,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,0,0) -- (\dimx,0,\dimz);%
    \fi
    \ifcuboidshade
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cstepx}{\dimx/\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cstepy}{\dimy/\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cstepz}{\dimz/\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lows}{\s-1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cpercent}{(\lows)/(\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}-1)*100}
        \fill[opacity=\tikzcuboidkey{shadeopacity},color=\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolorlight}!\cpercent!\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolordark}] (0,\s*\cstepy,\dimz) -- (\s*\cstepx,\s*\cstepy,\dimz) -- (\s*\cstepx,0,\dimz) -- (\lows*\cstepx,0,\dimz) -- (\lows*\cstepx,\lows*\cstepy,\dimz) -- (0,\lows*\cstepy,\dimz) -- cycle;
        \fill[opacity=\tikzcuboidkey{shadeopacity},color=\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolorlight}!\cpercent!\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolordark}] (0,\dimy,\s*\cstepz) -- (\s*\cstepx,\dimy,\s*\cstepz) -- (\s*\cstepx,\dimy,0) -- (\lows*\cstepx,\dimy,0) -- (\lows*\cstepx,\dimy,\lows*\cstepz) -- (0,\dimy,\lows*\cstepz) -- cycle;
        \fill[opacity=\tikzcuboidkey{shadeopacity},color=\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolorlight}!\cpercent!\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolordark}] (\dimx,0,\s*\cstepz) -- (\dimx,\s*\cstepy,\s*\cstepz) -- (\dimx,\s*\cstepy,0) -- (\dimx,\lows*\cstepy,0) -- (\dimx,\lows*\cstepy,\lows*\cstepz) -- (\dimx,0,\lows*\cstepz) -- cycle;
    }
    \fi 

  \end{scope}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \tikzcuboid{%
    shiftx=0cm,%
    shifty=0cm,%
    scale=1.00,%
    rotation=0,%
    densityx=1,%
    densityy=1,%
    densityz=1,%
    dimx=4,%
    dimy=1,%
    dimz=4,%
    front/.style={draw=blue!75!black,fill=blue!25!white},%
    right/.style={draw=blue!25!black,fill=blue!75!white},%
    top/.style={draw=blue!50!black,fill=blue!50!white},%
    anglex=-7,%
    angley=90,%
    anglez=221.5,%
    scalex=0.8,%
    scaley=2.0,%
    scalez=0.5,%
    emphedge=false,%
    shade,%
    shadeopacity=0.15,%
    xedgelabel={3.2m},%
    yedgelabel={2m},%
    zedgelabel={3.2m},%
    /tikz/edgelabel/.style={sloped},
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question with a plot using your solution, and with the labels I would like to place

Comment: I have tested slight changes in the angles, and the figure and labels look fine to me. I will post a new question if I see a problem playing later with your code.