A 3D shape and text inside a TikZ box
I have made this so far but I m not able to add those spheres or cubes under that TikZ box and write inside of them. Also I couldn't create the arrows.

\documentclass[ border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing,
    backgrounds,
    fit,fadings,
    matrix,
    positioning,
    quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,align=center,fill=Green,text=white,minimum width=2.5cm,text width=4cm] (A) at (0,0) {Nanomaterial\\Fabrication Methods};
\node[ellipse,draw=red,minimum width=9cm,minimum height=7cm] (B) at (0,0) {};
\node[rectangle,draw=Blue3,minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=2cm,fill=Grey!20] (C) at (30:4.5) {};
\node[rectangle,draw=Blue3,minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=2cm,fill=Gray!20] (D) at (90:3.5) {};
\node[rectangle,draw=Blue3,minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=2cm,fill=Gray!20] (E) at (150:4.5) {};
\node[rectangle,draw=Blue3,minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=2cm,fill=Gray!20] (F) at (220:4) {};
\node[rectangle,draw=Blue3,minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=2cm,fill=Gray!20] (G) at (-40:4) {};
\node [rectangle,fill=Blue3,minimum width=2.5cm,text=white,minimum height=1.1cm, left=10mm of F,yshift=2cm] (5) {Bottom up};
\node [rectangle,fill=Blue3,minimum width=2.5cm,text=white,minimum height=1.1cm, above=2mm of C,xshift=2cm] (6) {Top down};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Here is what i m trying to get.


It may be easier to create the content and then fit the box to it.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12020/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-draw-a-3d-cube-with-tikz?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267982/tikz-easy-drawing-of-cuboids, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29877/need-help-creating-a-3d-cube-from-a-2d-set-of-nodes-in-tikz?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/467612/, ...

i m not really an expert with latex @cfr i m still stuck on that matter actually
