# How to draw cube chain?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, asymptote

I'm trying to find the easiest way to draw a 3D cube chain in latex. Help me [image]

I know how to draw cube in tikz. For example

```
\newcommand{\tikzcuboid}[4]{% width, height, depth, scale
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#4]
\foreach \x in {0,...,#1}
{   \draw (\x ,0  ,#3 ) -- (\x ,#2 ,#3 );

    \draw (\x ,#2 ,#3 ) -- (\x ,#2 ,0  );
    
   
}
\foreach \x in {0,...,#2}
{   \draw (#1 ,\x ,#3 ) -- (#1 ,\x ,0  );
    \draw (0  ,\x ,#3 ) -- (#1 ,\x ,#3 );
}
\foreach \x in {0,...,#3}
{   \draw (#1 ,0  ,\x ) -- (#1 ,#2 ,\x );
    \draw (0  ,#2 ,\x ) -- (#1 ,#2 ,\x );
}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\tikzcube}[2]{% length, scale
\tikzcuboid{#1}{#1}{#1}{#2}
}
```

I find this code in [Need help creating a 3D cube from a 2D set of nodes in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29877/need-help-creating-a-3d-cube-from-a-2d-set-of-nodes-in-tikz)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I add new info above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a tikz solution. You can change`\cubesAmount` to draw more or less cubes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}[z={(0.5,0.5)}]

\def\cubesAmount{3}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\cubesAmount}{
    \draw (\i-1,\i-1,\i-1) rectangle +(1,1,0) -- ++(0,1,0) -- ++(0,0,1) -- ++(1,0,0) edge +(0,0,-1) -- ++(0,-1,0) -- ++(0,0,-1);
    \ifnum\i<\cubesAmount
        \node[anchor=north west] at (\i,\i,\i) {$(\i,\i,\i)$};
    \fi
}
\node[anchor=north east] at (0,0,0){$(0,0,0)$};
\node[anchor=south west] at (\cubesAmount,\cubesAmount,\cubesAmount){$(\cubesAmount,\cubesAmount,\cubesAmount)$};
 
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

Also, if you want to change the perspective, you can tweak around `z={(yaw,pitch)}`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** One can [include the asymptote code in a LaTex document.](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/doc/LaTeX-usage.html) It is something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
// can be directly run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
<asymptote code>        
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

---

My suggestion is using Asymptote, then everything is available, built-in: `unitcube` is a surface; `unitbox` is an array of paths/segments in the 3D space. We are free to choose projection/point of view, say `(0,-2,1)` in this case.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
import three;
size(5cm);
currentprojection=orthographic(0,-2,1,center=true,zoom=.8);
path3[] p=unitbox;
//surface p=unitcube;
draw(p,red);
draw(shift(1,1,1)*p,blue);
draw(shift(2,2,2)*p,magenta);
```

With `surface p=unitcube;`

[image]

or this one

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
import three;
size(5cm);
currentprojection=orthographic(0,-2,1,center=true,zoom=.8);
path3[] p=unitbox;
surface q=unitcube;

draw(q,red+opacity(.1));
draw(shift(1,1,1)*q,blue+opacity(.1));
draw(shift(2,2,2)*q,magenta+opacity(.1));

draw(p,red);
draw(shift(1,1,1)*p,blue);
draw(shift(2,2,2)*p,magenta);
```

Comment: Can you add some information how one can include the `asymptote`-Code in a LaTex document. This could help the OP and other users who find this answer.

Comment: Yeah! I added a link for that