# creating a fifo symbol with pgfdeclareshape

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, pgfkeys, pgf-core

I'm compiling with:

- pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2011.7.8)
- pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
- tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)

I'm trying to create two new shapes for use with the PGF/TikZ environment for my final thesis in embedded engineering. The purpose with the symbols are a task diagram, which is kinda like a UML diagram. 
The first symbol, which I think could be a template for the second is a simple FIFO queue symbol.[image: Simple FIFO queue symbol] [image: FIFO queue with a semaphore]

These are figures from a previous course in embedded programming I've taken. So I'm free to create my own ones. But these seem to be the standard at my school, so I would like to not deviate too much.

I've figured out by reading this answer ( [What is the easiest way to draw 3D cube with TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12020/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-draw-3d-cube-with-tikz/12039#12039) and thank you Matthew Leingang for that answer) that I could copy the rectangle shape and remove the west and east sides, like this:

```
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd,
  fifo offset x/.initial=20pt,
  fifo offset y/.initial=20pt
}

\pgfdeclareshape{fifo}
{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \backgroundpath{
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/fifo offset x}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/fifo offset y}}%
    \def\ppd@offset{\pgfpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}%
    \pgfpathclose%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}%
    \pgfpathclose
  }
}
\makeatother
```

That give me this:

[image: Rectangle without sides]

I could live with that, having the text in the center also opens for a lot more connection points for arrows to other nodes. But I still need to have a FIFO with a semaphore symbol and semaphore name. For the life of me, I can't crack that one. I'm thinking that I should do a multipart node so I'd have a field for both the queue name and the semaphore name.

I tried to create the internal vertical lines, but only got as far as the first one, then the next ones crashed the compilation. I went about it by first defining the offset between them:

By adding:

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd,
internal_displacement x/.initial=5pt,
internal_displacement y/.initial=5pt
}
```

Between the first \pgfkeys and \pgfdeclareshape and then I defined new x axis values for the vertical lines with:

```
\pgf@xc=\pgf@xb \advance\pgf@xc by-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/internal_displacement x}%
```

and added the path:

```
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathclose
```

this gave me this:

[image: FIFO with one vertical line]

NICE! right?!? But then I want to define some more vertical lines, so I add this right after I have declared \pgf@xc:

```
\pgf@xd=\pgf@xc \advance\pgf@xd by-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/internal_displacement x}%
\pgf@xe=\pgf@xd \advance\pgf@xe by-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/internal_displacement x}%
\pgf@xf=\pgf@xe \advance\pgf@xf by-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/internal_displacement x}%
```

I'm thinking that this should shift the x value left by internal_displacement x, but instead I get a whole lot of errors along the likes of:

```
\pgf@sh@bg@fifo ...nternal_displacement x}\pgf@xe 
                                              =\pgf@xd \advance \pgf@xe ...
l.10 ...idth=2cm,align=center] (fifo1)  {Node One};
```

I'm guessing internal_displacement x is cleared after being read the first time? This seems rather counter productive. There must be another way of doing this.

So is there somebody who has an idea of:

1. getting the semaphore symbol added with a multipart node (so I'll have to text fields)
2. what I'm doing wrong in the vertical lines? I'm thinking if I could get this question nailed, I would not have trouble making the distance between the vertical and horizontal lines.

Comment: There are no `d,e,f,...` allocated for `\pgf@..` temporary dimensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also place your node with a pattern fill and decorate it if the shape declaration turns out to be difficult.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    mynode/.style={outer sep=1mm,
    pattern=vertical lines,
    minimum width=2cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
    append after command={
        \pgfextra{
        \draw(\tikzlastnode.north east) -- (\tikz@last@fig@name.north west);
        \draw(\tikz@last@fig@name.south east) -- (\tikz@last@fig@name.south west);
        \node[anchor=north] at (\tikz@last@fig@name.south) {#1};}
        }
    },
    with flag/.style={append after command={
        \pgfextra{
        \draw[fill=white](\tikzlastnode.135) circle (3mm);
        \draw[fill,line width=1mm,line cap=round,line join=round]
        ([xshift=-1pt]\tikzlastnode.135) +(0,-2mm) -- ++(0,2mm) --++(-35:2mm) --++(-145:2mm);
        }
        },
    }
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mynode={Queue Name}] (a) at (0,0) {};
\node[mynode={Another Queue}, with flag] (b) at (1,2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: percusse, that's brilliant! I'll need to define the edges better and add some text to the flag, but you have definitely made my job a lot easier - THANKS!

Comment: @Troels My pleasure. I forgot to change the unnecessary `\tikz@last@fig@name` commands to `\tikzlastnode` which is a little more readable. So please convert them for your own use to avoid `\makeatletter....\makeatother` pair.

Answer (score 6):

Here's something to get you started.  First, the basic points:

1. The error messages are coming from the fact that you are trying to use dimension registers that haven't been initialised.  These are `\pgf@xd` and so on.  Only up to `\pgf@xc` and `\pgf@yc` have been declared.  Unless you are doing something very tricky, it is usually possible to simply reuse the ones that are already in existence.  It might take a bit of bookkeeping, though.
2. For repeating something, use loops.  Nodes are meant to resize according to the text so specifying a fixed number of bars is asking for trouble.  Better is to draw the bars using a loop and stop before you get to the bottom.

Here's some code that does that, as well as shifting the drawing to above the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71487/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd,
  fifo offset x/.initial=20pt,
  fifo offset y/.initial=20pt,
  internal_displacement x/.initial=5pt,
  internal_displacement y/.initial=5pt,
  fifo height/.initial=20pt,
} 
\pgfdeclareshape{fifo}
{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \backgroundpath{
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \pgf@yb=\pgf@ya
    \advance\pgf@yb by \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/fifo height}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/fifo offset x}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/fifo offset y}}%
    \def\ppd@offset{\pgfpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}%
    \pgf@xc=\pgf@xb
    \advance\pgf@xc by-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/internal_displacement x}%
    \advance\pgf@xa by \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/internal_displacement x}%
    \advance\pgf@yb by-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/internal_displacement y}%
    \advance\pgf@ya by \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/internal_displacement y}%
    \loop\ifdim\pgf@xc>\pgf@xa\relax
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
\advance\pgf@xc by-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/internal_displacement x}%
    \repeat
\pgfpathclose
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fifo,draw] {Node One};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Queue shape]

For further work:

1. The bounding box is incorrectly computed, I think because the background path doesn't go around the text.  This is fixable with a simple `\pgfpathmoveto`.
2. The anchors should be adjusted, really the `north east` should be at the north east of the whole diagram not at the north east of the text.  (Note that there is a difference between the *saved anchors* and the *anchors* as used for coordinate calculations.)
3. You could probably do with more anchors to be able to point to different parts: text and drawing.
4. For the semaphore one, I agree that a multipart node would be the way to go.

Comment: Nicely done, I'd never figured that \pgf@xa xb and xc were registers, I just thought that I could use \pgf@[radom variable name], thank you for that clarification.