# How to do small Bar for voltage input on opAmp

Tags: circuitikz

How can I do those small bars at the end of a wire?

Specifically at the end of `(opamp.up)` and `(opamp.down)`

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american inductors]
\draw
(7,2.5) node[op amp] (opamp){}
    (opamp.down) ++ (0,-.5) node[below] {$-Va$}
    -- (opamp.down)
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

I tried to use the perpendicular sign `-|` but obviously it's not meant for that.

So, is there a command for that (perpendicular) bar ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82282/89497) from [Peter Gill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4301/peter-grill), here are two new styles (named `opampdownlbl` and `opampuplbl`) which handle the placement and draw the horizontal lines at the top and bottom of the node.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\tikzset{opampdownlbl/.style={
            below,
            draw=none,
            append after command={
                (\tikzlastnode.north) edge ([shift={(-5pt,0pt)}]\tikzlastnode.north) edge ([shift={(+5pt,0pt)}]\tikzlastnode.north)
            }},
        opampuplbl/.style={
            above,
            draw=none,
            append after command={
                (\tikzlastnode.south) edge ([shift={(-5pt,0pt)}]\tikzlastnode.south) edge ([shift={(+5pt,0pt)}]\tikzlastnode.south)
            }}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american inductors]
    \draw (7,2.5) node[op amp] (opamp){}
        (opamp.down) ++ (0,-.5) node[opampdownlbl] {$-Va$} -- (opamp.down)
        (opamp.up) ++ (0,.5) node[opampuplbl] {$+Va$} -- (opamp.up);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: Op amp with bars]