# Tikz: Draw part of shape style definition?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can make a partial draw in style definition?

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
    myrect/.style={%
    minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, fill=olive!80
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[myrect] (R) at (0, 0){};
\draw[red] (R.north west)--(R.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: At least I do not understand the question.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82279/cut-one-side-of-a-rectangle-node-in-tikz

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuehner I want to be able to draw the top line in the node style definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one of possibilities is use `path picture={...}`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
    myrect/.style={%
    minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, fill=olive!80,
    path picture={%
    \draw[thick,red]       (\ppbb.north west)  --  (\ppbb.north east);
                },    
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[myrect] (R) at (0, 0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]