# The TikZ pipeline: relative order of rendering of pre-actions and 'behind path' nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, sourcecode, tikz-node

I'm interested in the TikZ pipeline, i.e. the sequence of low-level actions that a TikZ path is converted to as it is being "executed". Unfortunately, this is described only fragmentarily in the TikZ & PGF manual (for version 3.0.1a), so there is no escape from rolling up the metaphoric sleeves and diving into the source code. According to [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384390/pgfextra-vs-graph-a-paradox#comment951697_384404) by Mark Wibrow, the pipeline is implemented by the `\tikz@finish` macro in `<tex installation directory>/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex`.

The `\tikz@finish` macro has the following structure:

```
  % Step 1: The path background box

  ...

  % Step 2: Decorate path

  ...

  % Step 3: Preactions

  ...

  ...

  % Step 13: Add labels and nodes

  ...
```

As can be seen, the pre-actions are applied before any node is inserted. However, the manual states in the description of the node option `/tikz/behind path` on p. 215:

> When this key is set, [...] TikZ collects all nodes defined on the current path with this option set and then inserts all of them, in the order they appear, just before it draws the path. [...] "Just before it draws the path” actually means that the nodes are inserted into the page output just before any pre-actions are applied to the path

There seems to be a discrepancy between the manual and the source code. Is this a bug in the manual, or am I missing something?

Comment: `/tikz/behind path` sets the `\tikz@figbox@bg` which is used in step 1. There is no discrepancy.

Comment: @cfr: To me it looks like all it does is give the `\tikz@figbox@bg` macro the alias `\tikz@whichbox`:  the only place in the file that the string 'behind path' appears is line 901: `behind path/.code=\def\tikz@whichbox{\tikz@figbox@bg}`.

Comment: Which makes the difference. It means the stuff sent to the `\tikz@whichbox` ends up in `\tikz@figbox@bg` as opposed to the default `\tikz@figbox`. You can see from the order that makes a crucial difference to where the stuff ends up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no discrepancy or mystery here. As the code makes clear, the contents of `\tikz@figbox@bg` is used before anything else is done (step 1), and `behind path` ensures that the node in question ends up in this box.

To see the effect, we can simply redefine `behind path` to use `\tikz@figbox` (the default) instead.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [draw=blue, fill=blue, fill opacity=.5] (0,0) -| (1,1) node [behind path, fill=yellow, opacity=1, text=red] {behind path} -| cycle;
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-15mm, behind path/.code={\def\tikz@whichbox{\tikz@figbox}}]
    \draw [draw=blue, fill=blue, fill opacity=.5] (0,0) -| (1,1) node [behind path, fill=yellow, opacity=1, text=red] {behind path} -| cycle;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: behind path ... and not]