# `latex` and `pdflatex` produce different colors given the same TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, pdf, postscript, tikz-node

Consider the following LaTeX manuscript featuring a TikZ picture* containing an empty, red-bordered node placed at the picture's origin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \tikz \path[draw=red] (0,0) node[draw] {};
\end{document}
```

When this manuscript is compiled with `pdflatex` the result is a pdf file with the following picture of a red square, as expected:

[image: The output of pgflatex]

However, when the same manuscript is compiled with `latex` the result is a dvi file with the following picture of a black square:

[image: The output of latex]

When the node is replaced by a line segment:

```
\tikz path[draw=red] (0,0) -- (1,0);
```

both pdf and dvi look the same, showing a red line segment, as expected:

[image: A red line segment]

Why does `latex` draw a black square?

---

*  This picture was the subject of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384756/the-tikz-pipeline-a-paths-draw-option-has-no-effect-on-a-behind-path-node) post, which may or may not be related to the present question; I suspect that it is, but I don't know for sure, hence the separate question.

Comment: try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \tikz \path (0,0) node[draw=red] {};
\end{document}` (this is more correct code) and see if now appear difference between latex and pdftex

Comment: @Zarko: Thanks, but this was not my question.

Comment: i just like to point, that the way you write the code is not correct, so appearing colors are accidentally such as you see them (they aren't well defined) ... but let us wait to some latex/tikz guru, what (s)he will say.

Comment: TikZ and DVI doesn't always play well together, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84182/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5826/. Not sure if this same thing is the cause of the problems here though, I don't know much about the very low level stuff.

Comment: How do you view the dvi?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Thanks. This was a good lead. However, I think that the etiologies of the two problems are different, since the solution to that question doesn't work here. The solution to that question was simply to convert the dvi file to ps or pdf using `dvips` or `dvipdf`. However, if I do so with my dvi file, the resulting ps/pdf picture is still a black square.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: By double-clicking the file in Finder on a macOS Sierra 10.12.6. It opens in TeXShop 3.84.

Comment: @Zarko I don't agree. The syntax `\path[draw=red]` is allowed and should have a well-defined effect on nodes on the path. To me it looks like a bug in one of the driver.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug in the PGF backend driver for dvi.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: If it is a bug, why does it make my question off topic? Would you vote to close [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300423/how-to-apply-colour-options-to-the-contents-of-tikz-nodes-when-the-content-inclu#comment824105_335982) too?

Comment: @PaulGaborit I've reopened: questions which are due to bugs are normally OK if the bug is 'open' and if the question isn't phrased as an out-and-out bug report.

Comment: I'm with @UlrikeFischer here: looks like a timing issue bug with colour specials. Not sure who should post an answer ....

Comment: @JosephWright If Evan Aad asked for a workaround, we could answer the question. But, here, the only answer is: it's a bug.

Comment: @PaulGaborit https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6988/questions-which-are-bug-reports-revisited

Comment: @JosephWright Ok. I copy the official answer... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically a bug in the default PGF backend driver for DVI (`pgfsys-dvips`), and as such, it should be reported using https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/.

Comment: Note that TeXShop (which the OP was using) converts the dvi to pdf, so (as the manual states (section 10.2.1), the pgf driver should be explicitly to `pgfsys-dvipdfm.def`. This actually doesn't help for TeXShop, but remedies the situation for skim (a Mac specific viewer) when viewing the dvi (it also converts it). So I am not sure if this is a bug in PGF or merely a viewer issue.

Comment: @MarkWibrow All PDF backend drivers are correct.

Answer (score 2):

as latex/tikz gurus find out your problem is caused by bug, but as workaround until bug will be eliminated you can use my suggestion in the first comment:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document} 
\tikz \path (0,0) node[draw=red] {}; 
\end{document}
```

apparently my claim, that is my code more correct then yours, is wrong. thank to [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) for pointing me to my mistake.