# How to create commands for automating the commenting process on some zones of a picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, automation

I have a lot of comments to make on different pictures, I can do it with the following command for ex:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{mypicture}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.68,0.01) rectangle (0.97,0.85);
        \node[fill=blue!10,text centered] at (0.83,0.43){Comment one};
        \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.04,0.08) rectangle (0.30,0.55);
         \node[fill=blue!10,text width=2cm,text centered] at
         (0.17,0.31){zone~2 comment~2 multiline};
 \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I would like to automate a bit since the text is always centered on the bounding box and shall not go outside.

I haven't a clue where I should start, I have a basic knowledge of TikZ, I tried using a `\pgfdeclareshape` but without success, don't even kmow if it is the good start! How to specify the decoration of the frame and text separately?

Shall I use a syntax like :

```
\draw[parameters] (a,b) myshape (c,d){my comment}
```

Or

```
\node[theshape, parameters, heigh, width] at (a,b){my comment}
```

This is far beyond my knowledge today :-(

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz

Comment: I actually used this tread for my comments, but what I want now it to have a single command to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One can grab into a new environment the previous code and declare a couple of commands to create annotations.

So, I created the `annotatedtikzpicture` as:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{annotatedtikzpicture}{O{width=0.9\textwidth} m}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};
   \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
}{
 \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

For what concern the commands, both are able to immediately draw the border (with its own options) and the annotated text (with its own options); the differences are:

1. `annote` is very tricky for the number of arguments;
2. `xannote` is more user-friendly by exploiting `keys`.

Let's see the definitions:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\annote}{o r() r() o r() m}{
\draw[#1] (#2) rectangle (#3);
\node[#4] at (#5) {#6};
}
```

for `\annote`, while `\xannote` and its own keys:

```
\pgfkeys{/tikz/annotated figure/.cd,
   border width/.initial=0,
   border width/.get=\bwidth,
   border width/.store in=\bwidth,
   border height/.initial=0,
   border height/.get=\bheight,
   border height/.store in=\bheight,
   start border pos/.initial={(0,0)},
   start border pos/.get=\bpos,
   start border pos/.store in=\bpos,
   start text pos/.initial={(0,0)},
   start text pos/.get=\tpos,
   start text pos/.store in=\tpos,
   border options/.code={
    \tikzset{border style/.style={
        #1
      }
    }
   },
   text options/.code={
    \tikzset{text style/.style={
        #1
      }
    }
   },
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\xannote}{r[] m}{
\pgfkeys{/tikz/annotated figure/.cd,#1}
\node[coordinate] (x) at \bpos {};
\draw[border style] (x) rectangle ($(x)+(\bwidth,\bheight)$);
\node[text style] at \tpos {#2};
}
```

Notice that it is also possible to simplify the annotation text position thanks to the key `annotation centered` set to `true`. But, to do so, the `\xannote` command has to be changed into:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\xannote}{r[] m}{
\pgfkeys{/tikz/annotated figure/.cd,#1}
\node[coordinate] (x) at \bpos {};
\draw[border style] (x) rectangle ($(x)+(\bwidth,\bheight)$);
\ifannotationcentered
  \node[text style] at ($(x)+(0.5*\bwidth,0.5*\bheight)$) {#2};
\else
  \node[text style] at \tpos {#2};
\fi  
}
```

To make things complete, the following features are added:

- an `\annoteset` command is provided: its functionalities are identical to `\tikzset`and here is used in order to collect into a style similar options to be passed to `\xannote`;
- an `\yannote` command, different from the previous `\xannote` since it does not draw first a rectangle and then a node, but rather is just a node. Definition shown later on;
- a key to compute directly the width of the annotation as asked in [How to compute a length and set a text width with pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117720/how-to-compute-a-length-and-set-a-text-width-with-pgf); I didn't post the solution there because it's very far from being perfect (actually it won't work under some hypothesis).

So, how it is defined `\yannote`? It is simply a node in which the minimum height and width are already given:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\yannote}{r[] m}{
\pgfkeys{/tikz/annotated figure/.cd,#1}
\node[option style, 
   minimum width=\bwidth, 
   minimum height=\bheight] at \tpos {#2}; 
}
```

The `option style` is identical to the previous `border style` and `text style` and it could be customized by means of the key `options`. An example:

```
\yannote[start text pos={(0.5,0.075)},
  border height=0.7,
  border width=0.3,
  options={draw=red,
    fill=blue!10
  },
  ]{A Comment}
```

In this case, the `start border pos` is completely useless.

In order to group into a style similar options, it is possible to exploit `\annoteset`; defined just as:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\annoteset}{m}{
\pgfkeys{/tikz/annotated figure/.cd,#1}
}
```

can be used for example to group:

```
\annoteset{my annotation/.style={
  border options={red,ultra thick,rounded corners},
  annotation centered=true,
  automatic text width=true,
  text options={fill=blue!10,align=center,text width=2.25cm},
  }
}  
\xannote[start border pos={(0.68,0.01)},
  border height=0.77,
  border width=0.29,
  my annotation
  ]{Comment one}  
\xannote [start border pos={(0.04,0.08)},
  border height=0.43,
  border width=0.26,
  my annotation
  ]{zone~2 comment~2 multiline}
```

Notice the key `automatic text width`: that's responsible for setting the annotation text width. The width computation is actually performed by the following macro:

```
% based on Alain's answer:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38500/13304
% percusse's answer:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58291/13304
% and the \CalcHeight macro implemented in:
% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram
\makeatletter
\def\CalcWidth(#1,#2)#3{%
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{east}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{veclen(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)-4\pgflinewidth}
\global\expandafter\edef\csname #3\endcsname{\mywidth}
}
\makeatother
```

within the new definition of `\xannote`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\xannote}{r[] m}{
\pgfkeys{/tikz/annotated figure/.cd,#1}
\node[coordinate] (annote-x) at \bpos {};
\draw[border style] (annote-x) rectangle ($(annote-x)+(\bwidth,\bheight)$)coordinate(annote-y);
\coordinate(annote-z) at (annote-x.west-|annote-y.east);
\ifannotationcentered
  \ifautomatictextwidth
    \CalcWidth(annote-x,annote-z){widthborder}
    \node[text style,minimum width=\widthborder] at ($(annote-x)+(0.5*\bwidth,0.5*\bheight)$) {#2};
  \else
    \node[text style] at ($(annote-x)+(0.5*\bwidth,0.5*\bheight)$) {#2};   
  \fi  
\else
  \ifautomatictextwidth
    \CalcWidth(annote-x,annote-z){widthborder}
    \node[text style,minimum width=\widthborder] at \tpos {#2};
  \else
    \node[text style] at \tpos {#2};
  \fi    
\fi  
}
```

Just an hint on the reasoning: we know that the lower left point of the border is called `(annote-x)` and we know also the top right point of the border, denoted with `(annote-y)`. To compute the width we basically need to calculate the intersection of the previous coordinates to find the lower right point of the border, `(annote-z)`.

Why I said it's not perfect? Well, just use this approach and set a high `text width` within `text options`: it will fail.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{annotatedtikzpicture}{O{width=0.9\textwidth} m}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};
   \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
   \draw(image.south east)rectangle(image.north west);
}{
 \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

% based on Alain's answer:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38500/13304
% percusse's answer:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58291/13304
% and the \CalcHeight macro implemented in:
% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram
\makeatletter
\def\CalcWidth(#1,#2)#3{%
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{east}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{veclen(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)-4\pgflinewidth}
\global\expandafter\edef\csname #3\endcsname{\mywidth}
}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\annote}{o r() r() o r() m}{
\draw[#1] (#2) rectangle (#3);
\node[#4] at (#5) {#6};
}

% predefined styles
\tikzset{border style/.style={draw=none},
  text style/.style={draw=none},
  option style/.style={draw=none},
}

\newif\ifannotationcentered
\newif\ifautomatictextwidth
\pgfkeys{/tikz/annotated figure/.cd,
   border width/.initial=0,
   border width/.get=\bwidth,
   border width/.store in=\bwidth,
   border height/.initial=0,
   border height/.get=\bheight,
   border height/.store in=\bheight,
   start border pos/.initial={(0,0)},
   start border pos/.get=\bpos,
   start border pos/.store in=\bpos,
   start text pos/.initial={(0,0)},
   start text pos/.get=\tpos,
   start text pos/.store in=\tpos,
   border options/.code={
    \tikzset{border style/.style={
        #1
      }
    }
   },
   text options/.code={
    \tikzset{text style/.style={
        #1
      }
    }
   },
   options/.code={
    \tikzset{option style/.style={
        #1
      }
    }
   },
   annotation centered/.is if=annotationcentered,
   annotation centered=false,
   automatic text width/.is if=automatictextwidth,
   automatic text width=false,
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\annoteset}{m}{
\pgfkeys{/tikz/annotated figure/.cd,#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\xannote}{r[] m}{
\pgfkeys{/tikz/annotated figure/.cd,#1}
\node[coordinate] (annote-x) at \bpos {};
\draw[border style] (annote-x) rectangle ($(annote-x)+(\bwidth,\bheight)$)coordinate(annote-y);
\coordinate(annote-z) at (annote-x.west-|annote-y.east);
\ifannotationcentered
  \ifautomatictextwidth
    \CalcWidth(annote-x,annote-z){widthborder}
    \node[text style,minimum width=\widthborder] at ($(annote-x)+(0.5*\bwidth,0.5*\bheight)$) {#2};
  \else
    \node[text style] at ($(annote-x)+(0.5*\bwidth,0.5*\bheight)$) {#2};   
  \fi  
\else
  \ifautomatictextwidth
    \CalcWidth(annote-x,annote-z){widthborder}
    \node[text style,minimum width=\widthborder] at \tpos {#2};
  \else
    \node[text style] at \tpos {#2};
  \fi    
\fi  
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\yannote}{r[] m}{
\pgfkeys{/tikz/annotated figure/.cd,#1}
\node[option style, 
   minimum width=\bwidth, 
   minimum height=\bheight] at \tpos {#2}; 
}

% something for shadings, taken from:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104528/tikz-shade-also-the-border-of-a-node/104541#104541
\tikzset{
 shrink inner sep/.code={
   \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgf/inner xsep}{\currentinnerxsep}
   \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgf/inner ysep}{\currentinnerysep}
   \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgf/inner xsep}{\currentinnerxsep - 0.5\pgflinewidth}
   \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgf/inner ysep}{\currentinnerysep - 0.5\pgflinewidth}
   }
}

\tikzset{horizontal shaded border/.style args={#1 and #2}{
    append after command={
       \pgfextra{%                 
          \begin{pgfinterruptpath}
                \path[rounded corners,left color=#1,right color=#2]
                ($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(-\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth)$) 
                rectangle
                ($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)$);        
           \end{pgfinterruptpath}
        } 
    }
  },
  vertical shaded border/.style args={#1 and #2}{
    append after command={
       \pgfextra{%                 
          \begin{pgfinterruptpath}
                \path[rounded corners,top color=#1,bottom color=#2]
                ($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(-\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth)$) 
                rectangle
                ($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)$);        
           \end{pgfinterruptpath}
        } 
    }
  }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{annotatedtikzpicture}[width=0.8\textwidth]{foto}
\yannote[start text pos={(0.5,0.075)},
  border height=0.7,
  border width=0.3,
  options={ultra thick,
    rounded corners,
    vertical shaded border=green!50 and violet!50!magenta,
    top color=green!10,
    bottom color=violet!40!magenta!50
  },
  ]{A Comment}

% a style for grouping similar options  
\annoteset{my annotation/.style={
  border options={red,ultra thick,rounded corners},
  annotation centered=true,
  automatic text width=true,
  text options={fill=blue!10,align=center,text width=2.25cm},
  }
}  
\xannote[start border pos={(0.68,0.01)},
  border height=0.77,
  border width=0.29,
  my annotation
  ]{Comment one}  
\xannote [start border pos={(0.04,0.08)},
  border height=0.43,
  border width=0.26,
  my annotation
  ]{zone~2 comment~2 multiline}
\end{annotatedtikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]

Comment: Picture taken [here](http://www.scoprinatura.info/Portals/0/valgrana.jpg).

Comment: Very nice, many thanks helps a lot. I have adapted your code to specify the frame with corners coords, I am also trying to limit text width to frame width.

Comment: @Penbeuz: yes, there's still room for improvements. At the moment I left some space for users' decisions with the keys `border options` and `text options`: I think is much more better this way since this allows to introduce usual TikZ options. With a bit of care, however, one might define some other keys under the path `/tikz/annotated figure/` devoted to customization. Perhaps later I'll give a look deeper on this and on styles...

Comment: @Penbeuz: please see the improved solution. `:)`

Comment: thanks for your time and great answer, I will use it and try to understand what you have done :)

Comment: @Penbeuz: you're welcome. I've edited a bit the title to reflect more your needs (not a shape, but commands).

Answer (score 1):

A `stackengine` approach.  One can use nested versions of `\commentfig{x0 to box left}{y0 to text height}{dx-box}{dy-box}{{line 1} {line 2} {...}}{image}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\fboxrule=1.5pt
\def\stackalignment{l}
\newlength \vdiff%
\newcommand\commentfig[6]{%
  \setlength\vdiff{#4}%
  \savestack\TextStack{\color{black}\Longstack{#5}}%
  \bottominset{\color{red}\fbox{%
    \rule{0ex}{.5\vdiff}\\%
    \makebox[#3]{\colorbox{white}{\belowbaseline[-.5\ht\TextStackcontent]{\TextStack}}}\\%
    \rule[-.5\vdiff]{0ex}{\vdiff}}}{
  #6
  }{#2}{#1}
}
\begin{document}
\Large
%\commentfig{x0 to box left}{y0 to text}{dx}{dy}{{line 1} {line 2} {...}}{image}
\commentfig{.3in}{1in}{1.45in}{1.3in}{this {is a test} comment}{%
\commentfig{3.75in}{1.35in}{1.45in}{2.5in}{{Comment three}}{%
  \includegraphics{image}%
}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]