# How to compute a length and set a text width with pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf

Follow up on [How to create a shape for commenting a zone on a picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117570/how-to-create-a-shape-for-commenting-a-zone-on-a-picture) after answer of 
[Claudio Fiandrino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304/claudio-fiandrino).

I have slightly modified the code and would like to compute the text width automatically.

```
\pgfkeys{/tikz/annotated figure/.cd,
    start border pos/.initial={(0,0)},
    start border pos/.get=\bpos,
    start border pos/.store in=\bpos,
    end border pos/.initial={(0,0)},
    end border pos/.get=\epos,
    end border pos/.store in=\epos,
    border options/.code={
    \tikzset{border style/.style={
      #1
     }
    }
    },
   text options/.code={
   \tikzset{text style/.style={
     #1
     }
    }
   },
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\xannote}{r[] m}{
\pgfkeys{/tikz/annotated figure/.cd,#1}
\node[coordinate] (x) at \bpos {};
\node[coordinate] (y) at \epos {};
\draw[border style] (x) rectangle (y);
\node[text style] at ($(x) !.5! (y)$) {#2};
}
```

Pgf is still obscur to me, I don't know how to do that, I tried to use

```
\pgfextractx{\mydim}{\pgfpointdiff{\epos}{\bpos}}
```

and set the text width with that but no success.

Comment: Not the direct answer but you can use the `\pgfmathparse{width("text")}` which stores the result then in the `\pgfmathresult`  variable as points (pt).

Answer (score 1):

[Claudio Fiandrino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304/claudio-fiandrino) has improved his code and given a good answer in [How to create a shape for commenting a zone on a picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117570/how-to-create-a-shape-for-commenting-a-zone-on-a-picture). 
.