# Mathematical formulas on a graph (not made by TeX)

Tags: graphics, diagrams

Let us assume that we have a graph created by a program different from LaTeX (that is not with PStricks or Tikz). I was wandering if it is possible to incorporate mathematical symbols on that graph using a TeX editor.

Thank you.

Comment: `\stackinset` from the `stackengine` package. See page 20 of the documentation in stackengine.pdf at http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine

Comment: If it is an `.eps` file and there is some text in this graph file, the text can be replaced from `LaTeX` using the `\psfrag` command from the corresponding package, but this collides with pdflatex nowadays a little bit

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes this looks awesome. I will give it a try when I have time. I suppose the package is already in the MikTeX right?

Comment: @PantelisKazakis The package is about a year old.  I think it is part of MikTeX, but if not, you can grab it from CTAN and place the .sty file in your working directory until you figure out how to install it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I ckecked my MikTeX installation. I have the very late one, and YES, it is here already :)

Comment: Package [overpic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/overpic) can do it without TikZ.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically, this is using the example of the `stackengine` documentation, adapted for use in math mode with the addition of `\stackMath` in the preamble.

The routine you want is `\stackinset` which has 6 arguments, `\stackinset{H-anchor}{H-offset}{V-anchor}{V-offset}{inset}{underlying anchor image}`.  As shown here, it can be nested and the insets themselves can be stacks.

```
\documentclass[standard]{letter}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\imgi{\includegraphics[width=.75in]{example-image}}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{l}{ .1in}{b}{.2in}{y=mx+b}{%
\stackinset{r}{ .1in}{t}{.2in}{\Longstack{F_x=ma_x\\F_y=ma_y}}{%
\stackinset{c}{-.5in}{c}{.4in}{E=mc^2}{%
\stackinset{r}{ .8in}{b}{.6in}{\psi^2=0}{%
\stackinset{r}{ .1in}{c}{.0in}{\imgi}{%
\includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image}%
}}}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if this question gets closed, you might post your answer here: [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559)

Comment: @Steven Yeah, I saw that. Looks splendid :)

Comment: @cmhughes I specifically said that I want to manipulate a graph not made by PStricks or Tikz.

Comment: @PantelisKazakis: The [linked question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/5764) is about drawing on an image... and that's that. That image could have been made using PStricks, TikZ, a camera, or whatever...

Comment: @Werner I will follow Steve's way. It is quite neat!

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks for the suggestion, but looking more closely, that question asks how to use `tikz` to draw upon an image.  I do note, however, that some of the answers to that question use packages other than `tikz`.

Comment: @PantelisKazakis: Indeed, the same thing can done with TikZ, no matter where the image comes from and no matter whether math is needed or not. See also [How to create commands for automating the commenting process on some zones of a picture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117570/13304).