# How to have text overlay top and bottom of image with fade at top and bottom?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, overlays, gradient

How can I make the text in my letter just slightly overlay the top and bottom of a centered, margin-to-margin image within my document. The image is faded at the top and bottom so that the image is just visible---you know, a gradient fade. Anyway, I thought it would be nice to have my text blend right into the image with the text overlaying this faded part just slightly---whatever the most aesthetic text-to-image overlay ratio happens to be. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: I think I'm looking for a function that just automatically understands that the text above and below should just slightly overlay the faded parts of the image.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, you should post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your question. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and suggest a way to achieve the desired effect when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I don't have clue how to fade an image, but overlaid text is a snap.  See, for example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171483/mathematical-formulas-on-a-graph-not-made-by-tex/171486#171486

Comment: May be you are talking about watermark. This can be done in several ways - `background`, `xwatermark`....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an image with suitable fading to transparency, then you could insert it with negative spacing between the text and the image to create the overlaying effect:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\intextsep}{-20pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{untitled}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Image used in this example: [image]