# Put text into small parts of a picture

Tags: macros, pdftex

I have used the `\multiput` command to create a for example 4 by 4 table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}‎
‎\usepackage{graphicx} % inserting images‎‎

‎\begin{document}‎‎‎‎
‎‎
\setlength{\unitlength}{2mm}
\begin{picture}(4,4)‎
\multiput(25,0)(5,0){5}%
{\line(0,1){20}}
\multiput(25,0)(0,5){5}%
{\line(1,0){20}}
\end{picture}‎‎‎
‎
‎\end{document}‎
```

how can I put text into each small square?

Comment: The `tabular` environment may be what you are looking for.  Consult any elementary text on LaTeX.

Comment: Actually it is a figure, for some part of it I want to add some text to each small square

Comment: @AndrewCashner I have edited it

Comment: For laying text onto an image (maybe what you meant by "figure"), there are various approaches, including this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171483/mathematical-formulas-on-a-graph-not-made-by-tex/171486#171486

Answer (score 3):

If you are really doing a picture (although your example sure looks like a table), then probably is best done to use a modern drawing package such as`tikz`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\NodeWidth}{1.0cm}%
\newcommand*{\NodeHeight}{1.0cm}%
\tikzset{My Node Style/.style={rectangle, ultra thick, minimum width=\NodeWidth, minimum height=\NodeHeight}}
\newcommand*{\FourNodes}[6][draw=black]{%
    \node [My Node Style, #1] at (0,#2*\NodeHeight) {#3\strut};
    \node [My Node Style, #1] at (\NodeWidth,#2*\NodeHeight) {#4\strut};
    \node [My Node Style, #1] at (2*\NodeWidth,#2*\NodeHeight) {#5\strut};
    \node [My Node Style, #1] at (3*\NodeWidth,#2*\NodeHeight) {#6\strut};
}%



\begin{document}‎‎‎‎
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \FourNodes{0.0cm}{a}{b}{c}{d}
    \FourNodes{-1}{x}{y}{z}{w}
    \FourNodes{-2}{1}{2}{3}{4}
    \FourNodes{-3}{r}{g}{t}{u}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}‎
```

Comment: @user3482383: If the solution worked for you please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

This one uses `matrix`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{
table/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={rectangle,minimum size = 1cm,align=center,inner sep=0pt},
  text depth=1.25ex,
  text height=2.5ex,
  nodes in empty cells
},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% the matrix entries
\matrix (mat) [table]
{
 a & b & c & d \\
 x & y & z & w \\
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 r & g & t & u \\
};
\foreach \x in {1,...,4}
{
  \draw[ultra thick]
    ([xshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]mat-\x-1.south west) --
    ([xshift=.5\pgflinewidth]mat-\x-4.south east);
  }
  \draw[ultra thick]
    ([xshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]mat-1-1.north west) --
    ([xshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]mat-1-4.north east);
\foreach \x in {1,...,4}
{
  \draw[ultra thick]
    ([yshift=.5\pgflinewidth]mat-1-\x.north east) --
    ([yshift=.5\pgflinewidth]mat-4-\x.south east);
}
\draw[ultra thick]
      ([yshift=.5\pgflinewidth]mat-1-1.north west) --
      ([yshift=.5\pgflinewidth]mat-4-1.south west);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Easier version in which

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{
table/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-4\pgflinewidth,    %% adjust
  column sep=-4\pgflinewidth,  %% adjust
  nodes={draw, ultra thick,rectangle,minimum size = 1cm,align=center,inner sep=0pt},
  text depth=1.25ex,
  text height=2.5ex,
  nodes in empty cells
},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% the matrix entries
\matrix (mat) [table]
{
 a & b & c & d \\
 x & y & z & w \\
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 r & g & t & u \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```