# Is it possible to substitute text inside a pdf figure?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, psfrag

I have a drawing made by the CAD [DraftSight](http://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight/overview/), I exported the drawing into a `.pdf` file and then I included it with

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
% ...
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{myfig.pdf}
\caption{My figure}
\end{figure}
```

The figure is properly shown in the final `.pdf` document (I compile it in TeX Live with the command `pdflatex`).

Is it possible to substitute some text inside the `.pdf` document like the `psfrag` does for an `.eps` figure?

I have made some tests with `psfrag` but with no luck... I had problems with the package `auto-pst-pdf`, the command line options `-shell-escape` and basically I am clueless...

Comment: In a fashion similar to David's answer, the `\stackinset` macro (`stackengine` package) can be used to overlay text on an image (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171483/mathematical-formulas-on-a-graph-not-made-by-tex/171486#171486).  The text could be set in a white colorbox to obliterate the background info.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really substitute the way psfrag does as that uses the PostScript programming features to relocate the texts.

However you can do

```
\includegraphics[scale=1]{myfig.pdf}%
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(-20,10){\colorbox{white}{hello}}
\end{picture}
```

which will write `hello` on a white background over-printing the image.
So with some careful choice of coordinates you can arrange to cover up text in the image and replace by TeX typeset text.

Comment: too bad there's not a "cleaner" way -- if the text overprints an important feature of the drawing (which happens not as infrequently as one might hope), painting out a white area isn't going to be a good solution.  but there may be an ugly workaround (not tested): convert .pdf to .eps.  using `standalone`, input the .eps file and alter with `psfrag`, and output to .dvi.  convert .dvi to .ps/.pdf.  then use the altered .pdf graphic instead of the original.

Answer (score 1):

The same technique that is used to [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)
can be used to place text on the image as well. Below I have placed the text 'CENTER' at the midway point between the `south west` and `north west` corners of the image:

[image]

### Notes:

- Even though I used a `.jpg` image here, it is the same if a `.pdf` file was used instead.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (X) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[height=8cm, keepaspectratio]{../images/EiffelTall.jpg}};
    \node [blue, ultra thick] at ($(X.south west)!0.5!(X.north east)$) {CENTER};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```