# inserting picture or figure on another picture

Tags: graphics

I have just wanted to know how can I insert a figure or picture on another figure or picture as clarified in attached picture, where the whole gray box represents the main figure while the blue one represents the second figure.[image: inserting picture or figure on another picture]

Comment: I think your question can be solved with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20792/how-to-superimpose-latex-on-a-picture or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz

Comment: Here's a `stackengine` approach: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171483/mathematical-formulas-on-a-graph-not-made-by-tex/171486#171486

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can pretty easily be done with [TikZ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), as [@Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1952/ignasi) suggested in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245691/inserting-picture-or-figure-on-another-picture/245701#comment584166_245691).
Obviously you'll have to tweak the `width`s of the included graphics...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength\imagewidth
\newlength\imagescale

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.618\linewidth]{img1}
    \caption{Image 1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.309\linewidth]{img2}
    \caption{Image 2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \pgfmathsetlength{\imagewidth}{\linewidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\imagescale}{\imagewidth/524}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\imagescale,y=-\imagescale]
        \node[anchor=north west] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{img1}};
        \node[anchor=north west] at (300,100) {\includegraphics[width=0.25\imagewidth]{img2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Both images on top of each other}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer, you can do this kind of thing outside of latex easily with imagemagick.  The `+5+10` part controls the location of figure1 on figure2.

```
composite -geometry +5+10 figure1.png figure2.png new.png
```