# How do I position one picture over another?

Tags: graphics, context

I want to overlay one picture on another, like this:

```
——————————————————————————
|                        |
|     img1               |
|                        |
|              ————————  |
|              | img2 |  |
|              ————————  |
——————————————————————————
```

How do I do that with ConTeXt?

I have no clue where to start. It seems that playing with spaces (e.g., `\blank`) won't help.

Comment: Don't know about ConTeXt, but using LaTeX, my answer here might be helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171483/mathematical-formulas-on-a-graph-not-made-by-tex/171486#171486

Comment: I don't use ConTeXt, but it can be done easily with TikZ, and TikZ works with ConTeXt too. So, would it be ok an answer using tikz?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes : Might be useful for search's sake indeed, as well as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz.  BTW, thank to your answer I remember now : aren't such pictures called "insets" ?

Comment: @JLDiaz : Well, as long as it does work with ConTeXt…  Is it already covered in the link in my previous comment ?

Comment: Yes it is covered. But you can still answer your own question for those who are too busy to figure out why "drawing" implies "insets".

Comment: Yes, "inset" is the right word for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading a huge library such as tikz for such a simple task isn't necessary. You can place your img1 as a background to a frame into which you place your img2. For further adjustments, you can set parameters such as offset or top and bottom (see the documentation). Here's an example:

```
\startTEXpage

\defineoverlay [mybackground] [{\externalfigure [mill]
  [width=\overlaywidth,height=\overlayheight]}]

\framed [background=mybackground,
     frame=off,
     strut=no,
     width=7cm,
     height=10cm,
     offset=\zeropoint,
     top=\vss,
     bottom=,
     align=flushright]
{\externalfigure [hacker] [height=2cm]}

\stopTEXpage
```

With the result:

[image]

Comment: I guess that should be the preferred way indeed, though I wonder if relative positioning is possible ?  For further reading : [framed](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Framed) and [overlays](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Overlays).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by JLDiaz, [TiKz is compatible with ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TikZ).  Then elaborating from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9561/61949) the solution is as simple as :

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\starttext
  \starttikzpicture
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\externalfigure[fig1][width=10cm]};
    \startscope[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
      \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0.7,0.2) {\externalfigure[fig2][width=2cm]};
    \stopscope
  \stoptikzpicture
\stoptext
```

(`\startscope` and `\endscope` lines are not needed if you are at ease with absolute coordinates.)

`x={(image.south east)}` redefines the `x` unitary vector as going from `(0,0)` (bottom left of img1) to `(image.south east)` (i.e. bottom right of img1).

Comment: Note that semicolons are required.