# rectangle containing text pointing from minipage

Tags: beamer, algorithms, shapes

I would like to achieve the following: 
[image]

The current code that I have is:

```
      \scalebox{0.65}{
\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]              %new code
        \begin{algorithmic}
    \caption{Example Algorithm}
    \STATE STEP1 
    \STATE STEP2
    \STATE STEP3
    \STATE STEP4


    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}%
   }
```

and putting the remaining text in another minipage. But it doesn't look like the image I want so please give directions. I am ok If instead of arrow, curly bracket comes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I save the individual boxes and then inset one over the other.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{%
  \fboxsep0pt\fbox{\fboxsep3pt\colorbox{black!10}{\parbox{1.5in}{\parskip 1em
  $D = a + b$\par
  $D = a - b$}}}%
}
\savestack{\graybox}{\box0}
\setbox0=\hbox{\fboxsep3pt\fbox{\parbox{2in}{\parskip 1em
  Example Algorithm:\par
  Step 1\par
  Step 2 $D \xrightarrow{\rule{7ex}{0pt}}$\par
  Step 3\par
  Step 4\par~}}%
}%
\savestack\whitebox{\box0}
\stackinset{c}{65pt}{c}{9pt}{\graybox}{\whitebox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If rotating the pointing arrow is essential, then this small modification could help:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor,mathtools,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{%
  \fboxsep0pt\fbox{\fboxsep3pt\colorbox{black!10}{\parbox{1.5in}{\parskip 1em
  $D = a + b$\par
  $D = a - b$}}}%
}
\savestack{\graybox}{\box0}
\setbox0=\hbox{\fboxsep3pt\fbox{\parbox{2in}{\parskip 1em
  Example Algorithm:\par
  Step 1\par
  Step 2 $D$ \smash{\rotatebox{-10}{$\xrightarrow{\rule{7ex}{0pt}}$}}\par
  Step 3\par
  Step 4\par~}}%
}%
\savestack\whitebox{\box0}
\stackinset{c}{65pt}{c}{6pt}{\graybox}{\whitebox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer!! It works perfect!!  Can you tell me how to place the grey box at the border of  white box as I have added more text. I understand stackinset insert it inside. Is there any  other command that can be use to insert stacks ?

Comment: Go to http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine and open the pdf documentation of the `stackengine` package.  Pages 11-12 describe the `\stackinset` macro (also, pp. 19-20 give examples of nested insets).  Basically, first argument is `l`, `c`, or `r` denoting horizontal alignment.  2nd argument is the length offset from that alignment.  3rd and 4th arguments are the  same for vertical alignment (`t`, `c`, or `b`).  5th argument is the inset, 6th argument is the base image.

Comment: Thanks again !! I was able to do!! One more question can I animate the appearance of arrow and grey box in beamer

Comment: @ShreyaKhare I am sorry that I am not a user of LaTeX animation.  There are other questions on the site that might assist you in that regard, or maybe, if still unclear, you could ask a new question.  Best wishes!

Comment: Is there a way to insert two small grey boxes on the bigger white box

Comment: @ShreyaKhare  You can nest `\stackinset`, as described on p.20 of the manual, or here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171483/mathematical-formulas-on-a-graph-not-made-by-tex/171486#171486