# In BEAMER, Bring Front Formula over a Figure

Tags: beamer, floats, positioning, overlap, transparent

I am totally new in `beamer`.
I have a question about positioning formulas over a Figure in **`beamer`**.

Previously, I was preparing my presentations with Power Point.
In Power Point I could write a formula in box, then position it by mouse and if some part of it was under an image, I could simply bring it front of the image and then remove the box filling colour so the image under the formula box can also be seen.

In `beamer` my figures are included by `\input` in `figure` environment like:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \scalebox{0.29}{\input{\MyTikZPath/Sphere.tex}}
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \caption{Sample Sphere}                 
    \label{fig-1}
\end{figure}
```

and my equations are written in `alignat` environment like:

```
\begin{alignat}{3}
    AAA         &= yy,      \quad   & a    &= C,        \quad   & m     &= C,   \nonumber \\ 
%
    B           &= yyyyyyy, \quad   & bbcd &= A+B,      \quad   & n     &= A+B, \nonumber\\
%
    CCCCCCCC    &= T,       \quad   & c    &= BBBBBBB   \quad   & ddddd &= BBBBBBB \nonumber
\end{alignat}
```

**My question are:**

1- Is there any box so I can write the formulas in it and then position it freely (e.g. by absolute coordinates from bottom left corner of the slide)?

2- If there is such a box, can I overlap some part of it over a figure and bring it front of the figure?

3- Is it possible to remove the box filling colour, so everything behind it can be seen?

(**Please Note that** I want to do all in beamer and I do not want to edit Tikz files)

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page.  Also, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171483/mathematical-formulas-on-a-graph-not-made-by-tex

Comment: From your code fragments I take you are loading Ti*k*Z. Then it is trivial to do what you want with a `overlay,remember picture` `tikzpicture`. Unfortunately, you only post fragments, not many will know the contents of `Sphere.tex`.

Comment: I'm a fan of the [`textpos` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos), that work very well in beamer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{An annotated sphere}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[ball color=gray!50] circle[radius=pi*1cm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \caption{Sample Sphere}                 
    \label{fig-1}
\end{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \path (current page.south west) +(0.1*pi,pi) 
 node[text width=12cm,anchor=south west]{\begin{alignat}{3}
    AAA         &= yy,      \quad   & a    &= C,        \quad   & m     &= C,   \nonumber \\ 
%
    B           &= yyyyyyy, \quad   & bbcd &= A+B,      \quad   & n     &= A+B, \nonumber\\
%
    CCCCCCCC    &= T,       \quad   & c    &= BBBBBBB   \quad   & ddddd &= BBBBBBB \nonumber
\end{alignat}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]