# Is it possible to use the width of one TikZ node to calculate the width of another?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

## Question

Is it possible to store the variable width of a node and use that width to calculate the text width of another node in TikZ?

## Example

I have a list of similar nodes side-by-side (inline, not overlaid). Let's call the left column of nodes "A" and the right column of nodes "B". Column A nodes contain a number (counter variable, which means the node gets wider at each digit carry-over). Column B nodes should have some text width minus the text width of the corresponding node in column A.

- get width of node A = `\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont\countervalue{}`
- text width of node B = (\textwidth) - (width of node A)

I think the answer I am looking for is hidden somewhere in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117577/13552) answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did I understand correctly?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\j in {1,10,100}{
\node[outer sep=0] (a-\j) at (0,{-7*log10(\j)}) {\j};
\path let \p1=($(a-\j.east)-(a-\j.west)$) 
  in 
  node[anchor=west,text width=\textwidth-\x1] (b-\j) at (a-\j.east) 
    {\lipsum[1]};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey yes sort of... I was hoping to learn from this how to derive `\x` in your example, but I am still unsure of what `\x` is and where it came from. I expected to see the width of the first node being set somewhere (like in a pgf variable).

Comment: @macmadness86: The width of node `A` is the distance between its `west` and `east` anchors. In the example above, the point `\p1` is calculated by subtracting `A.west` from `A.east` (@percusse used the `a-\j` as node name instead of `A`, but the idea is the same). To refer to the x-coordinate of point `\p1`, you can use `\x1`, which is equal to the x-coordinate of `A.east` minus the x-coordinate of `A.west`. This difference is exactly the width of node `A`.