# Annotating picture with tikz and positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am annotating a picture with tikz.

I have tried

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
    box/.style = {red, thick, rounded corners},
    arrow/.style = {->, green, ultra thick},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.1cm, auto]
    % image
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {%
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{img/navbar.PNG}
    };

    % annotate
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[box] (0.02,0.15) rectangle (0.1,0.9);
        \node at (-0.02,-1) {Home};
        \draw[arrow] (0,-0.8) -- (0.02,0.15);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My code works but I have manually placed my node with text "Home". I have to draw multiple boxes with text to each box. I also want an arrow from the text to the box to which the text belongs.

Can I use some positioning magic? I have tried naming the drawn rectangle with `\draw[box] (home) (0.02,0.15) rectangle (0.1,0.9);` but it's apparently not allowed to name rectangles like I can name nodes.

Comment: you can search for the `local bounding box`  in the manual to create a tight wrap around the annotation drawing and refer to that later.

Comment: You can have a look to [How to create commands for automating the commenting process on some zones of a picture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117570/13304): maybe it results being useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a `coordinate` at one corner of the rectangle, draw a line with the end point relative to this with the `++(x,y)` syntax, and add the `Home` node at the end of the line. Adjust the value for `shorten <` to your liking.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
    box/.style = {red, thick, rounded corners},
    arrow/.style = {->, green, ultra thick},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.1cm, auto]
    % image
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {%
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}
    };

    % annotate
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[box] (0.02,0.15) coordinate(box1) rectangle (0.1,0.9);
        \draw [arrow,shorten <=1pt] (box1) -- ++(-0.1,-0.7) node[below,black]{Home};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. But sometimes I also want the annotation to be above the image and then it looks wrong when all the arrows are pointing to the lower left corner. Can I change that?

Comment: @Jamgreen I don't really understand the problem. The end point of the arrow is defined by the coordinates in `++(-0.1,-0.7)`, change those and the arrow will point somewhere else. If it points upwards, you likely want to change the positioning of the node at the end of the arrow from `below` to `above`.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun I created a macro to generate a node given its corners.  This essentially gives you a box with anchor points.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe}% for example=image

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}

\newlength{\boxnodewidth}
\newlength{\boxnodeheight}

\newcommand{\boxnode}[4][\empty]% #1=parms (aptional), #2 = name, #3=SE corner x,y, #4=NW corner x,y
{\coordinate (boxnodecornerse) at (#3);
 \coordinate (boxnodecornernw) at (#4);
 \pgfextractx{\boxnodewidth}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{boxnodecornerse}{center}}%
   {\pgfpointanchor{boxnodecornernw}{center}}}%
 \pgfextracty{\boxnodeheight}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{boxnodecornerse}{center}}%
   {\pgfpointanchor{boxnodecornernw}{center}}}%
 \node[minimum width=\boxnodewidth,minimum height=\boxnodeheight,inner sep=0pt,#1] (#2) at ($(boxnodecornerse)!.5!(boxnodecornernw)$) {};
}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
    box/.style = {red, thick, rounded corners},
    arrow/.style = {->, green, ultra thick},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.1cm, auto]
    % image
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {%
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}
    };

    % annotate
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \boxnode[draw=red,rounded corners]{box}{0.02,0.15}{0.1,0.9}
        %\draw[box] (0.02,0.15) rectangle (0.1,0.9);
        \draw[arrow] (box.north) -- ++(0,1cm) node[black,above]{Home};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have since discovered that a scope with [local bounding box=name] does the same thing.  You can use \path to set the corners.  OTOH, it will not work in [overlay] mode.