# How to use i.e. left, middle and right color when using draw as an argument instead of a command?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I'm forced to define colors within my `tikzset` for one of my projects. This requires me to use the `draw` command within my `tikzset` to set a color.

Normally I can just use, say `\draw` command to just set an argument of `[top color=#1,bottom color=#3, middle color=#2]` to get the desired result, but in this case I want to use the `draw` within my tikzset to define fading colors in similar fashion.

I doubt there are any workarounds barring perhaps the `shading` command for which I have not found an argument equivalent (?) in the PGF manual v3.00, see page 694.

Code:

```
\tikzset{
mal/.style={->, >=stealth,
single arrow, line width=16mm,
single arrow head extend=.5cm, single arrow head indent=.25cm}
}
```

And the object itself:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,node distance=1cm, auto,baseline=-.5ex]
\node (dummy) at (-5,-10) {}; 
\begin{scope}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(dummy.center)}]

\def\malpath{(8.75,4.25) arc (440:130:7.75)}
\draw[mal] 
\malpath;
\end{scope}
```

Comment: I just define malpath as a dummy to wrap my arrow around, if that's what you mean?

Comment: my mistake. Didn't see its definition in the code

Comment: Single arrow is a node shape but you are not using it. Do you want to shade the path? If yes, that's not really trivial to do. Example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134283/tikz-shading-a-path-without-any-filling and another example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5107/fading-a-path-in-tikz

Comment: Yep that's pretty much it. I'll look into the translation from that into an arc shape.

Comment: I am having difficulty to understand where the top middle and bottom color should show up. The path is a arrowed curve with no node involved. But you have `node` specific options in the `mal` style. Do you want a node in the shape of a single arrow and shade it or you want that path to be colored? **EDIT:** Ah, OK now it's clear.

Comment: You might be interested also in [TikZ: shade also the border of a node](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104528/13304)

Comment: Okay, for solvers with a workaround, I kind of have an idea of the methodology, but I can't quite get the execution right. I want to use a polar grid to define my fading colours, I want to overlay this circle of colours (an altered version of shading=color wheel with user-specified colours), to use this to only draw the overlapping areas of the circle and the double arrow, maybe with `clip`?. I've attempted to use that path shading workaround, but this code shows no intention of changing into an arc in the forseeable future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well yet another polar transformation hack. We are lucky since the path is circular so we can pull off this. For other curve shapes, it's quite more involved, if not impossible

Here, the x coordinate becomes the angle so by moving up and down we control the radius. By moving left and right we play with the rotation. I placed two nodes 
inside and outside the transformation scope. It is pleasing enough to fool around. Notice that the arrow tip is also distorted.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\usetikzlibrary{curvilinear,shapes.arrows}
\tikzset{arrownode/.style={
    transform shape nonlinear=true,
    shape=single arrow,
    shape border rotate=180,
    draw,
    top color=red,
    bottom color=blue,
    middle color=black
    }
}
\makeatletter
\def\polartransformation{% Directly from the manual
\pgfmathsincos@{\pgf@x}
\pgf@x=\pgfmathresultx\pgf@y%
\pgf@y=\pgfmathresulty\pgf@y%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[arrownode,text height=1cm,middle color=white] at (0,3) {\phantom{\hspace{10cm}}};
\begin{scope}
\pgftransformnonlinear{\polartransformation}
\node[arrownode,text height=1cm] at (0,3) {\phantom{\hspace{10cm}}};
% rotate shading angle !!
\node[arrownode,shading angle=60] at (pi,-2) {\phantom{\hspace{10cm}}};
\end{scope}
\node[arrownode,middle color=white] at (pi,-2) {\phantom{\hspace{10cm}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]