# rotate node shape in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, rotating

**Edit 1**

Claudio gave a nice solution to my question. 
But the image should be included in a `beamer` presentation. 
I use for that the option `transform canvas={scale=0.5}` and this has a side problem with the node position. Compare the image below with that provided in Claudio's answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{main,foreground}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={transform canvas={scale=0.5}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 cross appereance/.style={
   white,very thick,
 },
 cross/.style={append after command={
    \pgfextra{
    \begin{pgfinterruptpath}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
     \draw[cross appereance,shorten <=0.35\pgflinewidth,shorten >=0.35\pgflinewidth]
  (\tikzlastnode.south) -- 
  (\tikzlastnode.north);
     \draw[cross appereance,shorten <=0.4\pgflinewidth,shorten >=0.4\pgflinewidth]
  (\tikzlastnode.west) -- 
  (\tikzlastnode.east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{pgfinterruptpath}
    }
  } 
 },
  quad/.style={cross,fill=purple, cross,rectangle, thick, label=below:{quad},minimum width=1cm},
]

   \node[quad]  (quad1) {};

 \begin{scope}[shift={(1cm,1cm)}, every node/.style={rotate=-60}]
   \node[quad, right= of quad1] (quad2) {};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Original question**

I made a rectangle with a white cross in the centre using the `picture path` and the shapes anchors (north, south,...). 
My problem is that when I rotate the node the cross is not rotated.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 cross/.style={path picture={ 
  \draw[white,very thick]
  (path picture bounding box.south) -- (path picture bounding box.north) (path picture bounding box.west) -- (path picture bounding box.east);}},
  quad/.style={fill,cross, purple, rectangle, thick, label=below:{quad},minimum width=1cm},
]

   \node[quad]  (quad1) {};

 \begin{scope}[xshift=1cm, every node/.style={rotate=-60}]
   \node[quad, right= of quad1] (quad2) {};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the problem here relies on how the cross has been created: my feeling is that by exploiting the `path picture bounding box` as reference makes things rather complicated. I'm not sure whether is possible to rotate that (perhaps yes, but what's the effort?) and for sure there's a simpler way. Indeed, for debugging purposes it is possible to draw the `path picture bounding box` and notice that it isn't rotate at all with your code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,png,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{main,foreground}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 cross/.style={path picture={ 
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
  \draw[white,very thick]
  (path picture bounding box.south) -- (path picture bounding box.north) (path picture bounding box.west) -- (path picture bounding box.east);
  \draw[blue]  
  (path picture bounding box.south west) -- 
  (path picture bounding box.north west) -- 
  (path picture bounding box.north east) -- 
  (path picture bounding box.south east) -- cycle;
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  }},
  quad/.style={fill,cross, purple, rectangle, thick, label=below:{quad},minimum width=1cm},
]

   \node[quad]  (quad1) {};

 \begin{scope}[xshift=1cm, every node/.style={rotate=-60}]
   \node[quad, right= of quad1] (quad2) {};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Similarly to what did in [How to modify nodes in TikZ to automatically add a line on their top?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76459/how-to-modify-nodes-in-tikz-to-automatically-add-a-line-on-their-top/76461#76461) one can proceed as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{main,foreground}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 cross appereance/.style={
   white,very thick,
 },
 cross/.style={append after command={
    \pgfextra{
    \begin{pgfinterruptpath}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
     \draw[cross appereance,shorten <=0.35\pgflinewidth,shorten >=0.35\pgflinewidth]
  (\tikzlastnode.south) -- 
  (\tikzlastnode.north);
     \draw[cross appereance,shorten <=0.4\pgflinewidth,shorten >=0.4\pgflinewidth]
  (\tikzlastnode.west) -- 
  (\tikzlastnode.east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{pgfinterruptpath}
    }
  } 
 },
  quad/.style={cross,fill=purple, cross,rectangle, thick, label=below:{quad},minimum width=1cm},
]

   \node[quad]  (quad1) {};

 \begin{scope}[xshift=1cm, every node/.style={rotate=-60}]
   \node[quad, right= of quad1] (quad2) {};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

> **After the comments**

If you apply a transformation, then perhaps you want to change a bit the `quad` style otherwise besides having the label too distant there are also bad effects.

That's what happens to me:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,positioning}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{main,foreground}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={transform canvas={scale=0.5}}}

\tikzset{white circle/.style={circle,minimum size=4cm, draw}}
\tikzset{green circle/.style={circle,minimum size=0.1cm, draw,bottom color=green!80}}
\tikzset{red circle/.style={circle,minimum size=0.1cm, draw,bottom color=red!80}}
\tikzset{blue circle/.style={circle,minimum size=0.1cm, draw,bottom color=blue!80}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A picture alone}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetseed{123456}
\node (inc) at (0,5) [white circle,label=INCLUSIONE] {};

\foreach \circle in {1,...,10}{
  \pgfmathrandom{0,360}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\angle\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathrnd
  \pgfmathsetmacro\distance\pgfmathresult
  \node[green circle] at ($(inc.center)!\distance!(inc.\angle)$){};
}

\foreach \circle in {1,...,10}{
  \pgfmathrandom{0,360}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\angle\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathrnd
  \pgfmathsetmacro\distance\pgfmathresult
  \node[red circle] at ($(inc.center)!\distance!(inc.\angle)$){};
}

\foreach \circle in {1,...,10}{
  \pgfmathrandom{0,360}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\angle\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathrnd
  \pgfmathsetmacro\distance\pgfmathresult
  \node[blue circle] at ($(inc.center)!\distance!(inc.\angle)$){};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title}


Without change the style:

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 cross appereance/.style={
   white,very thick,
 },
 cross/.style={append after command={
    \pgfextra{
    \begin{pgfinterruptpath}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
     \draw[cross appereance,shorten <=0.35\pgflinewidth,shorten >=0.35\pgflinewidth]
  (\tikzlastnode.south) -- 
  (\tikzlastnode.north);
     \draw[cross appereance,shorten <=0.4\pgflinewidth,shorten >=0.4\pgflinewidth]
  (\tikzlastnode.west) -- 
  (\tikzlastnode.east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{pgfinterruptpath}
    }
  } 
 },
  quad/.style={fill,cross, purple, rectangle, thick, label=below:{quad},minimum width=1cm},
]

   \node[quad]  (quad1) {};

 \begin{scope}[every node/.style={rotate=-60}]
   \node[quad, right= of quad1] (quad2) {};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

By changing the style:

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 cross appereance/.style={
   white,very thick,
 },
 cross/.style={append after command={
    \pgfextra{
    \begin{pgfinterruptpath}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
     \draw[cross appereance,shorten <=0.35\pgflinewidth,shorten >=0.35\pgflinewidth]
  (\tikzlastnode.south) -- 
  (\tikzlastnode.north);
     \draw[cross appereance,shorten <=0.4\pgflinewidth,shorten >=0.4\pgflinewidth]
  (\tikzlastnode.west) -- 
  (\tikzlastnode.east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{pgfinterruptpath}
    }
  } 
 },
  quad/.style={cross,fill=purple, cross,rectangle, thick,minimum width=1cm},
]

   \node[quad,label=below:quad]  (quad1) {};

 \begin{scope}[every node/.style={rotate=-60}]
   \node[quad, right= of quad1,label=quad,xshift=-1] (quad2) {};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is workng fine like a standalone, but I would like to include the picture in a beamer slide. For that I scale all the `tikzpicture` with `transform canvas={scale=0.5}`. In this case the quads are not showing.

Comment: Did you used my working code? With my approach I don't perceive problems in Beamer with `\tikzset{every picture/.style={transform canvas={scale=0.5}}}` added to the preamble. Perhaps it is worth to modify your question in order to resemble your real needs.

Comment: Your example is working fine. The problem is that the shape appear very far from the label (which is ok).  It also hapens in your code if you change `xshift` to `shift={(1cm,1cm)}`.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused: _The problem is that the shape appear very far from the label (which is ok)_. Hence, it is a problem or it is ok? It appears far since you applied the canvas transformation, but, again, if you can provide a MWE with that picture plus another I can give you some more information.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I made an edit to the question with the problem (MWE and image included).

Comment: @zunbeltz: thanks for having clarified the question. Could you have a look to the part `After the comments` I added to my answer? Is what you're looking for?