# How create a customized node style?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create a node style which looks like this:

[image]

After some investigations I was not able to succeed and identified two directions to achieve this goal. I am asking here which direction should I take and how continue into this direction.

The first direction seems to use `append after command` in my style definition as following:

```
channel/.style={ 
        fifo,minimum size=4mm,minimum width=10mm,
        append after command={
          (\tikzlastnode.north west)edge(\tikzlastnode.north east)
          (\tikzlastnode.south west)edge(\tikzlastnode.south east)
          (\tikzlastnode.north east)edge(\tikzlastnode.south east)
        }
}
```

My problem with this solution is that I don't know how to extend it to draw de "other" vertical lines in my node.

The second direction consist in declaring a new shape as clearly described here [How to draw inside a TikZ node, using node style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11287/how-to-draw-inside-a-tikz-node-using-node-style) My problem with this solution is it's relative complexity and how to draw these lines using `\pgf` primitives.

Feel free to add any other solution that may better suits this need.

Comment: Except for the left border, a multipart rectangle is what you want. And, may be, [creating-a-fifo-symbol-with-pgfdeclareshape](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71487/creating-a-fifo-symbol-with-pgfdeclareshape) can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link and what is a multipart rectangle ?

Comment: TikZ has a node shape called `rectangle split`, which is a rectangle divided into multiple parts. See chapter 48.6, *Shapes with multiple text parts*, in [the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution would be to just add more edges at the appropriate spots.  This version adds four vertical lines evenly distributed along the length:

[image]

### Notes:

- As I discovered in a similar situation problem [Cut one side of a rectangle node in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82279/cut-one-side-of-a-rectangle-node-in-tikz/82282#82282), one needs to tweak the end by `0.5\pgflinewidth` to get the corners just right.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{channel/.style={ 
        minimum size=4mm, minimum width=10mm,
        append after command={
            (\tikzlastnode.north west)edge(\tikzlastnode.north east)
            (\tikzlastnode.south west)edge(\tikzlastnode.south east)
            ([shift={(0,+0.5\pgflinewidth)}]\tikzlastnode.north east)edge
            ([shift={(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)}]\tikzlastnode.south east)
            ([shift={(0,+0.5\pgflinewidth)}]
                $(\tikzlastnode.north west)!0.8!(\tikzlastnode.north east)$)edge
            ([shift={(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)}]
                $(\tikzlastnode.south west)!0.8!(\tikzlastnode.south east)$)
            ([shift={(0,+0.5\pgflinewidth)}]
                $(\tikzlastnode.north west)!0.6!(\tikzlastnode.north east)$)edge
            ([shift={(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)}]
                $(\tikzlastnode.south west)!0.6!(\tikzlastnode.south east)$)
            ([shift={(0,+0.5\pgflinewidth)}]
                $(\tikzlastnode.north west)!0.4!(\tikzlastnode.north east)$)edge
            ([shift={(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)}]
                $(\tikzlastnode.south west)!0.4!(\tikzlastnode.south east)$)
            ([shift={(0,+0.5\pgflinewidth)}]
                $(\tikzlastnode.north west)!0.2!(\tikzlastnode.north east)$)edge
            ([shift={(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)}]
                $(\tikzlastnode.south west)!0.2!(\tikzlastnode.south east)$)
        }
    }
}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [channel] (Channel1) at (0,  0)  {};
  \node [channel, minimum width=20mm] (Channel1) at (0, -0.5)  {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```