# How to draw cubic shapes on LateX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have been trying to get my head around drawing on latex and have not been able to get anywhere. I was just wondering if anyone could help me with the following shape? Just need a bit of guidance still quite new to the program.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have a look at the answers to [What is the easiest way to draw 3D cube with TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12020/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-draw-3d-cube-with-tikz).

Comment: You can  take a look at some `pstricks` packages: `pst-ob3d`, `pst-3dplot`, `pst-solides3d`, `pst-perspective`.

Comment: There are examples on texample.net too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The following solution uses the experimental(?) package `tikz3d.sty` from the TeX.SX launchpad. To install it, do the following:

1. Download `tikz3d.dtx` from http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/tikz3d.dtx.
2. Run pdflatex on the `dtx` file to extract `tikz3d.sty`.

   ```
   pdflatex tikz3d.dtx
   ```
3. Run `pdflatex` once more on `tikz3d.dtx` to obtain `tikz3d.pdf`, the documentation of the package.

Now `pdflatex`ing the following code should result in the picture above.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/perspective eye={0,5,-10},>=stealth]
\newcommand\xa{5} % half of width at bottom
\newcommand\xb{2} % half of width at top
\newcommand\ya{2} % height
\newcommand\za{2} % half of depth
\coordinate (A) at (3d cs:-\xa,0,-\za);
\coordinate (B) at (3d cs: \xa,0,-\za);
\coordinate (C) at (3d cs: \xa,0, \za);
\coordinate (D) at (3d cs:-\xa,0, \za);
\coordinate (E) at (3d cs:-\xb,\ya, 0);
\coordinate (F) at (3d cs: \xb,\ya, 0);
\draw[thick] (D) -- node[left]{$w$} (A) -- node[below]{$l$} (B) -- (C);
\draw[dashed] (C) -- (D);
\draw[thick] (A) -- (E) -- (D);
\draw[thick] (B) -- (F) -- (C);
\draw[thick] (E) -- node[above]{$t$} (F);
\draw[<->,dashed] (3d cs:1,0,0) -- node[right]{$h$} (3d cs:1,\ya,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/perspective eye={0,5,-10}]
\newcommand\xa{6} % half of width at bottom, shifted
\newcommand\xb{2} % half of width at top
\newcommand\xc{3} % half of width at top, shifted
\newcommand\ya{2} % height
\newcommand\za{2} % half of depth
\coordinate (A) at (3d cs:-\xa,0,-\za);
\coordinate (B) at (3d cs: \xa,0,-\za);
\coordinate (C) at (3d cs: \xa,0, \za);
\coordinate (D) at (3d cs:-\xa,0, \za);
\coordinate (E) at (3d cs:-\xb,\ya, 0);
\coordinate (F) at (3d cs: \xb,\ya, 0);
\coordinate (E') at (3d cs:-\xc,\ya, 0);
\coordinate (F') at (3d cs: \xc,\ya, 0);
\coordinate (a) at (3d cs:-\xb,0,-\za);
\coordinate (b) at (3d cs: \xb,0,-\za);
\coordinate (c) at (3d cs: \xb,0, \za);
\coordinate (d) at (3d cs:-\xb,0, \za);
\coordinate (a') at (3d cs:-\xc,0,-\za);
\coordinate (b') at (3d cs: \xc,0,-\za);
\coordinate (c') at (3d cs: \xc,0, \za);
\coordinate (d') at (3d cs:-\xc,0, \za);
\draw[thick] (a') -- (A) -- (D) -- (E') -- (A);
\draw[dashed] (d') -- (D);
\draw[thick,fill=gray] (a') -- (E') -- (d') -- cycle;
\draw[thick] (b') -- (B) -- (C) -- (F') -- (B);
\draw[dashed] (c') -- (C);
\draw[thick,fill=gray] (b') -- (F') -- (c') -- cycle;
\draw[thick] (a) -- (b) -- (F) -- (E) -- (a);
\draw[dashed] (a) -- (d) -- (c) -- (b);
\draw[dashed] (d) -- (E);
\draw[dashed] (c) -- (F);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The code can be simplified by [setting the coordinate system globally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365418/110998) to `3d cs`. If you include the lines

```
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@parse@splitxyz#1#2#3,#4,{%
    \def\@next{\tikz@scan@one@point#1(3d cs:{#2},{#3},{#4})}%
}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble, then you can remove the prefix `3d cs:` in all of the coordinates, writing e.g. just `(-\xa,0,-\za)` instead of `(3d cs:-\xa,0,-\za)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking this time to explain it to me. I have run the package and have obtained the pdf file but when I try and run the code it is giving me the following message: "("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikz
librarytopaths.code.tex")))

! LaTeX Error: File `tikz3d.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:   "  I am not sure what to do. Apologies, still trying to wrap my head around LateX.

Comment: @aml1005 Check that `tikz3d.sty` and the file with the code above are in the same directory; then it should work. If not, it is a specialty of MiKTeX, which I do not use. In the latter case ask on this site why MikTeX doesn't find the file.

Comment: this is going to sound very stupid and i'm sorry if it does but how would i make sure that it is? And will do, thanks again for everything I really appreciate it!

Comment: @aml1005 Open the directory that contains the code from above using the explorer. Then you should also see `tikz3d.sty`. If not, my guess is that after downloading `tikz3d.dtx` ended up in some `Downloads` folder; running latex on it will store the generated `tikz3d.sty` also in the `Downloads` folder instead of in your TeX working directory. So you will have to move `tikz3d.sty` manually (with the explorer) from `Downloads` to the TeX working directory.