# How to set a user-defined coordinate system globally?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

Consider an example like [this drawing using a 3d perspective](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352743/110998). The package `tikz3d` defines a new coordinate system `3d`, and the coordinates are specified as `(3d cs:1,2,3)` etc.

Is is possible to set the coordinate system globally for the current scope in order to avoid the prefix `3d cs:` in each coordinate? Is there something like `every coordinate/.cs={3d}`?

Comment: Okay, with this addition the mentioned package is of course no option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The coordinate specification `(1,2,3)` will eventually be processed by

```
\pgfpointxyz{1}{2}{3}
```

You can redefine this macro (locally) to implement a different coordinate system.

To be specific, `\pgfpointxyz` is a macro that reads three numbers and defines `\pgf@x` to be the desired x-coordinate and `\pgf@y` to be the desired y-coordinate. (See `pgfcorepoints.code.tex` line 852-864 for its original definition.)

---

In this case, where a coordinate system is well-prepared, you may also do

```
\def\tikz@parse@splitxyz#1#2#3,#4,{%
    \def\pgfutil@next{\tikz@scan@one@point#1(3d cs:{#2},{#3},{#4})}%
}
```

See `tikz.code.tex` line 5415-5417 for its original definition.

---

By the way, there is already a library called 3d,
you probably want to use a different name other than `3d`.

---

This is a working example. The code of the two `tikzpicture` are the same. But with different parsers they result in different curves.

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@parse@splitxyz#1#2#3,#4,{%
    \def\pgfutil@next{\tikz@scan@one@point#1(xyz cylindrical cs:angle=#2,radius=#3,z=#4)}%
}
\tikz{
    \draw(0,2,0)foreach\i in{1,...,200}{
        --(17*\i,2,\i/80)
    };
}
\def\tikz@parse@splitxyz#1#2#3,#4,{%
    \def\pgfutil@next{\tikz@scan@one@point#1(xyz spherical cs:angle=#2,radius=#3,latitude=#4 r)}%
}
\tikz{
    \draw(0,2,0)foreach\i in{1,...,200}{
        --(17*\i,2,\i/80)
    };
}
```

[image]

Edit log: @Schrödinger's cat notices the changes
of the internal macro name which invalidate my answer.
So I correct it.

Comment: That's a nice answer which I had upvoted some time ago. According to what I find you need with the more recent versions of Ti*k*Z `\def\pgfutil@next` instead of `\def\@next`.