# TikZ specifying barycentric coordinates using just lists of numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, coordinates

Here's what I currently have to type:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (90:3cm);
  \coordinate (b) at (210:3cm);
  \coordinate (c) at (-30:3cm);

  \node [above] at (a) {$a$};
  \node [below left] at (b) {$b$};
  \node [below right] at (c) {$c$};

  \draw [thick,green, fill=green,opacity=0.5]
  (barycentric cs:a=1,b=0,c=0) --
  (barycentric cs:a=1,b=0,c=1) --
  (barycentric cs:a=1,b=1,c=0) -- cycle;

  \draw [ultra thick] (a) -- (b) -- (c) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is a little tedious. Since I'll want to draw lots of shapes using the same a,b,c-based barycentric coordinates. Is there a way to pass an option to `scope` for example that would allow me to have `(1,0,1)` evaluate as `(barycentric cs:a=1,b=0,c=1)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is ok for you to use normalized barycentric coordinates, ie `(x,y,z)` such that `x+y+z=1`, then you can simply set `x=(a),y=(b),z=(c)`. So in place of `(1,1,0)` you should use `(.5,.5,0)`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path
      (90:3cm) coordinate (a) node[above] {$a$}
      (210:3cm) coordinate (b) node[below left] {$b$}
      (-30:3cm) coordinate (c) node[below right] {$c$};

    \draw [thick,green, fill=green,opacity=0.5]
      (barycentric cs:a=1,b=0,c=0) --
      (barycentric cs:a=1,b=0,c=1) --
      (barycentric cs:a=1,b=1,c=0) -- cycle;

    \draw [ultra thick] (a) -- (b) -- (c) --cycle;

    % set x=(a),y=(b),z=(c) and use normalized barycentric coordinates
    \draw[ultra thick, red, dashed, x=(a),y=(b),z=(c)]
    (1,0,0)  -- (.5,0,.5) -- (.5,.5,0) --cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aha! I was wondering about this. So `$x=(a)$` just sets the "x" coordinate in `xyz` coordinates to be the vector to `(a)`?

Comment: When you set `x=(a),y=(b),z=(c)` than `(x,y,z)` is a point with coordinates `x.a+y.b+z.c`. That's all.

Comment: @Kpym I am not angry and would like to see your other, nice answer revived. The only thing I am advocating is to refer to earlier posts by others, if they are related, something that you usually do.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `insert path` to abbreviate the coordinates.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bcs/.style args={#1|#2|#3}{insert path={--(barycentric
cs:a=#1,b=#2,c=#3)}}]
  \coordinate (a) at (90:3cm);
  \coordinate (b) at (210:3cm);
  \coordinate (c) at (-30:3cm);

  \node [above] at (a) {$a$};
  \node [below left] at (b) {$b$};
  \node [below right] at (c) {$c$};

  \draw [thick,green, fill=green,opacity=0.5] (a)
  [bcs={1|0|1},bcs={1|1|0}] -- cycle;

  \draw [ultra thick] (a) -- (b) -- (c) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another thing you could do is to [locally change the Ti*k*Z parser](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365418/121799). Then the whole path really boils down to

```
  \begin{scope}[bary={a}{b}{c}]
   \draw [thick,green, fill=green,opacity=0.5] 
    (1,0,0) -- (1,0,1) -- (1,1,0) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
```

where `bary={a}{b}{c}` install the barycentric coordinate system in the scope (we don't want it everywhere) and you really just have to specify the three numbers.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365418/121799
\tikzset{bary/.code n args={3}{
  \def\tikz@parse@splitxyz##1##2##3,##4,{%
    \def\@next{\tikz@scan@one@point##1(barycentric cs:#1=##2,#2=##3,#3=##4)}%
    }}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (90:3cm);
  \coordinate (b) at (210:3cm);
  \coordinate (c) at (-30:3cm);

  \node [above] at (a) {$a$};
  \node [below left] at (b) {$b$};
  \node [below right] at (c) {$c$};
  \begin{scope}[bary={a}{b}{c}]
  \draw [thick,green, fill=green,opacity=0.5] 
  (1,0,0) -- (1,0,1) -- (1,1,0) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}   
  \draw [ultra thick] (a) -- (b) -- (c) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Every time I read your answers on TikZ I say to myself *I have to study the user guide*. I'm afraid the amount of new tools there I never read about!!

Comment: @Sigur This impression never fades away, regardless how long you read it. ;-)

Comment: I was thinking about this too, but using `insert path={(barycentric
cs:a=#1,b=#2,c=#3)}` do not work at the end of the path. For this reason you added `--` in the `insert path`, I suppose. But now you can only draw straight lines :(

Comment: @Kpym Yes, that's true. [This great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447120/121799) comes with a sort of coordinate system parser, which one may adopt to this situation here. Anyway, I added yet another possibility that changes the Ti*k*Z parser locally.

Answer (score 5):

You can define

```
\newcommand{\foo}[3]{(barycentric cs:a=#1,b=#2,c=#3)}
```

and then use it as

```
  \draw [thick,green, fill=green,opacity=0.5]
  \foo{1}{0}{0} --
  \foo{1}{0}{1} --
  \foo{1}{1}{0} -- cycle;
```

or combine with another command with 9 parameters

```
\newcommand{\faa}[9]{
  \draw [thick,green, fill=green,opacity=0.5]
  \foo{#1}{#2}{#3} --
  \foo{#4}{#5}{#6} --
  \foo{#7}{#8}{#9} -- cycle;
}
```

and use as

```
\faa{1}{0}{0}{1}{0}{1}{1}{1}{1}
```

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\foo}[3]{(barycentric cs:a=#1,b=#2,c=#3)}
\newcommand{\faa}[9]{
  \draw [thick,green, fill=green,opacity=0.5]
  \foo{#1}{#2}{#3} --
  \foo{#4}{#5}{#6} --
  \foo{#7}{#8}{#9} -- cycle;
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (90:3cm);
  \coordinate (b) at (210:3cm);
  \coordinate (c) at (-30:3cm);

  \node [above] at (a) {$a$};
  \node [below left] at (b) {$b$};
  \node [below right] at (c) {$c$};

  \draw [thick,green, fill=green,opacity=0.5]
  \foo{1}{0}{0} --
  \foo{1}{0}{1} --
  \foo{1}{1}{0} -- cycle;

  \faa{1}{0}{0}{1}{0}{1}{1}{1}{1}

  \draw [ultra thick] (a) -- (b) -- (c) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Suggestion : use `\def` in place of `\newcommand` to make more "friendly" interface. For example `\def\bc(#1:#2:#3){(barycentric cs:a=#1,b=#2,c=#3)}` can be used after as `\bc(1:0:0)`.