# Is there a way to automagically use the three point perspective coordinate system?

Tags: tikz-pgf, threepointperspective

To use the three [point perspective coordinate](https://tikz.dev/library-perspective) systems, one has to use the syntax

```
(tpp cs:x=1,y=2,z=3)
```

to specify the point (1,2,3). I find this a bit cumbersome to write. Is there a way to automatically treat coordinates of the form `(1,2,3)` as coordinates in the three point perspective coordinate system?

I know that I could try to define a new command which translates `\tpp{1,2,3}` into `(tpp cs:x=1,y=2,z=3)`.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352849/how-to-set-a-user-defined-coordinate-system-globally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can introduce a key `3d coordinate is` with the choice

- `default` (→ [`\pgfpointxyz`](https://tikz.dev/base-points#pgf.back/pgfpointxyz)) and
- `perspective` (→ `\pgfpointperspectivexyz`).

You just have to use the right choice at the right time.

The red node should not use the perspective coordinate system but you can use `3d coordinate is = default` for it or the explicit `(xyz cs: x=4, y=0, z=0)`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  3d coordinate is/.is choice,
  3d coordinate is/default/.code={\def\tikz@parse@splitxyz##1##2##3,##4,{%
    \def\pgfutil@next{##1{\pgfpointxyz{##2}{##3}{##4}}}}},
  3d coordinate is/perspective/.code={\def\tikz@parse@splitxyz##1##2##3,##4,{%
    \def\pgfutil@next{##1{\pgfpointperspectivexyz{##2}{##3}{##4}}}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view, perspective={p = {(4,0,0)}, q = {(0,4,0)}}]
\node[fill=red,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,label=above:p] at (4,0,0){};
\foreach \i in {0,...,100}
  \filldraw[fill = gray]               (tpp cs: x=\i,     y=0, z=0)
    -- (tpp cs: x=\i+0.5, y=0, z=0) -- (tpp cs: x=\i+0.5, y=2, z=0)
    -- (tpp cs: x=\i,     y=2, z=0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  isometric view,
  perspective={p = {(4,0,0)}, q = {(0,4,0)}},
  3d coordinate is = perspective]
\node[fill=red,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,label=above:p] at (xyz cs: x=4, y=0, z=0){};
\foreach \i in {0,...,100}
  \filldraw[fill = gray] (\i,     0, 0)
    -- (\i+0.5, 0, 0) -- (\i+0.5, 2, 0)
    -- (\i,     2, 0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works nicely!