# Detexify for TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

For LaTeX symbols we have [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). Do we similarly have the same for TikZ pictures?

This idea came because I wanted to draw a slab:

[image]

But couldn't find such website.

As I am not very familiar with the TikZ, if this is offside consider it to be my ignorance, go ahead to make any amendments.

Minimal working example for cube(may be very poor example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[outside/.style={thick},
                        every node/.style={font=\tiny}]


        \draw[outside](-2,-2,-2)--(-2,2,-2)--(-2,2,2)--(-2,-2,2)--(-2,-2,-2);
        \draw[outside](-2,-2,-2)--(2,-2,-2)--(2,-2,2)--(-2,-2,2)--(-2,-2,-2);
        \draw[outside](-2,-2,-2)--(2,-2,-2)--(2,2,-2)--(-2,2,-2)--(-2,-2,-2);
        \draw[outside](2,2,2)--(2,-2,2)--(2,-2,-2)--(2,2,-2)--(2,2,2);
        \draw[outside](2,2,2)--(-2,2,2)--(-2,2,-2)--(2,2,-2)--(2,2,2);
        \draw[outside](2,2,2)--(-2,2,2)--(-2,-2,2)--(2,-2,2)--(2,2,2);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably the answer is no. There is http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/, but it's not the same thing.

Comment: If you intend a site where you draw an image and it gives you back the TikZ code, the answer is: you're asking too much!

Comment: @CarLatex  Thanks my ignorance. I will show the minimal example of cube but how to put middle lines and coordinate axis

Comment: If you add an MWE, we'll be happy to help you for this specific case!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Or asking for Inkscape + `svg2tikz`, but the code is generally not very good.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Done but very very far from the diagram. Thanks

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That could be a solution. Unfortunately, I tried a couple of times but I never managed to change the code created with that tool...

Comment: The best existing approximation to the website you're looking for is the one you're on right now. It justs takes a few minutes longer than detexify.

Comment: Inkscape really is that tool. You can export Ti*k*Z code. Sure, it isn't really editable or readable, but if you just want to turn drawings into Ti*k*Z and don't want to take the time to learn it, it is the way to go. (Though just including what you draw as PDF would probably be as good or better in most cases.)

Comment: Your question has been closed, for your specific case, please ask a new question with a bit more elaborated MWE: see some examples here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12020/101651