# How to draw a flow chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

Could you give me a hint on this one? I’m new to TeX

[image]

Text from the screenshot

> Users
>
> Ítems
>
> Training Set
>
> Validation Set
>
> Train
>
> Test
>
> 0
>
> Mask test ratings
>
> feed the model
>
> Trained model
>
> Predicted Ratings
>
> Calculate evaluation metrics
>
> 1. Ratings matrix divided according to users
> 2. Validation user ratings split. Train part fed to trained model
> 3. Metrics using predicted ratings and validation

mwe for the cube:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{1}
    \draw[red,fill=white] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[red,fill=white] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
    \draw[red,fill=white] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Maybe `lipsum`?

Comment: Yes! Lipsum would work fine, then I replace the text

Comment: This one must be a tough cookie since nobody has answered it precisely :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `parallelepiped` is taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12039/121799). Otherwise I copy from the same user as the others. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd, % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12039/121799
  parallelepiped offset x/.initial=2mm,
  parallelepiped offset y/.initial=2mm
}
\pgfdeclareshape{parallelepiped}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \backgroundpath{
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped offset x}}
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped offset y}}
    \def\ppd@offset{\pgfpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[standard/.style={minimum width=3cm,draw,align=center},
font=\sffamily]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=boxes]
  \node[standard,minimum height=4cm] (TS) {Training Set};
  \node[standard,below=-\pgflinewidth\space of TS] (VS) {Validation Set};
  \node[standard,below=-\pgflinewidth\space of VS] (TeS) {Test Set};
  \path (TeS.south west) -- (TS.north west) node[midway,left]{Users};
  \path (TS.north west) -- (TS.north east) node[midway,above]{Items};
  \node[right=1.5cm of TeS.north east,standard] (T1) {Train};
  \node[right=-\pgflinewidth\space of T1,standard,minimum width=1cm] (TT1) {Test};
  \node[above=1.5cm of T1,standard] (T2) {Train};
  \node[right=-\pgflinewidth\space of T2,standard,minimum width=1cm] (TT2) {O};
  \node[above=1.5cm of T2,parallelepiped,draw,align=center,inner xsep=1.5em] (PE) {Trained\\ model};
  \node[right=3cm of PE,standard] (PR) {Predicted Ratings};
  \node[below=1cm of PR,standard,rounded corners=1em] (CEM) {Calculate\\ evaluation\\ metrics};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[-latex,thick]
  \draw (VS.east) -- (T1.west);
  \draw (T1) -- (T2) node[midway,right]{Mask test ratings};
  \draw (T2) -- (PE) node[midway,right]{Feed the model};
  \draw (PE) -- (PR);
  \draw (PR) -- (CEM);
  \draw[rounded corners] (TT1.east) -- ++ (2em,0) |- (CEM);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[nodes={text width=3.5cm,align=center}]
  \node[below] at (boxes.south-|TS) {Ratings matrix divided according to users};
  \node[below] at ([xshift=5mm]T1|-boxes.south) {Validation user ratings split. Train part fed to trained model};
  \node[below] at (CEM|-boxes.south) {Metrics using predicted ratings and validation ratings.};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A perhaps more 3d-ish version for [jerrythemad](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/192335/jerrythemad).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd, % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12039/121799
  parallelepiped offset x/.initial=2mm,
  parallelepiped offset y/.initial=2mm
}
\pgfdeclareshape{parallelepiped}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \backgroundpath{
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped offset x}}
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped offset y}}
    \def\ppd@offset{\pgfpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[standard/.style={minimum width=3cm,draw,align=center},
font=\sffamily]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=boxes]
  \node[standard,minimum height=4cm] (TS) {Training Set};
  \node[standard,below=-\pgflinewidth\space of TS] (VS) {Validation Set};
  \node[standard,below=-\pgflinewidth\space of VS] (TeS) {Test Set};
  \path (TeS.south west) -- (TS.north west) node[midway,left]{Users};
  \path (TS.north west) -- (TS.north east) node[midway,above]{Items};
  \node[right=1.5cm of TeS.north east,standard] (T1) {Train};
  \node[right=-\pgflinewidth\space of T1,standard,minimum width=1cm] (TT1) {Test};
  \node[above=1.5cm of T1,standard] (T2) {Train};
  \node[right=-\pgflinewidth\space of T2,standard,minimum width=1cm] (TT2) {O};
  \node[above=1.5cm of T2,align=center,inner
  xsep=1.5em] (PE) {Trained\\ model};
  \node[yscale=-1,parallelepiped,draw,fit=(PE),inner sep=0pt]{};
  \node[right=3cm of PE,standard] (PR) {Predicted Ratings};
  \node[below=1cm of PR,standard,rounded corners=1em] (CEM) {Calculate\\ evaluation\\ metrics};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[-latex,thick]
  \draw (VS.east) -- (T1.west);
  \draw (T1) -- (T2) node[midway,right]{Mask test ratings};
  \draw[shorten >=1mm] (T2) -- (PE) node[midway,right]{Feed the model};
  \draw[shorten <=1mm] (PE) -- (PR);
  \draw (PR) -- (CEM);
  \draw[rounded corners] (TT1.east) -- ++ (2em,0) |- (CEM);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[nodes={text width=3.5cm,align=center}]
  \node[below] at (boxes.south-|TS) {Ratings matrix divided according to users};
  \node[below] at ([xshift=5mm]T1|-boxes.south) {Validation user ratings split. Train part fed to trained model};
  \node[below] at (CEM|-boxes.south) {Metrics using predicted ratings and validation ratings.};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It could  not look prettier! One question: is it possible to put the arrow, that goes from “Trained Model” to “Predicted ratings”, on the other side of the parallelepiped? Or... in the middle? Because by changing the position of that arrow, that parallelepiped looks more “3d”

Comment: @jerrythemad It is easy to accomplish that but why do you think that it looks more 3d-like? My problem with this suggestion is that the arrow that comes from below should be partially hidden if the arrows attach in the way you describe.

Comment: You might be right. I was just looking at the original screenshot and the only difference with yours is that the arrow is on the other side, just that. And the arrow that comes from below remains the same. I have the feeling that looks more 3d like because if you have the arrows as you have it right now, it blocks the depth of the parallelepiped visually speaking, of course. Other than that, you are a piece of work! It looks fantastic

Comment: @jerrythemad I added something along those lines. You can apply different transformations to `\node[yscale=-1,parallelepiped,draw,fit=(PE),inner sep=0pt]{};` in order to obtain whatever view you wish to have.

Comment: You’re special...! So talented. Thank you very much!!! :)

Answer (score 3):

I hope this gives you an idea!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc,fit,backgrounds}
% Define a few styles and constants
\tikzset{sensor/.style={draw, rounded corners, text width=6em, text centered, minimum height=2.5em},
         box/.style = {minimum width=16pt,minimum height=16pt,draw},
         idles/.style = {very thick,draw=violet,text width=6em, align=center, minimum height=12em, rounded corners},
         line/.style = {,>=latex,->,draw=blue!50}}
\def\blockdist{4}
\def\tdist{2.25}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
\node (idle) [idles] {IDLE Mode};

\path ([yshift=1.5cm]idle)+(\blockdist,0) node [draw=blue!50] (dch) [sensor] {CELL DCH};
\path (idle)+(\blockdist,0) node [draw=orange] (fach) [sensor] {CELL FACH};
\path ([yshift=-1.45cm]idle)+(\blockdist,0) node [draw=yellow!50!green] (pch) [sensor] {CELL PCH};

% Draw connections between nodes
\draw [line] (dch.east) -- +(12pt,0) |- ([yshift=5pt]fach);
\draw [line] (fach.east) -- +(12pt,0) |- (pch);
\draw [line] (pch) -- (fach);
\draw [line] (fach) -- (dch);
\node (t1) [box,fill=blue!50] at ($(dch)!0.5!(fach)+(\tdist,0)$) {T1}; % You can create a style for the boxes used in this line and the next
\node (t2) [box,fill=orange!50] at ($(fach)!0.5!(pch)+(\tdist,0)$) {T2};

% Exercise: Discover how to place Connected Mode label
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \path (dch.west)+(-0.5cm,0.25cm) node (dchleft) {};
  \path (t2.east)+(0.5cm,0cm) node (t2right) {};
  \node [idles,fit=(dchleft) (pch) (t2right),draw] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> Using TikZ, some styles, the positioning, fit and calc libraries.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}

\colorlet{mygreen}{green!80!black}
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!80!black}
\colorlet{myred}{red!80!black}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
std/.style={
  draw,
  text width=2.5cm,
  align=center,
  font=\strut\sffamily
  },
rnd/.style={
  draw=#1,
  rounded corners=8pt,
  line width=1pt,
  align=center,
  text width=3cm,
  minimum height=2cm,
  font=\strut\sffamily
  },
vac/.style={
  text width=2.5cm,
  align=center,
  font=\strut\sffamily
  },
ar/.style={
  ->,
  >=latex
  },
node distance=0.5cm and 3cm    
]
%The nodes for the left
\node[std] (va)
  {Vehicle Age};
\node[std,below=of va] (fs)
  {Fan Strength};
\node[std,below=of fs] (vs)
  {Vehicle Speed};
\node[std,below=of vs] (cv)
  {Cabin Volume};
\node[std,below= 1cm of cv] (fr)
  {Fraction of Recirculation};
\node[std,below=of fr] (ac)
  {Ambient $CO_{2}$ Concentration};
\node[std,below=of ac] (op)
  {Occupant Parameters};

%The nodes for the center
\node[rnd,right=of va,yshift=-12.5pt] (aer)
  {Air Exchange Rate Determination};
\node[rnd=myblue,below=of aer] (cdm)
  {Carbon Dioxide Built-in Module};
\node[rnd=myred,below=of cdm] (vcm)
  {Vehicle Cabin Module};
\node[rnd=mygreen,below=of vcm] (hvac)
  {\textsc{hvac} Module};

%The nodes for the right
\node[vac,right=1cm of cdm] (occ)
  {Output $CO_{2}$ Concentration};
\node[vac,right=1cm of vcm] (the)
  {Thermal Environment};
\node[vac,right=1cm of hvac] (col)
  {Compressor Load};

%The dashed fitting node
\node[draw,dashed,inner sep=8pt,fit={(va) (cv)}]
  (fit) {};

% Some auxiliary coordinates for the arrows
\coordinate (aux1) at ( $ (va.east|-aer.west)!0.25!(aer.west) $ );
\coordinate (aux2) at ( $ (va.east|-aer.west)!0.50!(aer.west) $ );
\coordinate (aux3) at ( $ (va.east|-aer.west)!0.75!(aer.west) $ );

%The arrows from left to center
\draw[dashed,ar]
  (fit.east|-aer) -- (aer);  
\foreach \Nodo in {fs,vs,cv}
{
  \draw[ar,myred]
    ([yshift=5pt]\Nodo.east) -- ([yshift=5pt]aux3|-\Nodo.east) |- (vcm);  
}
\foreach \Nodo in {fs,vs,fr}
{
  \draw[ar,mygreen]
    ([yshift=-5pt]\Nodo.east) -- ([yshift=-5pt]aux2|-\Nodo.east) |- (hvac);  
}
\foreach \Nodo in {op,ac}
{
  \draw[ar,myblue]
    (\Nodo.east) -- (aux1|-\Nodo.east) |- (cdm);  
}
\draw[ar,myblue]
  ([yshift=5pt]fr.east) -- ([yshift=5pt]aux1|-fr.east) |- (cdm);  
\draw[myblue]
  ([yshift=-5pt]cv.east) -- ([yshift=-5pt]aux1|-cv.east);  

%The arrows from center to right
\foreach \Ori/\Dest in {cdm/occ,vcm/the,hvac/col}
{
  \draw[ar]
    (\Ori.east|-\Dest) -- (\Dest);  
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,arrows, fit,positioning}
\tikzset{block/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=4cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2.5cm},
block2/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=4cm, text centered, minimum height=2.5cm},
arrow/.style={draw, -latex'}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,]
        \node[block,draw=none] (a) at (0,0) {MANUAL\\
SGSPH-LEGAZPI\\
RECRUITMENT AND\\
SELECTION SYSTEM};
        \draw (a.north west) -- (a.north east);
        \node[anchor=south, at=(a.north) ] (b) {0};                  
        \node[fit=(a) (b),block](c){};
\node[block2, above left=1cm and 1cm of c](c1) {SD\\DEPARTMENT};
\node[block2, below left=1cm and 1cm of c](c2) {RECRUITER};
\node[block2, above right=1cm and 1cm of c](c3) {CALL OUT\\PERSONNEL};
\node[block2, below right=1cm and 1cm of c](c4) {APPLICANT};

\draw[arrow](c1.south) |-node[pos=0.5,above right]{\tiny FINAL INTERVIEW}([yshift=0.5cm]c.west);
\draw[arrow]([xshift=0.5cm]c1.south) |-node[pos=0.5,above right]{\tiny JOB VACANCY}([yshift=1cm]c.west);
\draw[arrow]([xshift=-0.5cm]c.north) |-node[pos=0.5,above left]{\tiny INITIAL REPORT}(c1.east);

\draw[arrow](c.north) |-node[pos=0.5,above right]{\tiny CALL OUT LIST}([yshift=0.5cm]c3.west);
\draw[arrow]([xshift=-1cm]c3.south) |-node[pos=0.5,above left]{\parbox{1.5cm}{\tiny INVITATION DETAILS}}([yshift=1cm]c.east);
\draw[arrow]([xshift=-0.5cm]c3.south) |-node[pos=0.5,above left]{\tiny SCHEDULE DETAILS}(c.east);

\draw[arrow](c2.north) |-node[pos=0.5,above right]{\tiny INITIAL INTERVIEW}([yshift=-1cm]c.west);
\draw[arrow]([xshift=-1cm]c2.north) |-node[pos=0.5,above right]{\tiny JOB REQUIREMENTS}([yshift=-0.5cm]c.west);
\draw[arrow]([xshift=-0.5cm]c.south) |-node[pos=0.5,above left]{\parbox{2cm}{\tiny JOB VANCANCY  NOTIFICATION}}([yshift=-1cm]c2.east);
\draw[arrow]([xshift=-1cm]c.south) |-node[pos=0.5,above left]{\parbox{2cm}{\tiny RECRUITMENT REPORTS  NOTIFICATION}}(c2.east);

\draw[arrow](c4.north) |-node[pos=0.5,above left]{\tiny APPLICATION DETAILS}([yshift=-1cm]c.east);
\draw[arrow]([xshift=1cm]c4.north) |-node[pos=0.5,above left]{\tiny INVITATION RESPONSE}([yshift=-0.5cm]c.east);

\draw[arrow](c.south) |-node[pos=0.5,above right]{\parbox{2cm}{\tiny APPLICATION STATUS}}([yshift=-1cm]c4.west);
\draw[arrow]([xshift=0.5cm]c.south) |-node[pos=0.5,above right]{\parbox{2cm}{\tiny INTERVIEW SCHEDULE}}([yshift=-0.5cm]c4.west);
\draw[arrow]([xshift=1cm]c.south) |-node[pos=0.5,above right]{\parbox{2cm}{\tiny INVITATION}}([yshift=0.5cm]c4.west);
\draw[arrow]([xshift=1.5cm]c.south) |-node[pos=0.5,above right]{\parbox{2cm}{\tiny JOB ANNOUNCEMENTS}}([yshift=1cm]c4.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]