# Centering Arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to center the arrow that goes from "Validation Ratings" to Training. I also need to make that the arrow that is pointing from "Training" to "Fit Model" touches the box. Last but not least, I would like to add a second rectangle below the "training validation" box that says "training test"

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd, % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12039/121799
  parallelepiped offset x/.initial=2mm,
  parallelepiped offset y/.initial=2mm
}
\pgfdeclareshape{parallelepiped}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \backgroundpath{
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped offset x}}
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped offset y}}
    \def\ppd@offset{\pgfpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[standard/.style={minimum width=3cm,draw,align=center},
font=\tiny]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=boxes]
  \node[standard,minimum height=4cm] (TS) {Training \\ ratings};
  \node[standard,below=-\pgflinewidth\space of TS] (VS) {Validation \\ ratings};
  \node[standard,below=-\pgflinewidth\space of VS] (TeS) {Test ratings};
  \path (TeS.south west) -- (TS.north west) node[midway,left]{Users};
  \path (TS.north west) -- (TS.north east) node[midway,above]{Products};
  \node[right=1.5cm of TeS.north east,standard] (T1) {Training};
  \node[right=-\pgflinewidth\space of T1,standard,minimum width=1cm] (TT1) {Validation};
  \node[above=1.5cm of T1,standard] (T2) {Training};
  \node[right=-\pgflinewidth\space of T2,standard,minimum width=1cm] (TT2){0};
  \node[above=1.5cm of T2,align=center,inner
  xsep=1.5em] (PE) {Fit\\ Model};
  \node[yscale=1.1,parallelepiped,draw,fit=(PE),inner sep=0pt]{};
  \node[right=3cm of PE,standard] (PR) {Ped ratings};
  \node[below=1cm of PR,standard,rounded corners=1em] (CEM) {Evaluation \\ metrics};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[-latex,thick]
  \draw (VS.east) -- (T1.west);
  \draw (T1) -- (T2) node[midway,right]{Hide validation ratings};
  \draw[shorten >=1mm] (T2) -- (PE) node[midway,right]{Feed Model};
  \draw[shorten <=1mm] (PE) -- (PR);
  \draw (PR) -- (CEM);
  \draw[rounded corners] (TT1.east) -- ++ (2em,0) |- (CEM);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[nodes={text width=3.5cm,align=center}]
  \node[below] at (boxes.south-|TS) {Bablabla.}; 
  \node[below] at ([xshift=5mm]T1|-boxes.south) {Blablablba};
  \node[below] at (CEM|-boxes.south) {Blablablba};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason this code looks familiar to me.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd, % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12039/121799
  parallelepiped offset x/.initial=2mm,
  parallelepiped offset y/.initial=2mm
}
\pgfdeclareshape{parallelepiped}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \backgroundpath{
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped offset x}}
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped offset y}}
    \def\ppd@offset{\pgfpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[standard/.style={minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1.11em,draw,align=center},
font=\tiny]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=boxes]
  \node[standard,minimum height=4cm] (TS) {Training \\ ratings};
  \node[standard,below=-\pgflinewidth\space of TS] (VS) {Validation \\ ratings};
  \node[standard,below=-\pgflinewidth\space of VS] (TeS) {Test ratings};
  \path (TeS.south west) -- (TS.north west) node[midway,left]{Users};
  \path (TS.north west) -- (TS.north east) node[midway,above]{Products};
  \node[right=1.5cm of VS,standard] (T1) {Training};
  \node[right=-\pgflinewidth\space of T1,standard,minimum width=1cm] (TT1) {Validation};
  \node[right=1.5cm of TeS,standard] (T3) {Training};
  \path let \p1=($(TT1.north east)-(TT1.south west)$) in 
  node[right=-\pgflinewidth\space of T3,standard,minimum width=\x1] (TT3) {Test};
  \node[above=1.5cm of T1,standard] (T2) {Training};
  \path let \p1=($(TT1.north east)-(TT1.south west)$) in
   node[right=-\pgflinewidth\space of T2,standard,minimum width=\x1] (TT2){0};
  \node[above=1.5cm of T2,align=center,inner
  xsep=1.5em,inner ysep=1mm] (PE) {Fit\\ Model};
  \node[parallelepiped,draw,fit=(PE),inner sep=0pt](PEF){};
  \node[right=3cm of PE,standard] (PR) {Ped ratings};
  \node[below=1cm of PR,standard,rounded corners=1em] (CEM) {Evaluation \\ metrics};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[-latex,thick]
  \draw (VS.east) -- (T1.west);
  \draw (TeS.east) -- (T3.west);
  \draw (T1) -- (T2) node[midway,right]{Hide validation ratings};
  \draw[shorten >=1mm] (T2) -- ([yshift=1mm]PEF.south) node[midway,right]{Feed Model};
  \draw[shorten <=1mm] (PE) -- (PR);
  \draw (PR) -- (CEM);
  \draw[rounded corners] (TT1.east) -- ++ (2em,0) |- (CEM);
  \draw[rounded corners] (TT3.east) -- ++ (2em,0) |- (CEM);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[nodes={text width=3.5cm,align=center}]
  \node[below] at (boxes.south-|TS) {Bablabla.}; 
  \node[below] at ([xshift=5mm]T1|-boxes.south) {Blablablba};
  \node[below] at (CEM|-boxes.south) {Blablablba};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: This is an extended comment on Zarko's post. The idea to use `append after command` is good, and I would give +1 if it were not for the fact that there is a path inside a `\pgfextra`, about which the pgfmanual writes

Note that this operation should only be used by real experts and should only be used deep inside clever macros, not on normal paths.

It is unnecessary to do that. You can even use `append after command` to define a style `poor mans parallelepiped` (and avoid hard coded distances there using `calc`). It is called "poor mans parallelepiped" because it does not have the anchors the shape from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12039/121799) has. Note that, in order to use this style, you need to say `\draw node[poor mans parallelepiped,...] ...` while `\node[poor mans parallelepiped,...] ...` won't work.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[standard/.style={minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1.11em,draw,align=center},
poor mans parallelepiped/.style={standard,append after command={%
let \p1=($(\tikzlastnode.north east)-(\tikzlastnode.south west)$) in
(\tikzlastnode.north west) -- ++ (30:0.3) -- ++ (\x1,0) 
-- (\tikzlastnode.north east) 
(\tikzlastnode.south east) -- ++ (30:0.3) -- ++(0,\y1) }},
font=\tiny]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=boxes]
  \node[standard,minimum height=4cm] (TS) {Training \\ ratings};
  \node[standard,below=-\pgflinewidth\space of TS] (VS) {Validation \\ ratings};
  \node[standard,below=-\pgflinewidth\space of VS] (TeS) {Test ratings};
  \path (TeS.south west) -- (TS.north west) node[midway,left]{Users};
  \path (TS.north west) -- (TS.north east) node[midway,above]{Products};
  \node[right=1.5cm of VS,standard] (T1) {Training};
  \node[right=-\pgflinewidth\space of T1,standard,minimum width=1cm] (TT1) {Validation};
  \node[right=1.5cm of TeS,standard] (T3) {Training};
  \path let \p1=($(TT1.north east)-(TT1.south west)$) in 
  node[right=-\pgflinewidth\space of T3,standard,minimum width=\x1] (TT3) {Test};
  \node[above=1.5cm of T1,standard] (T2) {Training};
  \path let \p1=($(TT1.north east)-(TT1.south west)$) in
   node[right=-\pgflinewidth\space of T2,standard,minimum width=\x1] (TT2){0};
  \draw node[above=1.5cm of T2,align=center,poor mans parallelepiped] (PE) 
  {Fit\\ Model};
  \node[right=3cm of PE,standard] (PR) {Ped ratings};
  \node[below=1cm of PR,standard,rounded corners=1em] (CEM) {Evaluation \\ metrics};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[-latex,thick]
  \draw (VS.east) -- (T1.west);
  \draw (TeS.east) -- (T3.west);
  \draw (T1) -- (T2) node[midway,right]{Hide validation ratings};
  \draw[shorten >=1mm] (T2) -- ([yshift=1mm]PE.south) node[midway,right]{Feed Model};
  \draw[shorten <=1mm] (PE) -- (PR);
  \draw (PR) -- (CEM);
  \draw[rounded corners] (TT1.east) -- ++ (2em,0) |- (CEM);
  \draw[rounded corners] (TT3.east) -- ++ (2em,0) |- (CEM);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[nodes={text width=3.5cm,align=center}]
  \node[below] at (boxes.south-|TS) {Bablabla.}; 
  \node[below] at ([xshift=5mm]T1|-boxes.south) {Blablablba};
  \node[below] at (CEM|-boxes.south) {Blablablba};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing job, Cat! One last question. Could you make the `test` box to have the same size as the `validation` box? And also draw the arrows as in the `Validation ratings`

Comment: How can I draw a line from Test Ratings to Training | test  box?

Comment: Super genius! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

With use of the TikZ libraries `shapes.multipart`, `quotes` and `positioning`, mostly off-topic suggestions:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newcommand\textbox[2]{%
    \parbox[c][#1][c]{\linewidth}{\centering#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 2mm and 11mm,
  standard/.style = {draw, minimum width=#1, minimum height=1.11em,
                     align=center, inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0pt},
standard/.default = 24mm,
      mpnv/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
                     draw, text width=3cm, align=center},
      mpnh/.style = {rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal,
                     rectangle split parts=2, align=center,
                     draw},
        tw/.style = {text width=#1},
every edge/.style = {draw, semithick, ->},
                > = Stealth,
every edge quotes/.style = {font=\scriptsize, align=left,  auto=right},
             font = \footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont
           ]
\node (n1) [mpnv,
            label=Products,
            label=left:Users,
            label=below:bla bla bla]
    {
    \nodepart{one}  \textbox{4cm}{Training\\
                                  ratings}
    \nodepart{two}              Validation\\ ratings
    \nodepart{three}            Test ratings
    };
\node (t1) [mpnh, right=of n1.three east,
            label=below: blablablabla]
    {\nodepart[tw=13mm]{one}    Training
     \nodepart[tw=15mm]{two}    Test
     };
\node (t2) [mpnh, right=of n1.two east]
    {\nodepart[tw=13mm]{one}    Training
     \nodepart[tw=15mm]{two}    Validation
     };
\node (t3) [mpnh, right=of n1.one east]
    {\nodepart[tw=13mm]{one}    Training
     \nodepart[tw=15mm]{two}    0
     };
\draw[line join=round] 
    node (t4) [standard=12mm, below=of n1.north -| t3.one north,
    append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode} 
      (\LN.north west) -- ++ (30:0.3)-- ++ (12mm,0) coordinate (aux) 
                       -- (\LN.north east)
      (\LN.south east) -- ++ (30:0.3) -- (aux) 
                         }]     {Fit\\ Model};          
\node (pr) [standard, 
            right=of t4 -| t3.east]  {Ped ratings};
\node (em) [standard,rounded corners=1em,
            above=of t3-| pr]       {Evaluation \\ metrics};
\node[below=of t1-| em] {Bla bla blabla};
%
\draw   (n1.three east) edge (t1) 
        (n1.two east)   edge (t2) 
        (t2.one north) edge["Hide\\ validation\\ ratings"]    (t3.one south)
        (t3.one north) edge["Feed\\ Model"]                 (t4)
        (pr) edge   (em);
\draw[shorten <=1mm]  (t4) edge   (pr);

\draw[rounded corners,->]   (t1.east) -- ++ (6mm,0) |- (em);
\draw[rounded corners,->]   (t2.east) -- ++ (6mm,0) |- (em);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The pgf manual is very clear in that one should not use path commands inside  `\pgfextra`. It is also absolutely unnecessary here. Try `\draw node (t4) [standard=12mm, below=of n1.north -| t3.one north,
    append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode}
    []
          (\LN.north west)  -- ++ (30:0.3)
                            -- ++ (12mm,0) coordinate (aux)
                            -- (\LN.north east)
    (\LN.south east)  -- ++ (30:0.3) -- (aux)
                          }]  {Fit\\ Model};`

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, corrected.

Comment: It does not compile. it says `Undefined control sequence. \draw (\LN.south east)`

Comment: @NaveganTeX, indeed. In cede was remain part of code which should be replaced at last edit. Now corrected. Thank you for point mi on this.