# Smooth line intersection

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I'm drawing a 3d cube in tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1mm]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\draw[fill=gray!40] (5,5)--(6,4)--(6,-1)--(5,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to avoid this ugly effect?
[image]

Comment: When three lines meet, you could draw the two outer lines normally, and the third middle line with `line cap=round`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12024/8650 .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would draw the fill first, then the outer most cycle and lastly the diagonal lines with `line cap=round` or `line cap=butt`. Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1mm]
\fill[gray!40] (5,5)--(6,4)--(6,-1)--(5,0)--cycle;
\draw (0,0) -- (0,5) -- (5,5) -- (6,4) -- (6,-1) -- (5,0) -- cycle (5,5) -- (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Part of bow with corrected line joint]

You can draw all the lines first with different colors, to check if everything looks ok. -Also see [What is the easiest way to draw a 3D cube with TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12020/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-draw-a-3d-cube-with-tikz)

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick and useful answer!